# Recycle abandoned question?

Tags: discussion, edits, old-questions

Somebody has already asked/described the same question/problem I have.

But since he does not provide any details,
he ends up with comments requesting details and no answers.
Then the OP abandons the question.

Should I

a) Open a new question with the same title?

b) Edit his question and provide the details even so I do not know if for his scenario the details would have been different?

Comment: Related from Meta.SE: [Should I ask a new question if my more detailed question is similar to an old, unanswered one?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134988) and [How to bump a question that's the same as the one you wanted to ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1471)

Comment: Can you please link to the question that you're talking about?

Comment: Also related: [What should you do when your exact question has already been asked, but badly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138198/what-should-you-do-when-your-exact-question-has-already-been-asked-but-badly)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the old question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem, you should vote (or flag) to close it as off-topic with a close reason of:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

If your question is fundamentally the same, be sure to include enough information to make it answerable, and feel free to ask away.

It is also helpful in those circumstances to link to the existing question in a comment to explain the reasoning. In this case you may want to link to this question on meta as well for anyone who wants further discussion.

Comment: I don't think he can close...