# Why is the Popular Question badge awarded for closed questions?

Tags: discussion, badges, closed-questions

Why does Stack Overflow award the "Popular Question" badge for a closed question, e.g. [Autocomplete using php, jquery, mysql [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=1703116)?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why it shouldn't?

Comment: Aren't closed question "not suitable" for StackOverflow, so why someone should be rewarded for asking them?

Comment: Not all closed questions are unsuitable. The ones that are are generally deleted and the ones that aren't are kept.

Comment: @jacks4jokers so why are suitable questions closed? This sounds like a double standard "a question is ok, but let us just close it"

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/

Comment: Also duplicate questions can be useful, if the search engine picks one of the duplicates up. In this case the view count can also increase

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The badge is for views, nothing else.  Closed questions are still visible, so still get views, including searchers coming in from Google, so there isn't a reason they shouldn't be eligible for the badge.

Sure, there are bad closed questions that don't necessarily deserve the badge, but bad closed questions usually will get deleted long before it gets enough views to get the badge.  Good closed questions, while less common, do have value to the community.  If they didn't, they would be deleted.

Comment: Can you please give some examples of "good closed" questions to your answer?

Comment: @Peter The point is if the question wasn't valuable, it would have been deleted.  There are [automatic scripts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/182513) that delete questions that meet certain criteria, and there are talks about [expanding the criteria](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt).  the basic idea is that if it isn't automatically deleted, there is probably **some** value in the question.

Comment: @Peter That being said, I am speaking in generalities.  The question you linked isn't all that great, but it has an accepted answer and an upvoted answer, so someone thought it had value, which is why it wasn't deleted.

Comment: @Peter You can get a full list with the most viewed (hence probably useful to many people) closed question at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206328/closed-questions-with-highest-view-count

Comment: @Peter: off-topic posts can still be popular. They may not fit the Stack Overflow format, yet still be helpful to someone. As such, they receive votes, views and badges but no new answers.

Comment: @Peter Another example of a "good closed question" is one that gets closed as duplicate, but which is more likely than the original to show up in search results (e.g., because it uses alternate keywords or error text that people are searching for).  It can then funnel people to the question with the good answers.  Regardless, "Popular" does not imply "good", so take the badge for what it is...

Comment: @Peter - Stack Overflow defines a "good question" as +25 for the good question badge. So you can enter the following into the search box to get a list of closed good questions. `is:question closed:yes score:25`

Answer (score 4):

When I first joined StackOverflow, I was a newbie to web design/programming. I honestly had no idea what I was doing and I was on an adventure to create a web application since it was something I was passionate about.

I asked the following question on Stack, and it was voted to be closed shortly afterwards due to the fact that it contained no code on my behalf, along with no effort for trying. I admit, I did not try to write any code myself since I was so lost on where to even begin.

I received a fantastic answer from someone within the community, and it really helped me get along with my new web application. Since then, it has nearly received 7,000 views, so it must be helping quite a few people out from simple Google searches I guess.

**[Simple Javascript drop down menu box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239300/simple-javascript-drop-down-menu-box)**

A wise user on SO once told me:

> Sometimes it's hard to make a "head start" when you don't even know
>   where the starting line is.

Comment: Sorry but 7,000 views and 2 upvotes is hardly a ringing endorsement to the helpfulness of the answer.