# make original question undeletable?

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow is great site for programmer and to get solution for our problem. But ever since I became usual user of Stack Overflow, I felt one issue is challenging its quality.

The problem I'm talking is about duplicate questions. When question is marked as duplicate, it has following problem:

1. There is no quality answers as most answers are link to other question.
2. No accepted answer so useless for future viewers.
3. Waste time of answer giver.
4. Increase search result and Stack Overflow database.

My question is: Why there is not any mechanism to delete duplicate question and make the original one undeletable even by asker?

Comment: Sometimes a bad question gets asked twice.  The fact that a bad question is asked twice shouldn't prevent us from getting rid of them.

Comment: I believe duplicate questions are deleted after some time. They survive for some period so that people may reopen them if it turns out that they were not duplicates.

Comment: The duplicates can be deleted. If they use different wording, they're usually left as signposts. This way, if someone types wording into search similar to the dupe, they can find the original. :)

Comment: Also to be noted: If the dupe is a quality, well-written question and someone doesn't realize it's a dupe, it does sometimes happen that a quality, well-written answer is posted before it's marked as a dupe, or shortly thereafter if the answerer was already writing the answer.

Comment: I find too many post with info "This question is marked as duplicate by......." If it shouldnt be deleted right away... wouldnt it be better if we just hide question from users as soon as it is marked as duplicate.

Comment: If we hide the dupe from users, how could one of them come along, realize it's not a dupe, and help the OP explain, or help reopen it?

Answer (score 10):

Questions marked duplicate will get deleted if they have a negative score, no answers, and less than two comments after a period of time (1 year).  The criteria for this are described in [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

There is a question ( [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt) ) that goes into what *more* should be deleted (I've got an answer there about more aggressive dup deletion).

Questions that are the *target* do get deleted too for a number of other reasons. This doesn't cause a cascading delete through the dups which can lead to some confusion.  When this is seen it should either be:

- Flagged to remove the dup (and possibly reclose with another reason)
- Flagged to delete (noting that the target was deleted and this should likely be deleted too)
- Flagged to undelete the target and historical lock it (sometimes these are the targets of many other dups and its easier to lock to prevent another dup than clean up all the other dups).

Note that this often involves 10k involvement so that they can see the deleted posts.  [This data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/177487/find-duplicates-of-deleted-posts) can help people find such posts.   See also MSE: [Prevent duplicate-question link rot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226498/prevent-duplicate-question-link-rot) and [“Duplicate of…[deleted post]”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43724/213963) and the feature request to prevent things from breaking: [Don't allow the target of a duplicate question to be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224406/dont-allow-the-target-of-a-duplicate-question-to-be-deleted)

Comment: When question is marked duplicate, more than 80% of those question has duplicate answer. Most of user stop commenting or answering question as soon as it is marked as duplicate. So, duple question records  almost all of its score, comment and answer before it is marked as duple .Then what's point in keeping it alive for whole 1 year?

Comment: @Crawler I certainly agree.  See the section titled [Low view meh duplicates in the "what should the system..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262080/289086). [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/513832?lq=1) is one such super dup target that could deal with *much* culling.

Comment: Probably better use ViewsPerYear for sorting: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/229630/find-duplicates-of-deleted-posts

Comment: @Deduplicator it depends if you are trying to rescue them, or find ones that should also be deleted but aren't high enough on the radar.

Comment: Hm. Maybe. Anyway, that extra column will come in handy for someone sometime... perhaps.