# Why will an answer to an off-topic question prevent it from being deleted or closed?

Tags: support, answers, closed-questions

Earlier, I answered a question which has subsequently been put on hold as off-topic. At the time, I would not have considered that it would be put on hold as the OP had at least made some effort to include what they had tried.

However, my question relates to this comment (along with a down-vote on my answer) [Trying to log to console with onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236196/trying-to-log-to-console-with-onclick-event/26236265#comment41154427_26236265)

> Too bad because of this answer the question will not be deleted..

Since this was only a syntax problem which could have easily been found online with a quick search, I can now understand why this has been put on hold...

So, should I just delete my answer so that the question can be deleted?

Comment: Answers won't ever prevent a post from being closed.

Comment: related: [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601) "we dispense with the logic that preserves answers with 1 vote or an accept mark that will stay deletion at 9 days..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete your answer, as it is marked accepted.

It *is* true that your answer prevents the post from being auto-deleted; normally closed questions with a score of 0 or lower eventually are cleared out, *unless* they have an upvoted or accepted answer (or more than one answer). Nothing you can do about this now, however.

The only remaining options are to flag *the question* for moderator-assisted deletion (the question won't feel a thing, don't worry) or for 10k+ users to vote to delete (it'll have to have a score of -3 or lower, so one more downvote needed). A moderator would only delete the post if there was nothing of value there to keep.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'll make my way over to the downvote button.