# Why can't you delete a question that has been marked as duplicate,closed and downvoted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I asked a question that was immediately marked as duplicate. It was also downvoted 4 times. I tried to delete it but was told something like  "You can't delete this question because it has answers".

But the question is

```
a) closed 
b) marked as duplicate
c) downvoted 4 times
```

Why is it better to leave it around than allow the user to delete it?

Comment: I'd guess you refer to [this sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437618/is-deleting-non-dynamic-memory-undefined-behavior). Well, you can't delete it, because there are answers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mentioned in the question that it said I couldn't do it because it has answers. Why do answers to a duplicate DOWNVOTED question take precedence over getting rid of a duplicate DOWNVOTED question? If the answers are that worthwhile then I would suggest they have them automatically moved to the question that has been identified as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: You don't need to yell on me, OK! I read your question and understood you received that message. The policy is IMHO, that other peoples efforts on your question count more than your own behalfs on it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, wasn't yelling at you. Just trying to emphasize that people are saying it is a bad question. I know that if you downvote an answer and it become negative, that is supposed to motivate the person who made the answer to delete the answer. I was trying to apply the same reasoning to questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt)

Answer (score 5):

The Stack Exchange philosophy emphasizes keeping good content over deleting bad content, so a question can't be deleted if it has positively scoring answers.

The question it looks like you're talking about has one answer with +2 (at the time of writing this), so Stack Overflow considers that to be a good answer that we want to keep around on the site.

Comment: Why not just automatically move the good answers to the question that this one duplicates?

Comment: @Scooter I suppose because a duplicate doesn't have to have a 1:1 relationship with the question. Just for example, the canonical question ["What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) might be a duplicate target for a question "why am I getting a `NullReferenceException`?" If that got the answer "You need to instantiate the variable: `foo = new Bar()`, that might answer the question perfectly, but it wouldn't be a good answer to the canon question.

Comment: Normally that is the case - the questions - as in your example, are not duplicates. Only similar, or more correctly, covering a similar subject or concept. So I don't think it should be "marked as duplicate", but "marked as similar" or "marked as covering similar subject matter to another question". They are probably never duplicates because we search for a duplicate and are presented with "possible duplicates" before we post.

Comment: @Scooter I'm not sure the etymology of duplicates is the issue. The goal of marking something as a duplicate is to keep redundant data off the site, and to keep central hubs of knowledge. When `Question B` can be answered in a complete fashion by `Question A`, any answers to `Question B` are going to contain duplicate information to the information in the answers to `Question A`, thus having them separated is of no use to the site. Marking something as a duplicate isn't always marking it as being equal to something else, but rather marking it as a subset of the other question.

Comment: Speaking of the specific terminology, that's a whole other matter completely. If your suggestion is that we change the phrasing of "mark as duplicate" to "mark as similar," that should be another feature request. Although that said, I don't imagine you'll get much support on that, because "similar" is a whole lot less objective than "duplicate," and such a change probably wouldn't clarify anything in most situations.

Comment: You can use "marked as subset" in some cases if that is more appropriate than "marked as similar". I am confused about your use of etymology which Webster defines as "the history of a word". My point is not about the history of the word "duplicate" but the meaning. It's meaning does not match it's use on Stackoverflow in my opinion. I did already make a feature request. With regard to an objective justification, I think duplicate would fall short in just about all cases. To be objectively duplicate, they have to ask the exact same thing, which is rare.

Comment: @Scooter I was using the word in the context of Stack Overflow. But regardless, you're taking all of these words far more literally than I think you should be. The best thing you can do is edit your question to avoid further down-votes. And by the way, exact duplicates are "rare" because those questions are deleted. It doesn't help the site in any way to have two verbatim copies of the same question. In that event, yes, a moderator will merge the two and consolidate any good answers to one, then delete the other.

Comment: I would like to edit the question to correct what they don't like about it, but I don't see any comments suggesting changes, although there is an underlying tone that it shouldn't have been asked.