# Did Google recently update algorithms in a way that's bad for Stack Overflow questions?

Tags: discussion, google, seo

Until recently a simple Google search was great for finding answers on Stack Overflow. I generally don't restrict searches to **site:stackoverflow.com** because it's a pain to type and I occasionally get useful answers elsewhere.

Starting around Dec 10 2014, I began noticing that search results typically include only 1 or 2 hits from Stack Overflow with the rest pointing at useless blogs, tutorials or spam sites. At first I thought it was me and spent a lot of time re-wording queries and trying again to see if I could get better results. Didn't make much difference. At the moment I am finding it difficult to get the depth of answers on SO without using **site:stackoverflow.com**

Does anyone know if Google recently update one of the algorithms causing Stack Overflow posts to show up **a lot** less frequently or prominently in results?

This would be a major pain in the arse if they did!

**Update Dec. 24:** Well it now seems like it is ***Official*** and that Google has admitted that the Penguin algorithm has started updating on some kind of continuous basis.... and pretty much right around the time I started noticing search being less useful. According to one of the SEO Blogs [HERE](http://searchengineland.com/google-says-penguin-shift-continuous-updates-210580) there were a bunch of updates in early December, and these are probably causing what many of us are seeing. Apparently Penguin is supposed keep sites that use links to increase their SEO out of Search Results. Unfortunately the SO usage pattern is such that it looks to Google like one of the link bait sites (many answers often include links to other sites with Documentation or a solution) causing SO to be penalized. The odd thing about the latest algorithm changes is that it appears to be having precisely the opposite effect, and is promoting a bunch of useless spammy blogs. Bummer... Google just got a whole lot less useful where SO is concerned.

Comment: Do you have any specific examples?

Comment: Yes, something happened.  For the first time in years, I'm getting hits on MSDN Forum posts again that rank higher than a SO post.  I'm guessing it is the Penguin 3.4 update of Dec 6th, give or take.

Comment: @oded well pretty much ANY search of the type I've been doing lately has spam all over it. For example simply using "NSlayoutconstraint" used to turn up all kinds of stackoverflow hits, now... 1 with the rest to BS sites all over the place. Google really screwed the pooch with that last one.

Comment: About the update: http://searchengineland.com/holidays-google-breaks-updates-rules-gives-fresh-penguin-updates-210367

Comment: @oded here is another more realistic example which usually would return far more results than the 2 I get now: "layout constraints on custom uitableviewcell not working"

Comment: @Cliff - can you try searches both when logged in and as anonymous? When logged in you get customized results which could very well be different.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference. In general I am NEVER logged into Google as I hate webmail more than I hate the OSX mail client :)- However trying that last search logged into the gmail account I am most likely to be logged into (when I forget to log out) I am getting the same useless results and not seeing much of a difference. I seem to be getting one or two stack hits mixed in with Lots of BS tutorials on blogs etc.

Comment: Whatever Google is doing, it is causing Apple Docs to show up at the top anytime your query contains an iOS or ObjC Class name. Sucks for getting answers to problems though...

Comment: @CliffRibaudo Similar things happen with other things too, except now I'll get a bunch of Ghits where the results are "foo in docs for v1.8", "foo in docs for v1.9", etc.  Multiple versions of the same page. Usually there's not all that much, if any, difference.

Comment: Now that you mention it...wow...I have been implementing/researching an unfamiliar (to me) library all day and I've been struggling to find information. Not only are useless results polluting the top 10, but the *same* useless results keep showing up to different queries.

Comment: @TimMedora note you can always get a stack exchange only google search at http://stackexchange.com/search which avoids the need to toss a site: in there for google... and lets you also get results from other SE sites (if Programmers.SE or gamedev had something to say about it for example).

Comment: I am going to say yes. This would explain the changes that are happening on SO that many users are getting fed up with. I see many blog posts on the decline of SO, but rarely see any reasons as to why the changes are happening. I've always thought that Google updates are responsible so that SO can maintain high traffic without being penalized. It's better for revenue, but no good for the users.

Answer (score 148):

Disclaimer - I'm not an SEO person at all.  So this is purely based on guessing as to the motives of someone who isn't me.

Looking at the information in [Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/holidays-google-breaks-updates-rules-gives-fresh-penguin-updates-210367), Google is trying to cut back on sites that are spammy.  Sites generating lots of crap content - you know the type.  You search for "how do I ..." and get those horrendously written sites that are just bulking up on content with advertisements on the page and rather crap material.

Google knows when people click these links and then hit back and click on another link because they didn't find what they are after on the first page.

You know what, lots of Stack Overflow questions are similarly poor. How often do you click a SO link and then go back because it didn't answer the question you really had?  You found yourself on a page that was closed as "not a real question" from '11 with a score of +1 thats still sitting around?  Posts that are nothing more than a copy of the documentation? Posts that are just (ultimately) link farms?

In the past I mentioned how some of our bad posts were showing up on Google ([As it currently stands, this summary is not a good fit for Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217913/213963)).

> [image: search result]

That was something that showed up as one of the top hits when you searched for "java groovy".  It doesn't show up as a top hit for me anymore (note that its also [been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764416/why-would-one-use-groovy-over-java) and that may have something to do with it too).

On the other hand, a search like "how do I compute prime numbers with scala" is presenting me with:

> [image]

Top three answers.  You know what, all three of those questions are quite reasonable, with long, up voted, accepted answers.

Google appears to have decided what questions and answers are good on Stack Overflow and what ones aren't up to ***Google's*** standards for what information it wants to serve to its users.

You know how to get material to show up on Google again at the top?  Write good questions, write good answers, close the crap and make the site not look like ehow.

We present Google with the information about what our good questions and answers are.  They are open.  They have up voted questions and up voted answers and the answers in the post aren't links to other sites or almost entirely copy and paste of existing documentation, or poor code dumps.

No, this does not mean that the answer to getting the SEO for Stack Overflow back is to reopen (or not close) poorly written questions and up vote them out of pity.  That would remove what little signal there is on Stack Overflow and make it awash in the noise.  It means reward the good better and make it so that the poorly written answers and link only answers and "does this work {code dump}" are removed.

The key is to try to make the information on the site helpful.  Quality is more important than quantity.

Keeping the lights on at Stack Overflow means making sure those advertisements are being served.  This means making sure that the site that Stack Overflow is, is the one that Google wants to give to its users.

We need to improve the quality of the signal and lower the amount of noise.

Good questions and answers are searchable.  The poorly written ones are worse than the documentation on the official sites.

Comment: Good answer. I'm not sure how correct it is, b.c who knows really. But I still receive lots of `answers.com` results in some searches to things... and I don't know how that site could still be on the first page of any search results. It's the worst site for answers ever. It's just spam basically.

Comment: @Sompuperoo I'm basing it on the small number of searches that I did for known SO questions turned up either the question if it was "good" or no SO questions if it wasn't so good. I had trouble finding any poor questions via search on Google. Given that most questions on SO aren't that great, this can have quite an impact on search results.

Comment: You are right, SO's quality needs to be improved. More users need to help in moderation.

Comment: related: [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601)

Comment: Sounds like Google's trying to link more to 'official documentation' than Q&A sites such as Stack Overflow.

Comment: Congratulations, you just earned the well-deserved "ehow basher" hat (!)

Comment: Ehhh! This is not about the quality of posts. One mans trash is another's gold and there is NO WAY that Google can judge the quality of post just because I go into one post, back out and try another. I do that all the time looking for insight into difficult questions. The only thing you can infer from the fact that I backed out of a question is that I was looking for something else, but it might answer it next time.

Comment: @Cliff Ribaudo: With Google, it's always about quality. Your statement probably applies to the people who post the low-quality content to begin with: we think it's low quality, they think it's just fine.

Comment: @BoltClock sure, but I think my point is that at least where SO is concerned, it is difficult to infer quality from the fact that someone enters and leaves SO posts. The answers and solutions are often too complex for that type of simplistic analysis. Perhaps that is too SO specific for Google's algorithms... but I would think that the fact that one goes down a list of search results picking out the SO results and NOT the non-SO results WOULD be a good indicator that the searcher thinks SO is a relevant site.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo You're right. Google can't *really* decide which page to show you. But *somehow* Google has to decide which page to put on top, and which on the second place, etc? It can't possible show you *all* the thousands, if not millions, of results. As I don't use Google, I don't know if the "new way" is better or worse, but by using *any* internet search engine, you are relying on the judgement of an algorithm to determine what you read...

Comment: _"Google appears to have decided what questions and answers are good on Stack Overflow and what ones aren't up to Google's standards"_ Well then Google better get it's ass busy in the SO review queues.

Comment: If that is the case maybe the questions score could be included in the snippet that Google gets to see and then google can maybe in the future use it - but in the mean time we can use it. so something like Question Title (score) snippet.

Comment: @TheresaForster I'll have to dig more, but I think it already is.

Comment: @gnat: Instead of automatically deleting questions without user input, what about just automatically injecting the page's html header with robots "noindex" for similar criteria (-1 or lower score). That could lower any Google penalty for bad content and let other posts bubble up to the top of the search results.

Comment: @LouD [post I referred](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601) is about _closed_ questions, that is ones that already have a fairly solid input from credible users (in the form of close votes)

Answer (score 24):

I think you are relating to what is known in the SEO world as Google Panda or Penguin. Both of these algorithms could be having a fun time with this sites ranking.

Panda is about content while Penguin is about backlinks which, considering that SOs usage policy is to have links back to their original page, could be causing problems considering the amount of spammy sites which reuse this sites own content while still linking without using `rel="nofollow"`.

From ahrefs I have noticed a sudden spike in backlinks: https://ahrefs.com/site-explorer/overview/subdomains/?target=stackoverflow.com since the last Penguin update which could be causing problems. That was the first tool that came to mind but I find it is one of the most accurate.

So this one area that could be damaging SO.

The algorithm used by Google to attempt to judge low quality crap and down vote it (Panda)...much like we do could also be in play. It is not as sophisticated as the other answer states but SO could be hit since it has a lot of copied content which exists else where on the internet in a more authoritive source, for example, an answer which quotes Ember homepage might rank lower than the Ember homepage itself now whereas before it did not).

Some of the most visited questions and answers are, at times, copied content which will make them rank lower. Add on a lot more of the same questions and answers and you probably have a heavy penalty from the Panda update.

This is not so much about a human knowing poor quality, the Google Bot is not that intelligent, for example:https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=CouchDB+over+MongoDB&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=9huQVOjGFtLT7AaerIGQBQ the second link on that result points to a very low quality question on this site (despite being heavily upvoted) which, since it is does not come under the contraints of Panda has not been down voted on its keywords.

It is also good to note that the questions backlink profile could also be effecting it. If its backlink profile is not spammed too much (since down voting tends to happen page by page, not site by site) then it will rank the same as it used to.

So I think this is definitely Google Panda / Penguin, but which one is the question. I cannot truly answer that without investing a lot of time to study the true profile, plus you would need access to their GWT (Google Webmaster Tools) and GA (Google Analytics) to truly uncover what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

I've found quite a number of articles relating to recent updates to Google's algorithms, and I'm sure what you're observing is not a fluke -- the results are different now.

[One](http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/76896-SEO-Google-Makes-Penguin-Algorithm-More-Slippery) source says Google made updates to target sites with lots of keywords and links from low quality sites, etc, and continue to improve.

[Another](http://www.business2community.com/infographics/history-top-google-algorithm-updates-infographic-01078102) says Google is improving it's understanding of semantics, giving a little more preference to local results, and, of course, promoting high quality over low quality.

[This site](http://moz.com/google-algorithm-change) lists the major updates to the algorithm and doesn't show any **major** update in more than a month.

I'd say Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange are fine, but questions linked to from poor websites would be less prominent. Blogs and local content that are of good quality have probably jumped in prominence, jumping over some Stack Exchange results.

This doesn't explain why you're getting more "spammy" results, though. A couple of the articles mention roll outs **and** roll backs...

I tried some of the searches you mentioned in your comments for your original post and I got quality results with multiple SO answers.

Comment: in the comments to my original question I provided a link to an SEO site that thinks there have been THREE updates to Penguin in Dec alone. This seems to agree with what I'm seeing, where quality of search results have been steadily diminishing over the last two weeks. The results that are replacing seem to be VERY low quality blogs which appear to be scraping content from elsewhere.