# Tiku (answers scraped from SO) comes before SO for me

Tags: discussion, seo, scraping

If I run [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=50&espv=2&q=django%20admin%20field%20duplication%20inline%20generic%20many2many) search. I get these results:

[image: My search results]

Two from Django's Docs, Two from SO, and two from tiku, a site that's scraping [SO](http://tiku.io/questions/1118096/django-admin-filter-many2many-relations-independently) [questions](http://tiku.io/questions/640047/generic-many-to-many-relationships-in-django-admin).

AFAIK scraping is ok, and they do attribute back.

But is this not a SEO concern for SO?

Comment: The place to report scrapers ranking higher than the original SE site used to be [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-stack-exchange-content-copiers-here), but you'll now need to follow the dupe link and read whatever it says (I didn't)

Comment: Google doesn't like SO anymore since its last search engine update in early December.  That SO has content quality problems is pretty obvious to anybody so it is not exactly a surprise.  Simple things that scrapers can do are omitting unanswered questions (a million of them right now) and omitting duplicates that link to a stale old answer.  Perhaps skipping downvoted posts as well.  Pretty noticeable btw, I'm getting a lot less votes for my old posts.  For SE to do the same is, well, not so easy...

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sure I saw a discussion about how we should change the link type for second page results (?) could we now do the same so that every google cache of a duplicate points to it's duplicate immediately?

Comment: @HansPassant is this what your'e thinking of? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280328/did-google-recently-update-algorithms-in-a-way-thats-bad-for-stack-overflow-que?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

> tl;dr: **Send all reports of SCRAPERs to us via the form on the
>   [*contact us*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) page, linked at
>   the bottom of every page.** Please include:
>
> - the URL of the copied post
> - the URL of the original post on SE
> - for high-rankers, the search string you used (and the name of the search engine, if not Google)
> - any other details you noticed and want to share, because you're awesome
>
> (This is the end of the tl;dr section.)
>
> I used to be the *de facto* curator of the two SCRAPER reporting posts
>   here on Meta: [one for
>   attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-stack-exchange-content-without-following-attribution-rules)
>   and [another for
>   ranking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-stack-exchange-content-copiers-here).
>   The community was pretty good about using them, but like all list
>   questions, they eventually turned into unmanageable messes that were
>   hard to search. I've just saved all of the information posted there
>   and deleted them.
>
> The community team has been working on improving its internal process
>   for SCRAPERs behind the scenes, and now that I've joined the staff,
>   I'm going to be in charge of it. By funneling everything through our
>   usual support mechanisms, we can organize our own efforts better, and
>   as a side effect, we won't be giving Google-juice to the very sites
>   that are being called out for being naughty.

[Pop's Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/175002)