# Stack Exchange: A database of knowledge or an expert help site?

Tags: discussion

I am new to the Stack Exchange community, and since the day one, I struggled to understand one of the most fundamental aspects of its mission. Many posts on Meta have been written to broadly discuss this topic. Yet, an answer to one of the most important questions is not clearly delivered to every new user. On the contrary, trying to find the answer leads to some contradictory and confusing results.

To the point, my question is:

**Is Stack Exchange a database of knowledge (in the form of questions and answers) or a help site where expert volunteers contribute their time to help others with difficult questions?**

Now, despite the fact that there is likely to be a gray zone between those two missions, everyone should be clear as to which one is more important before they press the "Ask Question" button or decide to criticize a question.

## Differences

I think that most of you already realize what the consequences of each mindset are, but let me summarize:

#### 1) SE as a Database of Knowledge

Principle:

- If a question, no matter how simple, has not been asked yet, it should be asked.

Some arguments:

- Each of us needs a quick reminder of simple solutions from time to time and SE makes it much easier to find a solution than to browse through manuals. Isn't it first in Google search results for such questions anyways? How much time did such questions save each one of us at some point in the past?
- If none of us are experts in everything and every one of us (even secretly) actually benefits from simple questions, why shouldn't we contribute answers to someone else's simple questions and tolerate those as well?

#### 2) SE as an Expert Help Site

Principle:

- Questions should be asked only about problems for which the answer cannot be found using other means, i.e. extensive research online, reading manuals etc.

Some arguments:

- Realize that by asking a question, you waste someone else's time.
- The person answering your question is doing the work for you (for free), so ask only as the last resort.
- The flood of simple questions decreases the SNR and makes it more difficult to find those intriguing, brilliant questions and answers.

I assume that in both cases questions should be: on topic, clear and well written.

## Why am I confused?

#### Opinion of the Community

The community and the FAQs seems to be giving mixed signals. First, look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour, which clearly states:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed
>   answers to **every** question about programming.

Every question? Well, that sounds pretty much like **1)** to me. But what does the community really thinks? Just check out the most voted answer to the question [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users):

> A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. In
>   fact, asking a question on Stack Overflow is the absolute last thing
>   you ever want to do. You want to avoid it at all costs. You want to
>   think of it as a horrible shame that will forever haunt you and pass
>   down from you to your descendants.

That sounds very much like **2)** to me.

#### Actual Users Behavior

Let's look at some selected, most voted questions on SO (all time):

- [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)
- [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)
- [What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)
- [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)

and maybe a more recent example of this month:

- [What does i = (i, ++i, 1) + 1; do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614396/what-does-i-i-i-1-1-do)

According to **2)**, those questions should make the OPs and their descendants live in horrible shame forever. Yet, those are some of the most voted questions. Votes mean reputation. And reputation is here to promote and reward certain behaviors on the site, isn't it?

## So which is it?

Or maybe there is a discrepancy between what the founders of the site wanted and what the community believes is right?

And please do not say it's somewhere in the middle. New users need simple guidelines, call them ideals they should strive to follow. Then, reality comes and things tend to fuzzify naturally anyways. But is there a consensus about which of those should be emphasized more?

## EDIT:

So, the question attracted a reasonable amount of viewers and provoked a very useful discussion (to me at least). However, I am also trying to understand the reason for the downvotes, which I believe on Meta mean that I have made claims that the community disagrees with. Therefore, I feel that I need to clarify my position a bit:

- I am not a proponent of any of the two views (in this question at least), rather, I have noticed a contradiction which I believe exists and has been confirmed by others in the discussion.
- I perfectly understand that the world is not black and white, but I deliberately tried to be more strict about taking a side here. My observation was that: whenever someone openly tried to raise a similar question, the answer was: `it's in the middle` or `it just doesn't work this way`. That would be fine, however, many other questions that hint on the problem (some of them already referred to in this discussion) show that people have very (VERY) strong opinions about this problem. I can also see that in the comments given to questions asked on SO and the "close" votes. Now, acknowledging there is no consensus in the community is something different than saying that there is a consensus that it's "in the middle".
- I really hoped that a variety of answers to my question will make new users who care and Google that issue either:

  a) understand that `both types or questions are acceptable and both are likely to be criticized` and for instance feel better whenever they are referred to as rep-whores for answering a Googlable question or when they are bashed for asking one while thinking they are contributing to the body of SO knowledge.

  b) understand what is expected of them in case there actually is a consensus.

Comment: Not my downvote, but all your examples are six to seven years old. They are hardly suitable to discuss today's guidelines.

Comment: So the answer is, things have changed? To what then? What are the current guidelines? Or are you saying that all those votes are old and the question of what big o is used to be more difficult to answer in the past? No matter how old they are, they still serve as examples for new users.

Comment: Besides, those examples are not really the point, since they are clearly justified by the pretty current statement on http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: It's somewhere in the middle. :) Both are correct to some extent. The ideal goal is to build an archive of great questions and answers that everyone can search, and ideally never needs to ask a  question again that exists there. But the place is also a help site and full of duplicates because it's human beings asking and answering the questions and helping each other, getting things wrong, and being lazy and/or incompetent. There is no clear consensus on whether totally easily Googleable stuff should be a SO question, or downvoted to oblivion; that's probably why no clear guidelines exist.

Comment: Don't stop reading at "every question about programming". Some of the subsequent requirements will exclude a large segment of questions. At best read it as "every question about programming, following the guidelines below".

Comment: Ok, in that case, why is my question being downvoted if it touches a problem that does not have a clear solution or for which clear guidelines exist? :-)

Comment: What will happen if the answer to your question is 1, 2 or in the middle? Are we going to have a follow up question to instruct the community to follow the rules implied by 1, 2 or the middle?

Comment: Meta votes are ... something else. I'd guess disagreement with some of your statements/arguments. But well, no rep lost. Don't worry too much.

Comment: @Bart, my point is, that yes, you can go deep into every FAQ or Meta question and try to interpret it. But, such a fundamental problem which leads to very erratic behavior on the site should have clear, easy to find guidelines that leaves little to interpretation.

Comment: Good luck coming up with those.

Comment: @Bart, thanks for the kind words, but I don't quite care about the rep here. I care about being a good member of a community I am aspiring to be part of. However, to know how, and  if it is a community I want to be part of in the first place, it would be great to know what their goals actually are.

Comment: Then stick around and watch. You are never ever going to get crystal clear guidelines. Such guidelines are first of all impossible to formulate. And second of all, the things that are crystal clear to some, are muddy, unclear, and open to misinterpretation for others. What you see now is the  outcome of how the site has evolved over time. And not only that, it's how the text reflecting this evolution has evolved over time. Follow along on Meta and you'll see discussions every now and then, trying to make even more clear what we thought was already perfectly clear.

Comment: @Bart You should formulate an answer from that comment speech, was inspiring...

Comment: @James, I agree.

Comment: Especially that it is hard not to notice that there seem to be many very strict rules and guidelines regarding other aspects of SO, while no current voice exists on such fundamental question in a single place, even if that voice is "there is no existing consensus, meaning, both behaviors are acceptable and both will also be criticized"

Comment: `there is no existing consensus, meaning, both behaviors are acceptable and both will also be criticized` Ha, that's nicely put. I'd say that is a fairly accurate characterization of the situation.

Comment: @Pekka웃, to address your earlier comment, I just looked at this months (certainly recent) most voted answers on SO and I can see for instance this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614396/what-does-i-i-i-1-1-do  for which one google search gives: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator for which first sentence says: " binary operator that evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value "

Comment: I think this discussion clarified a lot to me. It would be really worth to put that into an answer in my opinion.

Comment: I think this question coherently points out an interesting contradiction, or at least confusion. It should be said, though, that (completely leaving aside different guidelines from six years ago and today) you can't just compare raw votes on questions that have existed for so long. You have to at least consider views, and/or views over time. A six-year-old question that has a score of 3700 and 700k views is not necessarily "better" in the long term than a year-old question with 100k views and 1000 score, as a contrived example.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, that is an important point indeed. Comparing raw votes can be misleading, especially if time is not taken into account. Still, my first examples are all "old", and if you look at this months results, there are similar examples (comparing to other questions of the month). I think it is safe to say that votes are not a reflection of the current sites guidelines. But, since votes promote behavior through reputation (and many new users learn by observing others), they are creating de facto standard. Maybe, it would be better to embrace it?

Comment: Oh yeah, votes are pretty much all we have as far as measuring "goodness" here; I accept that, and they work pretty darn well. I'm just saying that it's not a perfect signal.

Comment: Oh, also: "a discrepancy between what the founders of the site wanted and what the community [wants]". Never mind the users, there  [was discrepancy between what the two _founders_ wanted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/603977)!

Comment: Excellent reference @JoshCaswell!

Comment: @And re your response - yes that's a Googleable question, but arguably a very non-obvious and complex one that appealed to a lot of people. The kind of question I'm talking about is more of the "how do I do (very very basic thing) in X" variety.

Comment: @Pekka웃, of course, I can see that. And I believe that is a perfectly valid question for SO. I was just pointing out the contradiction between that and the very popular answer on Meta which explains how much research you should do: `A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of.`

Answer (score 10):

The two purposes for the site as you define them aren't mutually exclusive. The first point is indeed the primary goal. A repository of knowledge is what we're trying to create. But that does by no means imply that all conceivable questions are on topic. And they don't need to be.

There is no real value in hosting the answer to every conceivable programming question you can think of. Not only that, you would end up putting the bar so low, that you would end up drowning the few gems in a sea of mediocrity.

So we try to put up a set of guidelines, trying to optimize for pearls. For those things that aren't trivially found elsewhere. We're not a replacement for basic teaching material. But we're there if you're stuck on an actual programming problem. Something you've been scratching your head over for a while. That has got you stumped. And not the "I googled for 5 minutes" kind of deal.

## Crystal clear guidelines aren't going to happen.

Well meaning users, moderators and employees alike have spent countless hours debating the scope of sites on Meta. They have come up with boundaries and texts describing them. The FAQ is an ever changing entity and the Help Center has seen countless revisions. So now everything is perfectly clear, right?

No. And it won't ever be. The world isn't black and white. And even if something seems to be crystal clear to you, others will interpret it differently. And not because they are wilfully ignorant. It's just that when writing such content, perfect clarity doesn't exist. All you can hope is that you've placed some fence posts in the right locations, and that the chains in between don't allow for too much movement.

And to complicate matters even further, even in the hypothetical case that there's no room for interpretation, perfect enforcement is even more unlikely to happen. You care. We care. But the far majority of visitors to the site doesn't know, or simply doesn't care.

And I guess that brings us to some of your example questions and others like it. Although their votes are the results of several years of vote accumulation, there are others like it that seem at odds with what the site says it's about, but which have still received their significant amount of upvotes. Why? The site has strong Google-fu, and people found it valuable. They appreciated it. And whether or not the post was in line with what the site would like is often of secondary importance at best.

Answer (score 5):

It just isn't a simple formula that you can stick in a bottle and hand out to anybody who wants to drink.  There have been plenty of cases of ho-hum questions turning into fantastic Q+A that's been a major resource to many programmers.  Not infrequently after having the question edited and reformulated several times.  And fantastically detailed and researched questions can easily never get an answer and left forgotten and ignored.

The law of averages however applies strongly.  The odds that a poor question ever turns into helpful Q+A are just not very good.  A starting point for good Q+A will always be a decently researched question with strong participation from the questioner, responding to comments and tweaking the question, and plentiful help from multiple SO users, editing and answering.

Do avoid staring at ancient Q+A to get insight.  Content at SO had a very high ranking at Google and the ones you quoted got massive number of views.  701798 for that Python question, that doesn't happen very often.  Not anymore.  Given that three quarter of a million programmers looked at it and only 0.49% of them thought the question was worthy of a helpful vote does put a better perspective on it.  Not that impressive.

Q+A like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680654/an-enum-constant-contains-all-the-enum-constants-of-the-same-enum-class) would be more representative, 13 votes out of 230 views, ten times better than the Python question.  It does slack off over time however.