# Is Stack Overflow losing its popularity?

Tags: discussion

Is Stack Overflow losing its popularity? Or it got even more popular that not enough people to answer questions? On this site I used to get 10 different answers in 1 minute in the past, now I am lucky if I have any answer at all over a weekend. What is your experience?

Comment: It's not losing its popularity, it's just that the ratio of question askers to avid answerers seems to have skyrocketed over the years. So each question gets less attention. (I'm saying this without any hard evidence, but it certainly seems to be the case.)

Comment: SOAP ain't as sexy as it was back in the good ol' aughts. My guess is that there are simply a lot fewer people working with it on a daily basis.

Comment: How on earth a question gets 10 down votes but it's answer gets 6 up votes:-) how can a horrible questions answer is very helpful to many people?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are asking [spring-ws] questions.  Visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-ws/topusers) to see what is happening in that tag.

Upper-left corner is a pretty decent hint why you are not getting answers.  80% of the questions in the past 30 days did not get an answer.  That's pretty abysmal of course and puts the odds you'll get any helpful answer at slim to none.

You can use the same page to find the underlying reason.  Visit the profile of the experts, the SO-users that have a substantial number of posts in the tag.  Click through to the Activity tab, Answers, sort by Newest.  Easy to see the underlying issue, @Skaffman has posted only 4 answers in the past month.  @Thivent hasn't posted any in over 4 years.  @Kumjunnen only posted 6 answers last month.  @evandongen only 2.  Etcetera.

These numbers are across all tags these users participate in, not just [spring-ws].  So, yes, there's some magic lost, the subject of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions).

Otherwise nothing particularly wrong with popularity, the reforms in the summer of 2013 and 2014 made SO accessible to a [lot more users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/17034).  They just don't ask questions that require an expert to answer.  So there just isn't any need for them anymore.  You'll probably be fine when you ask a basic question, you'll have to look elsewhere for a hard one.  I don't know where.

Answer (score -5):

There are three questions (including the one in the title), increasingly more easy to answer. Lets start with the last one and work backwards.

> Do you have similar experiences?

No

> Is Stack Overflow losing its magic?

No. Because there was never any magic in the first place. There were just people putting in effort.
The technology involved might be advanced enough that it looks like magic to you ...

> Is Stack Overflow losing its popularity?

Probably not. At least not when going for the number of hits SO receives.

[image]

Source: [QuantCast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com)

The ratio of experts compared to non-experts visiting the site has probably just dropped.

Of course you might blame SO that some of the non-experts, who should have sought a different vocation, are still around. AFAIK there are no statistics on that.