# Is Stack Overflow losing its shine?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

Due to insane number of bad questions are being asked every day it's getting increasingly difficult to find good questions that deserve some answers.

As a result, good questions are getting buried under numerous homework kinds of questions and getting few views, which encourages many experienced users to leave.

Today I was checking some questions on Android and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529619/how-to-create-group-by-query-in-android), which is well-formed but still has a very low view count.

Is this not alarming? What is your view?

Comment: Related: [How to lure professionals to Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324072/2675154)

Comment: Finding questions to answer is a much smaller problem [than wading through crap to find answers when you need them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160565/general-reference-questions-create-low-quality-dead-ends-for-googlers), the avoidance of which was essentially the whole point of the thing in the first place. That said, people have been crying the end of the world^Wsite since about day 2.

Comment: The "Is SO losing X?" franchise continues to expand... the earlier installments were  [Is Stack Overflow losing its popularity?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296310) and [StackOverflow losing its luster?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239032).

Comment: Do we have to go through this again? Don't you have an interesting analysis or some new thoughts that we should all pay attention to?

Comment: I thought this was a burnination request just looking at the title in the `Hot Meta Posts` box :D

Comment: SO has never been shiny. You just thought it was shiny because you Googled programming questions and found answers on SO. Those bits are the exception that proves the rule. (I admit that I briefly hoped you were referring to my recent Android question, which I thought was decent but got me a Tumbleweed badge. I wanted a way to debug Android apps without connecting a phone, not a badge.)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 those aren't exceptions though, Googling answers to programming questions is the typical usage of SO for most people. So as long as it's working (and it is), SO is still shiny IMO

Comment: Nothing new: [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506/7586), [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/7586), [Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252756/7586)

Comment: Concur completely with the notion that the hostility/negativity level on SO is increasing and just killing the notion of trying to help people. Seems as though there's this snake-like instinct for people to react negatively - in whatever way possible - to even microscopic defects in a question or an answer via downvotes, snarky comments, whatever, that somehow the soul of the site has been lost in the shuffle. Part of the joy of the site is, or used to be, helping spread technical information as best we can to those who need it, because we ALL used to be there...

Comment: @samgak - I'm not referring to what most people see of SO; I'm referring to what SO mostly consists of. It's a giant junk heap, and then Google makes it easy to find the rare gems. The typical usage of SO you refer to leads to a biased perspective, making it look like SO is nothing but wonderful, quality content. The exceptional usage of SO - hanging out here all day farming rep - allows those users to see what really goes on. For every decent question, there are a hundred awful ones. But it's okay, because Google.

Comment: Anyone else find it puzzling that people respond to comments of "It's getting worse" with "It's been getting worse for a long time, stop worrying"?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes, it really is ok because Google. If I'm eating in a fancy restaurant, and the food's nice, tastes good and is healthy, presentation is good, price is reasonable, what do I care if behind the scenes the kitchen is a shambles and for every dish that makes it onto my table there are 20 others that ended up as food waste?

Comment: @samgak - It's more like "if the Yelp reviews are positive, what does it matter that eating there more often than once a month will make you sick?", or "if I had a good meal there, what does it matter that the other 99% of the patrons didn't?". And that's right, it doesn't matter... to whoever had a good experience. The fact remains that SO is a garbage heap, and the only people who are bothered by this are those who thought SO was an amazing place, started spending more time here, and noticed the garbage. It's a pretty darned useful garbage heap.

Comment: bad questions? you mean like this question for example?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 those analogies don't really work for me, because I don't believe that 99% - or even a majority - of people using SO in the typical fashion (i.e. searching for answers to questions) have a bad experience. It's extremely easy to find an answer to almost any programming question, even with the low ratio of good questions. And I don't believe that using it as a resource makes you sick. What you are really talking about it not unsatisfied patrons, but the jaded part time chefs who work at the restaurant pro bono. Once they get to that state, maybe it's just time to take a break?

Comment: @samgak - Yeah, it's basically the part-time chefs getting upset that the place is infested with roaches, but, luckily, most customers ask for dishes without roaches, and that actually works. But that doesn't remove the roaches. The roaches simply aren't a thing for most people, who don't even know about the roaches. Except that sometimes meal orders can't be heard over all the noisy roach-stomping, so that's a downside. And, the fact remains that _the good questions are an exception_. Just because most people don't see the bad ones doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: StackOverflow is my Nr1 online work aid. Lets just keep weeding out the questions that contains no effort or thought from the topic creator and keep being awesome.

Answer (score 35):

> What I noticed that due to insane number of bad questions are being asked every day it's getting increasingly difficult day by day to find good questions which deserves some answers.

Well, if you really want to help to cure this, **use all of your available down votes and close votes / flags every day**.

You may specialize upon your favorite tags to do that, and just watch what's coming in there.

That may get difficult and tedious, feeling like Sisyphos work, especially for frequent *poor quality* tags like [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).

*Poor quality* mostly refers to a broad unskilled mass of questioners and audience lurking on particular programming language tags.

From this POV the related question [How to lure professionals to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324072/how-to-lure-professionals-to-stack-overflow)  mentioned in the comments might get some significance.

Comment: No, the whole point is that using all of my available down votes and close votes / flags **does not contribute to solving the problem at all**. Why would I choose to engage in Sisyphus work? For what reason?

Comment: @torazaburo _"No, the whole point is that using all of my available down votes and close votes / flags does not contribute to solving the problem at all."_ It actually does, and you would contribute positively. The problem is the poorly asked question in 1st place, not the potential _problem_ stated there. Well, get more powers for the tag (e.g. a [tag:php] dupe hammer) and have the powers to bail out bad questions early.

Comment: @torazaburo ^^^ In short: We're not here as a _personal help desk_ to _solve the OP's problems_.

Comment: @torazaburo Sure, if everyone in the community just throws their hands in the air and says *bah, why bother, it is useless*, nothing is going to change. This is a poor reason _not_ to moderate your favorite tags. If you don't want to do it, just say it, but don't hide behind a useless *no-one else cares so why should I*. It _is_ frustrating to try to do something and see that nobody else cares, but at least, I'm honest with myself by doing the little I can.

Comment: @Tunaki What a ridiculous comment. I spend several hours a day pruning, commenting, close-voting on my tags. I'm not quite sure why I do, but I do. the point is that EXACTLY BECAUSE I DO THAT, I know that as things stand, all my efforts, or those of 100 other people like me, will not solve the problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "we're not a personal help desk to solve the OP's problem" -- still, Stack Overflow's baseline promises exactly that - "Ask Questions, Get Answers - No Distraction".

Comment: @torazaburo: I agree with your sentiment, but there are nicer ways to say that you disagree with someone - their view is different to yours, and not worthy of ridicule.

Comment: @jivan but that's a byproduct of the system, not the goal.

Comment: Amen to @haifer. This pervasive sense of "I'm right, everyone else is stupid" that has evolved on an increasing basis by some here at SO takes away the servant spirit that created it. If we "deign" to answer some newcomer's questions, we're not here for the right reasons. We should be here to serve, not to demean.

Comment: @DavidW The most questions I answer are actually _newcomer questions_, the only criteria for answering or down/close voting is the quality and usefulness of the question's content.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And perhaps that's the core of the issue - to the person *asking* the question, the usefulness is presumably high. When we make the presumption of saying "your question isn't of value," we realize the site's purpose isn't to inform, its to judge, and our increasingly ruthless sentences are downvotes and closures. When that becomes more important than helping people, we've lost our way.  Person A will never know that Person B's questions (or answers) were closed or downvoted, so the expectation that such votes accomplish a self-regulation function is a false premise.

Comment: @DavidW _"When that becomes more important than helping people ..."_ You probably misunderstood, that actually is _helping people_ (plural!). As mentioned helpdesk like support isn't useful in the long term.

Comment: @DavidW: "the **servant spirit** that created [SO]"?! You are projecting your own desires and perspective. So much of the system has been designed [against helping just one person](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) from [the very beginning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21968/159251). See also [Optimizing for Pearls](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: @JoshCaswell There is an irony in defending the meta-merit of designing help by not helping, but not recognizing that in doing so the very help to be provided is being lost. We do not get to measure the value of the help provided; those who receive it do. That's not me "projecting my desires." If SO becomes nothing more than geeks such as myself falling in love with their own knowledge and condescending toward those who aspire to gain it, it has no future.

Comment: @DavidW: We certainly *can* measure the help provided by measuring *how many people* it helped. It's not a perfect measure -- in fact it's quite flawed -- but it's a first approximation that's worth keeping in mind. Pretending that the help one question gives to one person is *indistinguishable in essentially all cases* from the help another question gives 500 or 5000 people is just an absurd focus on the few exceptions in order to deny the generalities.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The measure of the help you reference is totally self-serving - it measures the help *SO chooses to measure* in response to the help SO deigns to provide. That's the whole point. SO is becoming so self-focused that it is losing its perspective. *We* deign to provide help *only* in the way *we* decide, and *deride* those who dare to request it in a manner *we* don't approve - and pat ourselves on the back for each and every upvote we get as a self-congratulatory measure of our own success. We'll just have to agree to disagree on this issue, and that's cool, too.

Comment: @DavidW: That was literally the entire intention from the very beginning: to help programmers in a specific, well-defined way, rather than trying to cover every possible avenue. There is no "becoming" here. There was never any other mission.

Comment: @NathanTuggy We have vastly different views on what "help" is about. Help isn't about defining it on *our* terms. It's defining it in terms of the people who need the help. That's the essence of servanthood, which should be at the very core of any help- or service-based resource. That's *not* what SO is becoming. I am humbled to help anyone amid the vast experiences here. What you're telling me is that I should "evolve" into something quite the opposite, intoxicated with my own expertise. Different strokes, I suppose, but that's just not me. Cheers.

Comment: @DavidW: I see no need to give up humility, unless humility is defined as "it's impossible for anyone but the asker to judge question quality" or similarly. That's just false humility, though. There *is* expertise here. There *are* consistent ways to judge question usefulness beyond individual whim. Denying that is not humility.

Comment: @DavidW I'm very much with Nathan's arguments. There's nothing to expect making this site better by just _"helping"_ new users and answering VLQ and low research effort questions as you seem to be suggesting as _helpful_. That's what comments, (close-) votes and duplicates are for.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ (and others) I appreciate your differing positions, and understand them. We just disagree. Understand, however, there's a difference between measuring "help" and "question quality." They're not the same. Sometimes, helping others isn't exciting, or fresh, or compelling; sometimes, its telling someone how to tie their shoes just one more time.That's all. Appreciate the discussion, and thanks for hearing my side.

Answer (score 20):

I have to admit that over the years I've gone from highly engaged, to mostly meta, to hardly ever. Now I just tend to pop in when I've got a question.

I used to fret over this, but now I consider that I've "done my time" and moved on. However I do recognise those feelings of helplessness: seeing the unending pile of carp* that my close votes never seemed to even dent.

I think it's important to remember that lots of things *have* been tried and added over the years, though us 'old' users may forget - or never even see them. New users get lots of automated 'hand holding' before asking their first questions. (Of course, the ones who just go 'click-click-tldr' are unhelpable), and all the review tools, flags, close votes are so many different layers of defence. There's even an [AutoReviewComment](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) plugin out there, or so I've been told :)

There is a trade-off between 'being nice' (which there have been regular calls for) and quality. Automated quality in any case. I suspect the only way to 'be nice' and assure quality is to have real humans doing the triaging and guiding people individually. But that is not everyone's idea of fun.

[image]

**UPDATE: I'm not thinking so much of a LearnerOverflow for beginner programmers, but more of a 'naughty step' for persistently low-quality questioners.**

Maybe one idea could be to have a 'learners' StackOverflow? A bit like the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) for [English Language & Usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), or [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) for [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)? A persistent 'naughty' user on StackOverflow, rather than being banned for life, could be gently nudged/pushed/shoved onto 'Learners'.

Of course, this is not without problems: as it could just be seen as a 'trashcan' for rubbish questions. But I would consider it more as a [purgatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purgatory) for 'rubbish' askers.

It would also require a cohort of motivated 'helpers', but personally I think that it could work better, because it would provide a clear mental demarcation between *StackOverflow where I come to ask and answer interesting questions* and *LearnerOverflow where I come to help newbies learn how to ask interesting questions*. I mean, wouldn't you rather go and help clean up a riverbed every few months, rather than have effluent flowing into your bathtub?

And you could even imagine that once the user on LearnerOverflow gets to a given reputation, they gain access to StackOverflow again.

*(My apologies to the dev team who are staring at the screen thinking "#$%&! another £$_%ing exception!")*

*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: This has [certainly never been suggested before](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/propose-newbie-overflow-site-or-section)….

Comment: @NathanTuggy, a) that was a long time ago, b) I'm not talking about moving questions, but moving *users*, c) ELL/ELU show that it *can* be done, d) the problem is not going away any time soon.

Comment: As an ELL answerer, I have to take some exception to your idea that ELL is for the "easy" ELU questions. It's for *second-language learners*, some of whom have quite tricky questions indeed. (And a substantial chunk of ELU is just word-requests and similar, which are as dead-easy as anything you could wish to see, and have been hovering on the verge of going off-topic for years without actually plunging off.)

Comment: The numerous Newbie Overflow proposals have never successfully carved out a similar niche, and I'm not convinced they can. If anything, the age of the original ideas shows that this isn't going to turn out much better just by throwing the same idea around again: the SE climate has not gotten *more* favorable toward that particular style of audience segregation in that time.

Comment: Proposed since then as well: [Why are there beginner and advanced English sites on the network but not programming?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266443), [Would it be a terrible idea to split so up into a tiered platform?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252781), [Should we fork SO for beginning programmers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254381), [Can we separate Stack Overflow by experience level?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261956), and then there was "Stack Overflow Academy", which led to [Can we make this meta site work for mentoring?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268779)

Comment: Why make a separate site for the active users, when you could instead as inactive users just hang out in chat. No point in making a separate site for the majority,

Answer (score 8):

As a relatively new user (6 months or so), to say it is losing its shine is certainly not true for people starting out on their programming journey. This is, I think, an interesting addition to the question - Is Stack Overflow losing its shine for experienced users? If so this is a big problem as it is the experienced users who make it so brilliant.

Interestingly, my own usage would indicate that the methods in place to maintain quality are semi-working, I appreciate I am a just one user, but my experience is as follows:

- Having used the site for six months, I am very limited still in what I can do.
- It's still very hard to find questions to ask that are not already on here. I'd argue this isn't down to lack of effort as I have programmed almost every day in the last 6 months ([green squares!](https://github.com/JoeWroe)).
- One area that I am completely unrestricted in (especially if I just click, click, submit without reading), is asking questions.

The final point above is the crux to the issue. In my opinion, I like the limiting of features, but I can see that the key to gaining access to new features is asking questions. Therefore, the limiting is currently driving people in my position to ask questions.

With this in mind, I'd propose, maybe the limiting of the ability to ask questions if you're new to the site, or retrospective action perhaps for people who ask questions that are duplicates or just rubbish. Something like a 2 week question ban if your post is closed for a certain reason. Equally I understand that this will make it near on impossible for new users to progress until the have reached a level where they can ask meaningful questions (by which time I'd argue they are probably pretty decent programmers), therefore I'd also support new ways of progressing as a user to unlock new features (but that's for another question).

Comment: ".. the key to gaining access to new features is asking questions": you forget *answering* questions.

Comment: @RadLexus not exactly, admittedly it was an oversight of mine to have not mentioned it but perhaps that points to another issue with the limiting?

As a Junior user, over the last 6 months, I have found it hard to find questions good enough to ask and I can hands down say that finding questions to ask is immeasurably easier than finding questions to answer that have not already been done!

Comment: I focus almost entirely on one tag on SO, and I've only ever asked one question. That said, with more time under my belt, I realize that some of those easy pitch-and-catch answers I offered should have been down voted and flagged as dupes or OT. *By answering questions I didn't know I should flag for close, I added to the problem*. With low average question quality, it certainly makes it hard to *find* good questions to answer. That said, editing borderline questions to improve their quality is one of the most beneficial acts a user can perform and will add reputation.

Comment: One point about the "2-week ban". Something that draconian raises a reaction from the guilty person/victim, and leads to bad feeling and perhaps quarrels. What could work better is a very gentle increase in "minimum question interval", say a 10% increase each time. 10% isn't worth starting a quarrel about and is more likely to promote "how can I improve my questions?" thinking rather than "why do they all hate me?". You guide horses with gentle pressure, not sharp tugs on the reins.

Comment: are you aware of [rolling question rate limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/165773)? This feature was introduced in end 2014, last time tweaked [few weeks ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/839601): "Rolling rate-limits kick in faster. Like, _immediately_. If your first question is downvoted and you try to ask another one 40 minutes later, you'll be forced to wait at least a day..."

Comment: @jon-harper Thanks for pointing that out I'll get to editing. Perhaps that is the answer, drive initial users to learn to look out for mistakes and edit them to make good questions, that way people gain an understanding of what is expected of them and how to write a good question before they start asking bad questions.

Comment: @nugae I definitely agree with that less draconian approach, and as gnat points out it looks like that kind of thing is in place already. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 6):

I think many users are focused on maintaining overall post (both question *and* answer) quality at Stack Overflow. There are many ideas on a constant (weekly if not daily) basis which are put forth to address the problem you put forward of finding interesting questions. The sort of semi official term historically used has been "the signal to noise ratio".

I don't think it is fair to say the site is "losing its shine" though. Stack Overflow is kind of a large ship now, and that fact doesn't avail itself to making quick maneuvers. An amazing thing has been built here, and too many large changes could cause it to veer off its already very successful course.

If you want to help, work on creating high quality content, and using the tools available to you to indicate low quality content. Putting forward ideas for increasing the "signal to noise ratio" on meta can also be beneficial - although potentially jarring :D

Comment: A 30,000-tonne garbage scow.

Comment: @MartinJames - Surely you are not implying that all of my contribution (or yours or Jon Skeets) is garbage.

Comment: @MartinJames [11 ton butterfly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0CGHNnLzYU)

Comment: @TravisJ _"Stack Overflow is kind of a large ship now, and that fact doesn't avail itself to making quick maneuvers."_ We need more [Seal Drivers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Qcm_LTHkIg)! And more diesel horses of course, I liked that _more close votes_ campaign recently.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  'They changed their style to melancholic doom with this album.'

Comment: @TravisJ well, obviously, there are some gold bars sticking up out of the trash level.

Comment: @MartinJames B'sh** Jethro Tull were never _melancholic_ in any way.

Comment: Putting forth ideas for increasing the "signal to noise ratio" is useless. Please name recent ideas that have been adopted. By the way, exactly how am I supposed to "create high quality content"? You know that the "tools available to me to indicate low quality content" are essentially useless, right?

Comment: @torazaburo - Useless? I wouldn't exactly say that. As for ideas, how about the [dupehammer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/178816) which was a feature request I created from [a response](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252616/1026459) I wrote to a question literally titled "More effective closing / downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio?" I pretty much would disagree with your *entire* comment.

Comment: _@Travis_ It seems @torazaburo still has a serious misconception about the long term Stack Overflow goals (if these were ever consolidated clearly).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ So wait a minute, I have a serious misconception about long-term SO goals which were never ever clear? By the way, what are they?

Comment: @TravisJ I love the gold badge dup hammer as much as the next guy, and use it regularly, but it's a mere finger in the dike, and there is a serious reluctance on the part of SO management to take any more decisive measures to halt the reduction of the signal to noise ratio. It's a culture of denial and paralysis.

Comment: @torazaburo _" I have a serious misconception about long-term SO goals which were never ever clear?"_ Well, ask [joel spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html). Probably the culprit is there somehow.

Comment: @torazaburo - There is a lot of focus on the new Documents feature at the moment, which is hopefully going to create a place to consolidate frequently addressed issues more efficiently than the Q&A structure can. That is their most recent endeavor to increase the signal to noise ratio. This is all rather tangential, perhaps you should form a separate question asking what the long term goals of Stack Overflow are if you want a larger community response.

Comment: @TravisJ That might heal something, but was Joel actually wrong with that idea? I'm living well with my c++ tag, but I can imagine how all of that doesn't scale well for [tag:php], where the language specs seem to be out of order in 1st place.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - In my opinion they are violating the same rules that Joel created by not fixing existing problems before creating new features. A lot of time is being spent on Documents, and if it fails it could be a significant drag on the company as a whole.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, I have to admit that working on Documents might help to fix that scale leak, and at least sake Stack Overflow from getting useless for some particular (overly popular) language tags.

Comment: Without trying to re-litigate the pluses/minuses of Documents, I fail to see how such a thing would possibly help in a situation where some large proportion of the problem is people who steadfastly refuse to read **any** documentation, including perfectly good existing ones such as MDN, and/or appear incapable of assimilating any information in whatever documentation they do read. One user actually had the temerity to tell me explicitly, when I commented that he could easily have found the answer to his question in the documentation, that reading documentation was not "his learning style".

Comment: @torazaburo 'reading documentation was not "his learning style" ' glad that was you and not me.  I'm tired of replacing display screens after smashing KB and mice through them:(

Comment: Instead of documents, I think we need videos to appeal to the millennials. Ideally 2-3 minutes in length to match their attention span.

Comment: @torazaburo - A "Stack Overflow TV" idea was floated last year, perhaps you should look into that proposal. It was pretty well received. Unless you were being facetious in which case it went over my head due to internet intent misidentification.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Stack Overflow is "losing its shine" as such - it's just that engaged professionals are losing their enthusiasm as the site has become extremely popular. I am sort-of in the same boat: I haven't given up, but I've switched to little bursts of daily editing, rather than answering questions. The site is still useful for me when I have a question, and like Wikipedia editors, I see value in maintaining the existing corpus, even if the task feels never-ending.

There is *a lot* of rubbish that comes in every day, and I think we need to switch on some more content filters, even if that risks reducing the number of questions we receive. Unfortunately some contributors need to be dissuaded from posting. (There are a few content filters already, e.g. to avoid poor-quality titles, so this isn't a particularly radical suggestion).

I [have made this suggestion before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291854/472495) and when I get a moment perhaps I will expand it into a full feature request. It has been raised before, but perhaps some UI screenshots of how key phrases can be detected and flagged on a "are you sure you want to post this" interstitial would pique the interest of product owners at Stack Exchange. I think this could do some good in reducing the number of zero-effort and homework cheating posts we get.