# Why hasn't this "abandoned closed" question been automatically deleted?

Tags: support, automatic-deletion

As stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244519):

> **If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed".

So what's the reason [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760980/while-loop-checking-for-string-c) hasn't already been automatically deleted? <sup>*it was deleted after posting this, but that's irrelevant to my question of why it wasn't already deleted*</sup> Here's the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9760980/timeline).

It wasn't closed as a dup, it's had a score of 0 for long time, it's never been locked, it has no answers, doesn't show any pending reopen votes, and hasn't been edited in long time.

This is the only question I found like this. I saw many others that weren't deleted that I think fit this same criteria, except they were "locked" so they got to remain visible. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793955/rugarch-package-message). It seems that when post is migrated to SO from another SE site, and the SO question ends up being closed, that the question automatically gets locked by Community? But this didn't happen in this one and only case?

Is this a very strange bug or what am I missing?

Comment: How about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658098/5-things-you-hate-about-javascript)?

Comment: It was closed for the "wrong" reason, not a real question.  One basic reason why we have to put up with so many crappy questions these days, can't get them closed anymore.  Same issue with Pang's link.  Backgrounder [is here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/17034).

Comment: Your [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760980/while-loop-checking-for-string-c) link give page not found, looks like they are deleted now.

Comment: Screenshots for under-10kers: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pBD2l.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/EuQg2.png /cc @Anthon

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks. That makes it clear they were deleted by hand.

Comment: @HansPassant we have close reasons for the first one (Off-topic -> "why isn't this code working" reason) and for Pang's ("Primarily opinion based"), so I don't think the issue in this case is not having the proper close reasons.