# Should we close a question which might be a little "basic" and If so, with which reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There's some very basic questions, so should we close them?

What I meant is, for example [here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246146) closed as **a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**. However, I think that reason is incorrect in this case.

Because I think **Can no longer be reproduced and typos** can only be used if the question is like:

> Well, when I run your code I can't get that problem as you said in question. (or that problem just because a typo)

But not:

> Nah, only idiots can have this stupid problem, nobody will have this stupid problem again.

About the above example question, there's no typo and the OP's issues are reproducible. Which I think their question shouldn't be closed as **Not reproducible**.

---

So I'm asking: **Should basic questions like that be closed? If so, then which reason should be used in this case? Is *Can no longer be reproduced and typos* OK?**

By the way, I always try to find a duplicate, but if we can't find one, then leave it open?

---

PS: If you don't want to check the above example, think about the following question:

> Why does my program terminate when I call `terminate();`?

Another:

> I got a segfault. What's wrong? Here is my code [*code is like 5 lines
>   of code accessing an array out of bounds with negative literal
>   constants as indices, and not as an innocent typo, but multiple lines accessing arrays using negative indices*].

Also a funny one:

> How do I use my computer when it is turned off? I tried yelling at it for hours but it still wouldn't do anything. Here is a voice recording of what I yelled at it to do.

Comment: @rene That's also why I hesitate. For all reading this Q, I kind of prompted it wondering about questions where the author seemed a little too hopelessly out of touch with understanding the programming language. Maybe "broad" makes sense as guiding him properly to even understand an answer would require writing a book.

Comment: There's another way to say questions aren't that great: downvotes. If the question is a fair question to ask, but really trivial, easily to find the answer to with a search, etc., then by all means downvote it.

Comment: @Bart: Yeah I know, then we don't need close it? Also what to do with these already closed? Is reopen them needed?

Comment: @KevinGuan don't bother re-opening I would say. That needs three voters.

Comment: @rene: Hmm...think so. But if just downvote is fine, then is there's anyway to tell the reviewers don't close some questions like the examples as typo?

Comment: @Bart I don't know if I'd describe them as trivial -- though an immediate answer would be. Maybe something like, `"How do I use my computer when it is turned off? I tried yelling at it for hours but it still wouldn't do anything. Here is a voice recording of what I yelled at it to do."` The immediate response is usually like.... `"Err.... what?"`

Comment: Assuming the subject matter would be on topic for the specific site @Ike, a downvote would suffice there if a particular close reason doesn't exist.

Comment: @Bart I see -- maybe just down votes would do -- the site cleans after itself anyway kind of by prioritizing things with higher votes in many cases.

Comment: I once saw a question titled *"How do I read a book?"*. No joke. It got a score like -25 :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Wait me ask a question on SO about *How to ask a question on SO*.

Comment: @KevinGuan hmm... no need, someone [already took care of it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312001/what-is-stack-overflow) :D ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/wLXIZXM.png) for <10k users)

Comment: @approxiblue: Huh? Why unclear? If that question is clear about the problem, vote to close it as unclear makes no sense. For example about the last example, it's very clear that he want to *How do I use my computer when it is turned off* :P

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Wow, just 4 days ago :P

Comment: @approxiblue: I meant about why close questions like that as unclear as the accepted answer said in the dupe question. Or maybe just go to create a custom reason?

Comment: The president of the company that owns this web site [thinks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/17034) you should either answer the question or find a duplicate of the question.  This dictum is widely ignored, SO users just pick a random reason from the close dialog.  The more opposite of the true reason the better, that makes "Unclear what you are asking" an excellent choice.

Comment: @HansPassant: Ah, that makes sense :).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I actually like *"How do I read a book?"* more than, *"Why does accessing an array using negative indices give strange results? -- here is my MCVE and no expressed statement of what I expect that will do."* "How do I read a book?" might actually get some very interesting and detailed answers that might help other people.