# Why Doesn't ASK do a Google Search?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

This is relocated (manually) from MSE after someone explained the MSO distinction and the question's relevance mostly to SO.

While digging through the existing (MSO-focused) content on question quality and closing, I noticed a bunch of complaints of the LMGTFY variety.  Is this a big enough problem that it would be worth complementing "Questions that may already have your answer" with an inline google search (even just the top 1 or 2 responses)?

Benefits would include:

- Head LMGTFY off and preserve resources (e.g. answering, moderating) for higher value questions.
- Avoid duplicates not detected by issues like [Why can I find a certain question without any problems using Google, but not via SO's site search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129360/273930).
- It seems easy to bench test.  Take the last N closed, duplicate, or neg-vote questions and put them side by side with the google results and see if (1) this might have been avoided and (2) how deep the search would need to go.

Two objections were mentioned before I relocated (losing comments) the question:

1. "Why send folks elsewhere?"  Some responses:

   - Answers/respondents are doing this anyway
   - This would only affect people who reached the "ask" stage and not the general (e.g. search) user
   - At some point, the community resources to moderate/close are more precious than a few eyeballs
2. "Cost of Google Search."  Valid, but are there offsetting benefits?

   - How valuable are community resources?
   - How many "asks" are actually started in a year?
   - Could the google search appear (i.e. the API call made) only after "passing" on the existing SO question list?