# Where do all these 'user123456' accounts come from?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Being a read-only user for a long time, I hadn't noticed this before...

But, switching to 'registered user' and reviewing all these questions asked - I wonder, where all these newbie accounts (i.e. 1-10 rep. at most), named with pattern `user[\d]{6}` (i.e. user+6 digits) comes from?

Especially most of questions asked by such accounts are about assistance in some homework task (being very much programming newbie issues).

The only thing that comes to my mind is that Stack Overflow (while this seems to apply to other forks of it) has launched some referral / marketing program, or suffers some security hole.

Comment: Well every user has a userID and the default user name is `"user" + userID`. Now that all "these" users ask homework questions is probably because most of them are students who just create a new account and ask their question with the default username.

Comment: So, you mean one just register on SO w/o specifying some username and gets such account name ?
I wasn't aware that's even possible.

Comment: Yes, that is the default username.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explanation.
Seems to be somewhat surprising to me, but now I know the answer at least.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35839

Comment: I've simply bypassed such an option the other day I've registered on SO (or it hasn't got into my attention) that there is option to use some default username. Nor was searching for way to change my current nickname so far.

Comment: Does some of down-voters care to explain that is the problem with this question? Thanks in advance.
(I do understand one may have it reasons, but explaining my mistake, so I do not reproduce it ever, would be great)

Comment: @agg3l [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) and you should know that votes on meta do not count toward (or reduce) your reputation.  Meta voting is simple feedback, and may also qualify you for certain badges to your meta profile.  Your regular SO profile is completely separate from your meta profile, for the purposes of voting.

Comment: @agg3l there are only 2 downvotes. You should just relax on the downvotes. Complaining and asking for explanations is not going to get you the answers you seem to expect

Comment: @psubsee2003 Not that I bother much about it, but slightly disappointed about some questions may receive tons of downvotes with no-one ever cared to explain why :(
Not my case, yet it can be very repulsive for some newbee, as you can guess

Comment: Thus there are only two options left:

- run away and abandon any write-activity, afraid of more negative replies
- wait for some good soul to explain what was wrong.


Ok, here is the third, which I'm on now - don't give a s*1t to it, yet wait for some explanation from someone with better knowledge of community.
Neither of these appeals to (generic) newbee anyhow

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Thank you for your reply.
I do not bother about rates/votes et cetera much at my age...
As I've menioned already, SO lacks explanation for upwotes (for the ones being positive nobody really cares "why") or downvotes (and it can dissapoint one very much)..
I've hit the vent of unexplained downvotes couple of times already - that's not something encouraging to use SO, as anyone can guess

Comment: I doubt this 'vote up' / 'vote down' discussion should continue in this thread any more

Comment: [about 20%](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/557629) of the low rep users keep their default username. When the rep gets higher that percentage drops significantly.

Comment: funny to see [Spolsky](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/839601) referred to as _security hole_. "Joel Spolsky transformed SO to match his vision... empower more SO users to ask questions; it's much easier now that there's no need for showing research or understanding of the problem..."

Comment: What's wrong with the default username!? :)

Comment: @user1354557 It's hard to remember

Comment: @user1354557 nothing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer to this question was explained in details by the very first commenter that got a look at it (this wasn't not verified by me, though I don't have any reason to doubt it):

Stack Overflow registration procedure accepts not entering any local "nickname", assigning something simple as 'user' + {registration_id}...
Thereafter any newborn accounts hadn't bothered to adjust theirs registration information ends with all these infamous 'user123456' nickname.

(The "trivial questions" part is of the initial question is definitely obvious from the very start, taken the date of the question was asked - the fall (mid-October) - school/college season is on, thus too active students are on the go at the time of the question.)

Comment: I have one of those accounts, but I'm not a student. I use it for many reasons, one of them being to ask trivial questions, which sometimes get no answer. I'm fine with my user name, so I never bothered changing it.

Comment: @user3653831: Please don't ask trivial questions.

Comment: Related: [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September)

Comment: The questions may be trivial for you, but for me they are not. Some could be resolved by simply reading the manual, assuming you have a good grasp of the basics (of python programming, for instance). But, when you are a beginner, you don't have a grasp of anything. For example, 14 years ago, I would have posted a question on how to compile a "Hello world" code. At that time, I spent three days figuring that out.