# Rephrasing "research effort" to something less contentious

Tags: discussion

The term "research effort" and consequently the phrase "showing research effort" seems to allow for two possible readings:

1. The charitable one:

   > Before writing this question you surely have invested time into
   >   narrowing down your problem through trial and error; please, friend,
   >   share the fruits of this work with us so we do not need to repeat 
   >   the process and can arrive at a beneficial solution sooner.
2. The sarcastic one:

   > You lazy [expletive] just copy and pasted this homework here without
   >   even attempting to do anything yourself.

Often enough I find that people tend towards the second interpretation needlessly. But we do not really care how much "effort" (sweat and tears) a person has put into "researching" their problem before they posted here. Sure, we would *prefer* for everyone to [exhaust all their resources before coming here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/476). But that is a **non-quantifiable metric**. We are interested in **the question, not the person.**

Nobody can *demonstrate* that they have exhausted all their other avenues. If somebody is looking for a way to do X, and they have read all the appropriate documentation from cover to cover without finding an appropriate method, that's quite a good *research effort*; but it's not demonstrable in any way. We just end up with useless noise like *"I've searched"* in questions which might well be true and just about sum up what the OP did do; but it still never satisfies our "show research effort".

What we really mean by "showing research effort" is that:

1. the question's scope is reasonably narrow and not *too broad*
2. the problem statement is reasonably *clear*, something which 
   research helps improve

Research is a means to an end, it is not an end in itself; yet many users elevate it to be an end in itself, to which the particular phrasing "showing research effort" needlessly contributes I believe.

Hence: **can we rephrase that to something else** or omit that phrasing entirely?

Ultimately a lack of research effort results in *too broad*, *unclear* or *duplicated* questions, so I'd be fine with deduplicating that meaning and omitting it altogether. However, to keep a short summary of that meaning in the downvote tooltip or elsewhere, how about something along the lines of:

> is not answerable in its current state

> problem isn't defined well enough

> is too raw

Comment: You are right that "research" is technically not always the correct word, and focusing on the OP's sweat and tears isn't what we really should be focusing on, but more research effort is exactly what most of those types of questions *need*. Your suggestions do not point that out as clearly as "research effort" does.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the "feature-request" tag?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, but the issue with the current phrasing is that it promotes a culture of "you don't deserve an answer you lazy… person." My main concern is to suppress that. I'm sure the phrasing started with the charitable meaning and tried to express all those points as succinctly as possible, alas it appears to me that it is being misunderstood, because it *allows* an easy misunderstanding.

Comment: @Maroun I want to take the room temperature first actually. :)

Comment: `We just end up with useless noise like "I've searched"` - That, IMO, does not qualify as showing "research effort"; as you say it's just useless noise. In the rare occassion I ask a question, I tend to describe what I found and why exactly it is not applicable for my current problem. In my experience it's extremely rare to have a problem where google returns nothing and "I've searched but didn't find anything at all" is actually true. And while I like "isn't defined well enough", I'm not sure we should de-emphasize doing resarch given the lack of it in most questions.

Comment: @l4mpi But again, what if someone did *a ton* of research and just ran into walls every which way because what they came up with was simply way off the mark. Adding all that doesn't really help either. It's not atypical to have a problem you have zero knowledge about, doing some googling comes up with a lot of stuff but nothing that obviously seems to fit remotely, and simply posing the original problem as is without extraneous noise is the best point to start a question from. Citing all the things that obviously didn't apply doesn't make the question any better.

Comment: @l4mpi Citing research is only useful if you found something that was *close* but didn't apply due to specific reasons. But if you simply come up with *nothing* close, there's nothing to cite.

Comment: @deceze I agree, but I think that's an edge case and far from the norm for most questions being asked and/or closed. Do we really need to optimize for that?

Comment: @deceze I can't believe you will never find something close and getting a hard time adapting it, hence usually the question turn into I started from "This example" and I've never been able to adapt it. And even then I would ask to see the attempt, just to understand how the asker fail.

Comment: And for my point of view, the tooltip say: "doesn't show **any** research effort" which bring down to the the second meaning only. If we would be hand holding peoples we wouldn't downvote or close anything.

Comment: Some people even think "demonstrating research effort" entails including a code sample for the sake of having one - even if that code is nothing but boilerplate, or worse, utter nonsense.

Comment: voted down for [attempt to make Spolsky even happier](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/839601), "empower more SO users to ask questions; it's much easier now that there's no need for showing research or understanding of the problem..."

Comment: @gnat Not necessarily. As I say, "research effort" is IMO pretty much encapsulated in other established reasons to downvote or close, so removing it doesn't take anything away from your tools to judge a question. As I say, I don't even necessarily want to "take it away" at all. I just want it to be changed to something which fewer people can hang their hat on to start a fire, as opposed to some more objective reason to get rid of garbage (not clear, too broad etc).

Comment: you know I've been myself marching and singing ["and nicer and nicer and nicer"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsdXVl47ZOs) from the very start of this nonsense with summers of love and hunting the snark. I thought this will make site look more professional. I changed my mind [only recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281807/165773) after I discovered that none of this works as advertised, negativity and snark stay there and amount of garbage questions increases and it only gets harder to find good content

Comment: @gant I'm not proposing to keep more garbage. I still want all the same garbage removed. But the snark and negativity is *exactly* what I'm trying to address here. As I said repeatedly on this post, this phrase IMO promotes a culture of negativity. I want to change that into more objectivity. I would still want you to close the same stuff, just with fewer negative feelings behind it.

Comment: I know your intentions are good and I respect that. As I wrote I shared these intentions myself for quite a long time. My point is only that history has shown that measures like you propose don't make the intended impact and instead only lead to increase of low quality questions and possibly as a side effect to increase of negativity and snark

Comment: @gnat I'd disagree there, since, again, I don't think it'd take anything away except comments like "what did you try", "show some code" and other noise like that, which is rarely constructive.

Comment: I think we can just wait and see. SE team will likely do as you suggested, to please their boss one more time and after some time passes you just look around and see that things are just as I say you now: negativity stays or increases, amount of garbage questions increases

Comment: @gnat I'm actually much less optimistic about this being implemented than you are… seems we're both negative about different aspects of this.

Comment: [why oh why we are so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601) :)

Comment: I want people to show me what they have done so that I don't waste my time suggesting things they have already tried.

Comment: @Will Of course, we all do. If they don't, the question is likely *too broad*. That's not the point. The point is the specific phrasing of "effort".

Comment: I thought research meant searching for existing Q&A to avoid creating non-useful duplicates.

Answer (score 10):

You are assuming that "shows research effort" means that the question needs to contain verbiage describing how much research effort was put into it. That is not the case. Such verbiage is not useful, and I actively remove it. I agree with you that it doesn't do any good to insert phrases like *"I've spent a long time searching"* because that simply doesn't mean anything. What is a long time? Where did you look? What keywords did you use? Did you literally find nothing, or did you not understand what you read, or did it not work for you? If not, why not? In other words, such claims prompt more questions than answers.

Rather than *telling* about how much research has been put into the question, we want questions to *show* (or *demonstrate*, if you prefer) that research effort has been invested. That means avoiding asking questions that could be solved by reading the error message, looking in the manual/FAQ, conducting a simple Internet search, and so forth. It simply doesn't matter if you are incompetent, unable to use Google, don't have a manual, or otherwise have an excuse. Questions that do not show research effort are subject to being downvoted as "not useful", and I'm not eager to do anything that appears to discourage this practice.

**In other words, we want to encourage questions that, *by the nature of what is being asked*, indicate that a reasonable research effort has been undertaken. You should *show*, rather than *tell*.**

You are also adding an "exhaustive" qualifier in there that does not actually exist. We don't expect an *exhaustive* effort, because if there had truly been an exhaustive effort, then it could plausibly be concluded that there *is* no answer and therefore the question is unsuitable for an entirely different reason.

These words are intentionally subjective, since votes are intentionally subjective. It is my assessment of the question's demonstration of research effort that is going to cause me to downvote. If I think the answer could have been found easily, and consequently I don't think it is a question that will be useful to others, I will downvote it. In that sense, the tooltip is an apt reflection of how people actually use downvotes, and thus does not need to be changed.

It isn't perfectly quantifiable, but that's okay, because we're not having a computer make the determination. The determination is made by *users*, ideally those who are knowledgeable about the problem domain. If it's a complex question that a few minutes of research would not be sufficient, then I am going to know that, and I'm not going to downvote on that basis. Nor should anyone else—and, more importantly, nor *do* they in my experience (and I hang out on the C++ tag, where we have *very* high quality standards).

> What we really mean by "showing research effort" is that:
>
> 1. the question's scope is reasonably narrow and not too broad
> 2. the problem statement is reasonably clear, something which research helps improve

I agree with the first interpretation, but not with the second. That one is already covered by "clear"; it doesn't need to get shoved into "research effort".

I already said above what *I* take "research effort" to mean. If you ask "What is `int` in C?", then I'm going to downvote that because it doesn't show research effort. I believe that a few moments of research would have revealed the answer to you, and since the answer is already readily available, I don't believe that duplicating it on Stack Overflow is useful or a good way for experts to spend their time. The problem here is not with a lack of clarity, nor with a broad scope. It is that you failed to RTFM and thus are wasting our time.

If you *do* want to ask a "RTFM" question, then you need to explain why what you read in the manual didn't help, didn't make sense, or didn't apply to your case. In other words, quote the standard or some other authoritative text, and ask what it *means*. Show the research you've done, don't just claim to have done it.

---

> - is not answerable in its current state

Already covered by "unclear" and "not useful"

> - problem isn't defined well enough

Same as above

> - is too raw

I don't know what this means

Frankly, I don't see "research effort" as being "contentious" at all. When someone actually does copy and paste homework into the question box, I think that's a totally valid reason to downvote, so I'm not really sure where you are going with that. And if they do assume that is the interpretation of "research effort", then it would seem they would be *less* likely to downvote on that basis, not more likely. Aside from the needlessly harsh phrasing, I don't quite understand why that reading is problematic.

Comment: *"You are assuming that "shows research effort" means that the question needs to contain verbiage describing how much research effort was put into it"* – No, I'm saying **too many users interpret it that way** and that this phrasing promotes a "you no deserve answer" culture, which I find *needlessly contentious*. I don't want people to use *that* as a reason to downvote, since it promotes the wrong reason. As we seem to agree, "lack of research" is already covered by other close reasons; so let's get rid of that as redundant because it causes needless contention.

Comment: I *don't* think it is covered adequately by the other close reasons. In fact, I don't think it is covered by *any* of the close reasons. You can't vote to close a question because they didn't RTFM (and I'm not sure that you actually should be able to). But I can downvote it on that basis, and I think that's important. Aside from that, the explanation in that comment is more clear to me than the entire question. But I'm not too concerned about this, either, because I think there are questions that don't deserve an answer. What's wrong with them being downvoted and the asker knowing why? @dec

Comment: *"When someone actually does copy and paste homework into the question box, I think that's a totally valid reason to downvote"* – Why exactly? Because it doesn't make for a good question? Or because you feel they don't deserve an answer? What if they rephrased the homework so it's not really recognisable as originating from a homework question, and suddenly it makes for a good question?

Comment: The reasons why I have a problem with copied-and-pasted homework questions are adequately summarized [here](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/), and various other discussions we've had on this very Meta site. It isn't simply rephrasing the question that solves the problem, but *explaining what the question is*. If the person doesn't understand how to solve the homework question, they probably won't understand the answer I post, either. I need to know what parts to *explain*. (I take for granted that code dumps are not good or even acceptable answers.)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I don't find homework questions thrilling either. However, I want people to judge **the question,** not what they perceive the person behind the question did or didn't do. Bad questions are still bad and should still be downvoted. But that judgement must happen more objectively based on the premise posed by the question, not because you feel the OP could or should have done more to deserve an answer.

Comment: I don't think "shows research effort" is judging the person. I make this decision exclusively based on the question itself. It is quite obvious to me when a question fails this test. I don't vote for this reason in edge cases, and I haven't seen any actual evidence of anyone else doing so, either. If you can't swing a cat without hitting the answer, then it shows no research effort. It isn't nearly the issue of perception that you make it out to be.

Comment: I'm also just not feeling all of this hand-wringing over *voting*. People can vote for any reason they want. This is a pretty darn common one, so I think the tooltip should reflect it.

Comment: @deceze: Well, you can have an RTFM question that's clear, straightforward and succinct. Little to find fault in except that it's been asked literally 1000 times over and gets asked once every other day, *on top of* already having an answer in the manual. Is it still a good question?

Comment: @BoltClock If it already has dupes, then it's a dupe and deserves to be closed for that reason. If we still stand behind dupes to promote different entry points to the canonical answer, there shouldn't necessarily even be much wrong with this. From there it's extremely subjective whether the OP *should* have been able to find the canonical answer by themselves or not and hence deserve a downvote; since we do acknowledge that dupes help add keywords to a problem, I see a bit of a disconnect there with trying to serve both gods at the same time.

Comment: If a dupe provides a different entry point to the canonical answer, then the dupe probably shows research effort. Otherwise, they would have found the canonical answer and not have had to ask. We don't want people to *intentionally* ask duplicates. Downvoting a duplicate for showing no research effort is completely reasonable if I type the question's title into Google and turn up the canonical question as the very first result. You might not *like* this, and you are free to abstain from voting for this reason, but it *is* how people vote and it is fair, and so the tooltip should reflect it.

Comment: *"If a dupe [...] then [it] probably shows research effort. Otherwise, they would have found the canonical answer and not have had to ask."* – Sorry, not getting you, that seems contradictory.

Comment: Well yeah, because you ignored some words. :-) I'll try to rephrase. If the question truly provides a different entry point to the canonical answer, then it probably shows some research effort. Otherwise, if there was no research effort, then the duplicate is not useful and doesn't provide a different entry point—it is just the same question over again.

Comment: You're saying somebody asks a dupe, but phrased very differently, and using that different phrasing they would/could not have found the canonical answer, exactly because their phrasing does not match the canonical version? Well, then *showing* their research effort doesn't matter, because it was bound to come up with nothing. For all you know they did type all their keywords into the right search window, it just didn't find anything because there was nothing to be found with their (incorrect/misguided/alternate) keywords. How will you judge that research effort?

Comment: Asking a question with keywords that wouldn't have turned up the canonical doesn't imply research effort. But asking a question whose title would have turned up the canonical in the list of suggested questions implies no research effort (e.g. by neglecting to peruse the list of suggestions).

Comment: I see now, the use of "otherwise" is rather confusing since it can refer to two different sub clauses. OK, let's ignore that, it's not the main point anyway.

Comment:  Perfect example of unclear phrasing causing needless contention BTW… ;o)