# Provide 24*7 Online help centre facility

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Many programmers are struggling during their office time due to critical bugs and doubts. If you provide online immediate assistance it will save lots of developers careers and life too.

Comment: This already exists. It is called Stack Overflow.

Comment: Asking a question on SO means having to wait until someone answers. I think OP wants something with immediate assitance. Where you can talk with a person, and identify the problem together. Synchronous communication, rather than the somewhat asynchronous question-and-answer.

Comment: *"If you provide online immediate assistance it will save lots of developers career and life too."* If careers and lives depend on the online assistance you're seeking ... perhaps those developers should look for a different career.

Comment: related: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/839601)

Comment: So... Wait... To save YOUR job and YOUR source of revenue.... I have to sacrifice mine because now I have to be at your beck and call whenever you need? Do... Do I make a cut of your salary too?

Comment: @Patrice no, but I get to sue you if I get fired despite your help.

Comment: @Pekka웃 that sounds fair.... Sign me up!

Comment: @Patrice there is a signup fee, though. And a monthly fee.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I assume you are talking about one-on-one technical support for programmers, helping them resolve their particular situation.

As you probably know, that isn't really what Stack Overflow is there for. Stack Overflow wants to build an archive of knowledge for future readers, and one-on-one support isn't really its mission, even though it sometimes is the natural result of answering a question.

Offering one-on-one tutoring is certainly an interesting idea. There is, however, no way to provide that kind of service for free. What motivation would anyone have in helping some random person do their job? There are *much* more effective and rewarding ways to do good in the world.

So this would have to be a paid service to work. It's certainly *possible* it could be commercially successful - but as it stands, it looks *very*  unlikely Stack Overflow will ever expand its business in that direction. They are looking for funding elsewhere, like ads and the very lucrative job market.

You'll probably have to look elsewhere for this kind of service. There are services like [Codementor](http://codementor.io) that do what you are requesting - however the hourly rates of their mentors are mostly fairly high.

Comment: SO is here to assist you with being a good programmer, not to make some other person do your job for you.

Comment: @pekka absolutely that is my request. **one-on-one technical support for programmers**. I just suggested that feature. If feasible implement in future. Thanks  lot for your detailed reply.

Answer (score 12):

There's this amazing site called https://stackoverflow.com where you can get help 24/7.
***Even on holidays!***