# Why do we have this round of elections barely 8 months after the previous one?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Looking at the history of my election participation, I see that I have voted in the November 2016 election, in the July 2017 election, and will also do so in the present round. This means elections every 8 months. Isn't this a bit too often?

I do not participate much in the SO discussions, but I am significantly more active on MathOverflow and Math.SE; on those sites, moderators are elected every several *years*, whereas here elections seem to happen every several *months*. Is it possible to know, in general, why this happens, and, in particular, what triggered this very round of elections? I thought about moderator burn-out, but Math.SE is a very active SE community, too, and this phaenomenon does not happen there, so the cause should be different. Based upon my experience on MO and Math.SE, I expect a moderator to hold this position for several years (unless "force majeure", of course) - which does not seem to happen here.

Comment: @yivi: This could be the reason I had thought of, but could a moderator show some numbers regarding the two communities? Isn't the number of moderators proportional to the number of users?

Comment: Elections are held when it is needed. That need is determined by SE staff based on the workload / flagload, and if the mod-team feels they can use the extra hands. There have been cases where SE Staff said: let's do an election and the sitting mod team said: meh. That was not on SO though but I don't recall for which site it was.

Comment: I imagine it should be proportional to the amount of traffic and flags generated, which are not necessarily proportional with the number of users. Different communities have different usage patterns.

Comment: @AlexM. *Isn't the number of moderators proportional to the number of users?* if anything, I expect it to correlate with the number of posts per day but more so with number of flags raised per day. The latter isn't publicly available though

Comment: @rene I think if we had [additional close votes for tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240702/165773) there would be no need to have so many mods. This way mod power would just scale naturally and smoothly along with the growth of active tags. Quite a pity that this probably won't happen as it would go so much against [current party line](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/839601)

Comment: Elections are sometimes held because someone wants to retire. Additionally, one of the recently-elected moderators hasn't been very active for a few months. Hopefully not, but it may be that someone is _unable_ to hold the position any more.

Comment: @gnat I would have to see if that makes a big difference on flag load for mods but yeah, I'm not opposed to introduce a bit more close vote weight to more users.

Comment: @rene I bet it would because quicker closure of inappropriate questions would help handling quite a lot of associated issues that currently result in mod flags

Comment: @gnat - Moderators don't handle close flags on SO, so that would do little for our flag load. Only moderators can handle the 1100 custom flags currently sitting the queue, the 380 disputed review flags, etc. While it's an interesting suggestion, it wouldn't address the need here.

Comment: @BradLarson I am not talking about close flags but about assiciated issues. For example voting fraud intended to pull one from question block, stuff like that - it would be much less popular if people knew that inappropriate questions will be quickly closed anyway. Compare that to asking questions in the answers - this seems like easiest way to circumvent question ban but why it is not widely abused? Because community has been given enough power to make this kind of abuse futile

Answer (score 7):

Because more moderators are needed. SO has many more users than Math.se, and it's probably growing at a faster pace as well.

You can read more in Über.se ([When do moderator elections take place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-do-moderator-elections-take-place)) which basically says:

> *Most elections are scheduled as a result of moderators reaching out to Stack Exchange to ask for additional help.*

The number of moderators needed probably correlates more closely with posts published and flags raised than with number of users; since I expect different communities may have different ratios for posts | flags / users.

Comment: You point to some generic reasons for holding elections, which I agree with. I was particularly interested in seeing if there are "outgoing" moderators, and if so - how many. What I was trying to insinuate (and we must wait for a moderator to step in and clarify this) is that some moderators are a bit superficial when running for this position, believeing it to be a game, or a hobby. When they realize that moderating requires dedication and involvement, they quickly give up - an attitude that I dislike. But this is just my conjecture, only moderators can confirm or refute it.

Comment: Instead of insinuating, just ask your question. Insinuations aren’t very useful.

Comment: @AlexM. - Typically, we leave announcements for outgoing moderators until after the election has completed. It's best for anyone who might be stepping down to have a chance to say so themselves. Regarding work load, I think the current group of moderators didn't regard this as a vanity position, but it's always a shock to see what we're presented with on a regular basis. In almost all recent cases, someone has stepped down because their work or life situation had changed (in a good way) such that they simply didn't have time for this anymore.

Comment: Also, I can tell you that having your inbox filled with obscenities, slurs, and threats can get to you after a while. The recent anonymizing of moderator messages at least has helped to reduce the number of personal threats and insults we get outside of the site. Haven't had someone call my office number about something I did on the site in the last few months.

Comment: _"call my office number about something I did on the site"_ Ugh, that's truly awful. I'm sorry that you folks have to deal with that kind of thing.

Comment: @BradLarson: It seems that your comments could make for a good answer, if put together. I understand the need to let the election pass before formulating it; would you agree to revisit this question and post an answer with all the missing (for now) information? I could ping you to remind you of it, if you agree. Thank you.

Comment: Do mods get a SO tshirt as compensation when they get their first swatting?