# What's the best method of dealing with seemingly useless questions?

Tags: discussion

I came across this question today: [plotting histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102416/plotting-histogram).

It has no upvotes.

It has an answer that has no upvotes. It is not an accepted answer either.

It has seen no activity for almost three years, since it got posted. It seems like a useless post to me.

My questions:

1. Is bringing the post to moderator attention to delete the post the correct thing to do?
2. Should we do something else with such posts?
3. Should we just leave such posts alone?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to involve the mods. VTC if you think it's appropriate or walk away

Comment: The main thing I see is that... we simply have a lot on our plate, to worry about these types of questions. It's just the pareto-principle I suppose. We need to focus energy on certain high-reward areas... and leave alone what we can afford to leave alone.

Comment: Why do you think that question needs moderator attention? There's no reason I could possibly imagine that would require that question to be flagged.

Comment: I am always trying to purge useless cruft in software. Why not apply the same principle to SO content? Maybe not many feel the same way. That's OK.

Comment: @GrantWinney, I think your comment makes a lot of sense, and is probably the best reason to leave such posts alone.

Comment: [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601) "...If a question is more than 30 days old, and...

* has a score of -1 or less, with no votes in the past 30 days
* has no answers with a score > 0
* is not locked
...it will be automatically deleted."

Comment: Burninate C, Android, PHP

Comment: Holy hell, who gives a crap?  We probably have over a million similar questions.  Let sleeping dopes lie, ffs.

Comment: @Will, looking at the comments and the downvotes, apparently, not many :)

Comment: @MartinJames - LOL !!!!!

Comment: I will say that lone answer is pretty mediocre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the database can handle storing that small amount of extra content. Further, if it is deleted the database will still hold on to it since it is only soft-deleted. The only thing you are doing by deleting that question is preventing it from reaching any search results. Luckily only one user every 3 days lands on that page (average, probably lower since most views come either right when it was posted or due to the "meta effect").

It also may or may not even qualify for closure and/or deletion. The problem statement "*The problem is that I have to add another array to this histogram by "o" letters*" is rather shaky. Maybe it makes sense to someone. If not, perhaps the question is unclear (closure option if you feel that way).

Long story short, the content is already in the database, and doesn't seem to be causing any harm (Stack Overflow *seems* to have survived these past 3 years with that question being here). While this one instance may get closed from the meta effect, the overall task of finding these and closing them is a waste of time in my opinion.

In response to the set of questions:
1. No
2. There is no clear pattern shown
3. Action them as you will, but seeking them out is a waste of time imo

Comment: I stumbled on to the post while I was searching for something else, and wondered whether I should do something about it.

Comment: @RSahu - Yeah, that can happen from time to time, running into one of these "in the wild" as it were. If you feel it fits a close reason then vote that way if you feel it should be closed. If not, move on. But I think you probably have better things to do with your time than setting out to find every post that fits that structure. The moderator interaction is definitely going to get declined here, because the community is more than capable of handling this post, and also because it does not need immediate moderator attention (they are quite busy).