# What could we do with a FAQ duplicate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

### Too much information kills information

At time of writing, there are 9,237,948 questions on Stack Overflow, and there are many *frequently asked question*, duplicated with as many more answers...

For a sample, entering [`bash read space`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bash%20read%20space) in Stack Overflow's search field gives (today) ***571 results***, and when searching for a direct answer: [`IFS= read`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=IFS%3D%20read) will offer ***3,889 results***.

I think this could become a good habit to make a little search for already posted answer, then signaling duplicate, **before** posting his own answer.

But...

I won't be able to become a discipline teacher... Or maybe, Stack Overflow miss tools to do this...

For a sample, there is [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29739956/1765658). I was searching for a good duplicate before posting my close vote, but an answer was posted 2 minutes before my post.

The [comments about this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739956/how-to-avoid-read-command-in-shell-script-to-avoid-trimming-spaces/29740011#comment47613156_29740011) let you see my opinion and the answer author's point of view about this... (I'm coming to ask this question here, after [@BlueMoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739956/how-to-avoid-read-command-in-shell-script-to-avoid-trimming-spaces/29740011#comment47613422_29740011) suggest.)

In fact. I don't know what to do with that, but I dislike to see Stack Overflow growing in this way. It's counter-productive.

#### Fake duplicate vs real FAQ duplicate

I insist: this question stands for a real ***FAQ duplicate*** where the **same recurrent** answer is coming many times (with maybe some difference in presentation, formulation or explanation).

I agree, there are a lot of *fake duplicates*, meaning questions flagged as duplicates, and where there are some subtle but important differences.

This would just make answering this more difficult...

#### Feature request?

I think, there is something to *invent*, but as *every question must have an aswer...*

So if someone could post a good idea about this... (I tagged *feature request* as if a good idea is coming there, they could become a feature...)

Comment: I dislike idea of deleting answer (even good), but I would like to invite author to do this himself.

Comment: *"I think this could become a good habit to make a little search for already posted answer, then signaling duplicate, before posting his own answer."* - that is absolutely what you're *supposed to do*. The [tag:python] community has a resource for this: http://sopython.com/canon/

Comment: I agree in your point, although you make your point a bit agressively (_Please, as there is already a lot of same answer on SO, drop them and vote to close this question..._ may not be the best approach). Regarding the issue itself, we should definitiely do something about it: currently it is faster to answer than looking for a duplicate. And it is also common to see what happened to you: you know such duplicate exists and, while looking for a good one, someone posts an answer. By the way, I see the answer got two downvotes, whereas it is a good answer. I think those a "meta downvotes".

Comment: See [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773) and [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601)

Comment: I understand the interest in removing duplication, but I don't see a strong argument being made as to why this duplication is actually a problem which needs solving.

Comment: @TravisJ In this case, searching for a *good answer* in the bunch of already posted answer took  a lot of time (my valuable time;-). Effectively, there is already a lot of *upvoted answers*, where some of them could be discussed... So adding on more seem not to be a good idea. As opposite, finding a good post, making them more upvoted could serve SO goals

Comment: @F.Hauri - If there are that many of them, then address that specific issue on meta, and not this one user posting an answer. He is merely making the system work and there is nothing wrong with that. If you are truly interested in this topic, then create a meta post suggesting or asking for help to make a chain of duplicates for this specific topic and perhaps add it to the FAQ for the bash or linux tag wiki. For what it's worth, I found this one as well which seems to be popular and along the same lines http://stackoverflow.com/q/7314044/1026459

Comment: @TravisJ Nice! So one question: How many time did you spend for findind this? ;-)

Comment: @F.Hauri - Roughly 52 seconds.

Comment: I guess I don't really see the point here. Duplicates are good because they find a comprehensive answer faster than writing one as well as build search prominence through concentration of links and activity. If there's somebody out there that just likes writing answers and not using a search engine, really, who cares? You haven't made enough of an effort to convince me there's a problem. If you know of a duplicate, use it. If you don't, write an answer. Assuming a question is answerable, the correct action is whatever is efficient and effective towards answering it.