# When is a negative score question deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

From what I've read on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/213671), a post is deleted if:

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked

I'm working through some ["thanks in advanced"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thanks+in+advanced%22+score%3A0..0+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) posts with filters based on the criteria above. These post have a score of exactly 0 so that I can downvote if I fell the question is unsalvageable. No need for close votes and the system will take care of the deletion for me.

Most of the posts I've worked were asked more than 30 days ago. When will the post be deleted, 30 days after the post was asked (which is in the past), or 30 days after the post last went negative? Will the post be deleted tonight, or in 30 days from my downvote?

So just to be clear, if I downvote a 0-score question that has been asked more than 30 days ago with no answers, 1 minute before the nightly job runs, will the post be deleted 1 minute after my vote?

Comment: "More than 30 days old" means from date and time of first posting.

Comment: So by downvoting >30 day old question the system deletes it at the first possible opportunity, meaning that with good timing I could get a post deleted by a single downvote a few minutes before?

Comment: I suspect that such deletions occur during the overnight batch processes.

Comment: Actually, it's **weekly** instead of nightly. [The Roomba post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) says: *"These checks are run every week across all sites."* in the middle of the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community deleting legitimate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302077/community-deleting-legitimate-question)

Comment: @gnat I thoroughly disagree with that.

Comment: I voted because of [answer over there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302079/839601), it says the same as accepted answer here, with more details and is from user who was SE developer at the time of posting it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Under the present system, the timing of votes is of no consequence. When the deletion script runs, it identifies all  questions that meet the [criteria for deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) at that moment, and deletes them. Only the state of the question at the run time matters, not how it got there.

Comment: While it does sound concerning that someone could "game" the system, it does makes sense. The system only cares about the raw criteria being met.

Comment: There is a [proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/) to change that (which is the reason I wrote _under the present system_).