# Community deleting legitimate question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, community-user, automatic-deletion

I just noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553231/why-can-i-not-find-a-custom-attribute-on-this-methodinfo) I had posted a while back had been deleted by the "community" user.

The only reason I noticed it is because I had left a comment in my code to follow up on this. The only reason I can see that it was deleted was that I happen to have enough rep.

What the heck? This is a perfectly legitimate question. It has a single down vote with no explanation whatsoever. Why on earth would the community-bot delete this? Is this a bug?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/145673

Comment: But this question wasn't closed - why was it deleted? All those notes (except the first one) concern closed questions.

Comment: Yep I just noticed that. Not sure if some additional cases have been added since. Searching for "Roomba" might find something more up-to-date.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking but nothing is coming up - I really think there might be a bug

Comment: open questions are eligible for [30-days and 365-days auto-deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/165773)

Comment: I see...so sounds like I got bit by the exact thing the first commenter was concerned about

Comment: I gave it an undelete vote and an up vote, I'll see if I can grab the bounty later on ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As it says in:

[Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

> ... the Community user will delete questions in the following circumstances:
>
> **If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked

Which matched the question exactly.

So, the monthly "dead questions" cleanup process ran and removed that post.

Comment: *sigh* I guess we're past the point of discussing whether this is a good policy or not...

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Arguably, the roomba doesn't get enough. The problem is you never got any upvotes and that single downvote...

Comment: @Deduplicator [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601)