# Ancient, closed question edited and nominated for reopening - abort, retry, fail?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions, old-questions, vote-to-reopen

The offender: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731924/is-there-an-equivalent-of-pythons-timeit-module-in-java

This particular question was edited almost **half a decade** after it was asked and closed. Ignoring the fact that the edit made was minor, and IMO should never have been approved, the editor has nominated it for reopening, which I don't believe is useful either.

I would like to know the official viewpoint on this - is it okay to "necro" such old questions in this way, particularly if they're closed? Is there a "statute of limitations" on SO?

Comment: The edit is IMO useless as it doesn't make the question any more on topic. Reopening also does not make sense, as it still asks for an external library.

Comment: And btw, the second revision seems like a clear case of somebody really really wanting that copy editor badge. I'd usually flag something like that but I doubt anything will be done over a two year old minor offense...

Comment: Notified OP and editor.

Comment: @l4mpi I did think about the badge aspect, but then why would the user make it obvious by nominating the question for reopening? It's just bizarre all around...

Comment: The editor only has 500+ rep, no closevote privileges, and barely enough to see pending closevotes. I would take this to imply a less than fully formed idea of what the community considers acceptable, or how the close reasons are typically applied.  Likely no harm intended.

Comment: @IanKemp I was talking about the second _revision_, not the third - my previous comment was unclear as it said "second edit". The third rev is probably an attempt at grabbing 2 rep for a suggested edit. And the editor itself cannot nominate it for reopening yet, that was probably an edit reviewer or somebody from the reopen queue.

Comment: @l4mpi Come now, that space made a significant difference to the readability of the question, and you know it!

Comment: @l4mpi Yes, you're right - it was probably a faulty review (2 actually) resulting in the reopen votes.

Comment: Relevant: [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077)

Comment: Sorry to generate such a debate... as the "offender": basically I had the same question the other day and found no solution elsewhere. I thought it was better for SO to re-open the question instead of asking it again... but looks like was not the best choice. I meant no harm or points: I really believe the question is interesting. Probably it could be reworded so, when Python people searches for "a Java way to time small pieces of code", they will find an answer.

Comment: @edrabc Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 17):

For the general case, I would say no, there should not be a statute of limitations on improving an old question and voting to reopen it. If you can salvage the question, please do so.

In this particular case, though, the question was not salvaged.

> I was amazed at Python's timeit module and I would like to know if there's an equivalent in Java (in the standard library or as third-party module), in order to time/profile small bits of code in a fast way.

If that were asked today it would be closed as asking for an off-site resource. There's no point in editing a question just to exchange one close reason for another.

Comment: +1 for clear distinction between general and specific answers.

Answer (score -9):

I found [the second edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7791053) to be [a great improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731924/is-there-an-equivalent-of-pythons-timeit-module-in-java#comment47740148_2731924). It's a more general form of what I asked originally (Java ecosystem vs. Java stdlib).

I'm also the person that voted for it to be re-opened. I think it's worth it.