# What posts get deleted, and why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, statistics

A fair number of posts get deleted on Stack Overflow each month, for a wide variety of reasons and by a diverse set of methods.

Because these posts are, by definition, *not visible* and not searchable, there tends to be a lot of misinformation about how much gets deleted and who deletes it.

So, for the sake of discussion, let's have some numbers on what has been recently deleted, who deleted it, and why.

Answer (score 111):

**1,670,492** posts were deleted on Stack Overflow during the year of 2020. That breaks down as follows:

| Post Type | Deleted by... | Posts Deleted | % of total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Question | Author vote | 420,215 | 25.16 % |
| Question | Auto-deletion: AbandonedQuestions | 304,913 | 18.25 % |
| Question | Auto-deletion: AbandonedClosed | 222,854 | 13.34 % |
| Answer | Author vote | 202,575 | 12.13 % |
| Question | Auto-deletion: DeadQuestions | 177,528 | 10.63 % |
| Answer | Moderator | 135,167 | 8.09 % |
| Answer | Parent question deleted (Auto-deletion: AbandonedClosed) | 47,335 | 2.83 % |
| Answer | Parent question deleted (Author vote) | 42,743 | 2.56 % |
| Question | 3rd-party vote | 24,030 | 1.44 % |
| Answer | Review | 23,638 | 1.42 % |
| Answer | Parent question deleted (3rd-party vote) | 14,845 | 0.89 % |
| Question | Moderator | 10,878 | 0.65 % |
| Answer | Parent question deleted (Author was deleted) | 8,520 | 0.51 % |
| Question | Author was deleted | 8,281 | 0.50 % |
| Answer | Parent question deleted (Moderator) | 6,750 | 0.40 % |
| Answer | Spam/Offensive flags | 5,889 | 0.35 % |
| Answer | Converted to Comment | 5,227 | 0.31 % |
| Question | Spam/Offensive flags | 3,292 | 0.20 % |
| Answer | 3rd-party vote | 2,288 | 0.14 % |
| Answer | Author was deleted | 1,529 | 0.09 % |
| Question | Auto-deletion: MigrationStubs | 1,319 | 0.08 % |
| Answer | Parent question migrated | 439 | 0.03 % |
| Answer | Parent question deleted (Spam/Offensive flags) | 138 | 0.01 % |
| Question | Auto-deletion: RejectedMigrations | 62 | 0.00 % |
| Answer | Parent question deleted (Auto-deletion: RejectedMigrations) | 21 | 0.00 % |
| Answer | Parent question migration rejected | 8 | 0.00 % |
| Answer | Parent question deleted (Auto-deletion: AbandonedQuestions) | 3 | 0.00 % |
| Answer | Parent question deleted (Auto-deletion: DeadQuestions) | 2 | 0.00 % |
| Answer | Other | 2 | 0.00 % |
| Answer | via Vote (probably owner-deleted) | 1 | 0.00 % |

Note that during this same time period, **5,972,029** posts were *created*.

This looks only at posts that were deleted during this time period *and remain deleted*. It does not count posts that were deleted and then undeleted, nor does it double-count those that were deleted, undeleted, and then re-deleted in the same manner as the first deletion. There are arguments to be made for counting all of these things, but they are few in number and mostly just add confusion. "Other" mostly involves crazy scenarios where posts got deleted *twice* without being undeleted; as such, they're likely counted twice.

Previous years: [2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/296609/6) [2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/296609/7) [2018](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/296609/8) [2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/296609/10)

Comment: What's the difference between a "dead" question and an "abandoned" question?

Comment: what does  parent deleted means?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam I would assume that means the question the answer was posted to was deleted.

Comment: So the two biggest blocks (80% combined) are from an algorithm and from the author, each ranking in at every 2 of 5 deleted posts.

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006), @Josh - "Dead" is the 30-day section, "Abandoned" is the 365-day section, "AbandonedClosed" is the 9-day section.

Comment: Those darn mods delete a lot of stuff!!

Comment: I know you were probably joking, @bluefeet, but seriously, for those people who are about to upvote your comment to express their anti-mod-deletion viewpoint: mod and third-party deletion combined is _well_ less than half of self deletions.

Comment: What's the difference between *Author vote* and *Owner deleted*? Is *Owner deleted* a mod action which deletes a user along with all of his posts?

Comment: When a user is deleted, any posts owned by them scoring < 0 are deleted as well, @Lucas. There's also a mod tool that'll delete ALL posts owned by the user along with them - this is generally used for spammers. I suppose I could've called those "Owner **was** deleted" and avoided this confusion.

Comment: You have rows with `Answer    Parent deleted (reason)`, but then there is a row with 206 answers that has `Answer    Parent deleted [nothing]`.

Comment: No wonder I can't keep up!

Comment: That's an artifact of how I implemented this query, @HomegrownTomato: it won't pick up the reason if the *question* wasn't also deleted during the same timeframe. Such as, for instance, when a bunch of old migrations to [programmers.se] are suddenly rejected, causing the answers to be resurrected... Below long-ago-deleted questions... only to be choked to death in the night by the script that is responsible for ensuring deleted questions have only deleted answers. Some of these old questions had a LOT of answers, hence their migration to progse.

Comment: @Shog9 Are [any of these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt) already implemented?

Comment: No, @Pang - believe me, you'll know when they are.

Comment: I'm very curious about what that 1 "Other" is :)

Comment: Not aliens. Definitely not aliens.

Comment: It would be nice if this included the number of created questions in this 30 day period, to at least get a feel for the ebb and flow of questions.  If [this particular search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2015-05-12..2015-06-11) is accurate, then while we gained ~523K questions, we shed about 24% of that number in the same period.

Comment: @Shog9 Was asking because it seems Roomba failed to delete, say, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823484/licenses-merging) ([timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8823484/timeline)). Is Roomba dead?

Comment: The roomba is alive and kicking, @Pang. That question just hasn't met the [current roomba requirements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006). Now that it has been downvoted, it soon will be reaped.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I though it was downvoted a few days ago?

Comment: @Pang: exactly. Now wait 30 days. It would now be classified as dead, but it wasn't dead until very recently. It may be there is some other component I am missing here though.

Comment: I'm curious about the 1 singular mysterious "other" post....

Comment: @MartijnPieters It won't take 30 days. A dead question will be removed when the dead-questions script runs, which happens weekly. Next run in about 36 hours.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato: ah, yes; that's the issue, the script doesn't run every single day.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets: Jon Skeet said "no" out loud when looking at an incorrect post and it was deleted immediately. He tries to avoid that, but sometimes it just slips out.

Comment: Interesting that 12 people answered spam/offensive questions.

Comment: @Scimonster normally the same spammers do that. Now they ask seemsly valid questions to inmediatly answer with their spam. Users have been informed to flag such questions as spam too.

Comment: how many posts are created in a typical 30-day period?  I'm guessing it's in the 300K+ range, currently

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Per Makoto's query above, it appears to be upwards of 540,000.

Comment: The *probably not aliens* has increased to 9! We need a meta post to guess that now.

Comment: The trends would be easier to discern if you posted another answer for 2017 instead of replacing 2016 data with it...

Comment: @if.... true, but the question is specifically about showing the numbers for recent events. It's not about showing trends.

Comment: @Gimby I imagine the answer author could have convinced the question author to reformulate the question to allow this slight expansion of its scope.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of "Author vote"? Is it activation of the *"delete"* link on a post?

Comment: Yes, @peter. Used for consistency with UI terminology, but of course it only takes one vote.

Comment: That 1 post could be anyone of us :)