# How did OP delete his question which has an answer?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

I have answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540712/trying-to-get-equals-button-to-function-properly-in-calculator/34540730#34540730), and then after I went to improve my answer with more information of the problem then the question was deleted within some minutes of the question being asked.

[image]

How is the question deleted which has an answer?  
Can the OP, who asks the question, delete the question if there is an answer?

Comment: If you feel your answer would have helped others, you can flag one of your own posts and use the "other" to get a moderator to look at it. They may undelete the question and upvote an answer so the asker cannot delete the question again. However, if it was a "to be improved later" answer it's probably not worth it. Some post, grab an answer, delete and submit their homework. They hope the delete means that their tutor can't spot the ask for help.

Comment: From answerer's perspective, it's kind of annoying when this happens.  Perhaps a useful addition to the rule chain shown in the answer by @TinyGiant would be to require that OP cannot delete their question for 24 hours after the singleton answer is posted.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, I would go against it. It's also frustrating to see a question which should be closed/deleted-by-owner receives some crappy answers that may even grab some you don't know where they come from upvotes, making the post undeletable... Unfortunately, I saw this situation a lot more than the one described by OP...

Comment: For [only 0.6% of questions asked in the past year](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313857/4639281), it doesn't seem like a  problem worth solving. What Kaiido refers to occurs far more often @Robert.

Comment: I'm puzzled for robert's argument vs Kaiido's... Anyway the 0.6% figure is not relevant at all : most post are ok, so any problem does not matter relative to the whole bunch of post made on S.O. each day. And after all, a 'on hold' post might remain a day or more... don't know how a 'hall of shame' could be done, worth a though i think... :-)

Comment: A problem associated with 0.6% of all questions asked is not worth fixing? I was not aware of that. I suspect that Kaiido's objection could be mitigated by some additional conditioning, such as "any question without downvotes, that has one answer that has no upvotes or downvotes, cannot be deleted for 24 hours after the posting of an answer". After all, a reasonable possible first indication that a question is not well-formed might be downvotes (unless you place no stock in voting at all.). But there's little point in discussing or trying to work the problem if it's not a problem worth solving

Comment: I was just saying : the 0.6% figure alone does not help choosing between Robert and Kaiido's point of view. When i said 'i'm puzzled' i meant it. Unfortunately (?or not?), bad questions might not bring either downvotes or close votes, but just no views or no reaction from viewers. Furthermore the 'i ask/get answer/then delete leaving no trace' behaviour is not an easy pattern to track. ... Maybe flagging and trusting moderators is the best way to go...

Comment: @Robert: Something is already done about it. If the user makes a habit out of it, they get post banned. [11%](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313854/statistics-on-answered-questions-deleted-by-their-author/313857#comment289380_313857) of the users that have done this go on to make a habit out of it and get banned. So, while I agree it is a bad thing, it doesn't happen often enough for me to think that further complication should be added to an already complicated system. That's just me though. If you want consensus, I would recommend posting a discussion question on the subject.

Comment: @GameAlchemist questions like that don't warrant flags, they warrant downvotes and delete votes from 20k+ rep users. See: [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) for information on what content is automatically deleted.

Comment: Tiny managed to misrepresent his own statistics here, @Robert: it's not 0.6% of all questions, it's 0.6% of all *answered* questions scoring >= 0. This implies that out of every 166 answers you post (to reasonably decent questions) one will be deleted along with the question - but of course, it's not that simple; questions that attract multiple answers or votes for answers will rarely ever be affected, while questions on more obscure topics stand a greater chance of getting hit. Meanwhile, [there are a bunch of other ways](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296609) for answers to get deleted.

Comment: @TinyGiant : but you can't downvote questions when they were already deleted by a 'theft' poster that got its answer... Only the one who got used by the poster can flag to have that behavior getting noticed. (worst thing being : if the answerer has not enough rep, he won't even see the deleted question...)

Comment: @Shog9 That's what I meant to say, thanks for clarifying my error.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I was talking about the situation that Kaiido mentioned, not the situation that Robert is talking about. I thought that is what you were referring to in your last comment: "*Maybe flagging and trusting moderators is the best way to go*"

Comment: @RobertCrovella, IMO, a better solution for these cases would be to actually let the answerer access the deleted posts in such cases, so he might be able to post a self-answered question from these.  Easier to implement and better results.

Comment: the Q&A is undeleted now. I suggest that you improve your answer. It's a bit "curt".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> ## When can’t I delete my own post?
>
> You can’t delete your own question when it:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has an accepted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
>
> [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/288751)

If we invert that list we get the conditions for when a question *can* be deleted.

The owner of the question can delete it if it:

- has no upvoted answer, and
- has no accepted answer, and
- has less than two answers

#### Related:

- [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented)
- [Better oversight for self-deleted answered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244839/better-oversight-for-self-deleted-answered-questions)

Comment: as @RobertCrovella pointed out wisely, another useful condition would be to add a time out, to avoid 'i ask, get my answer, and leave before anyone noticed i asked'... ( And i won't trigger the debate, but such 'you are just tools for me' users should be banned...).

Comment: Of course, this would remove one of the primary uses for question self-deletion, @GameAlchemist: folks who post a question and then quickly realize they were looking at the wrong problem / forgot to plug it in / missed a typo somewhere.

Comment: @Shog9 There are good reasons to delete a question, sure (i did). And bad ones, just as sure (i didn't ...). Maybe moderators could decide, i don't claim to have the answer.

Comment: Those aren't good reasons to delete a crappy question that has a valuable answer.

Comment: So we could ask moderators (or someone else) to review another 26 questions a day, or we could just ask folks to flag when this ability is abused and review a much smaller number of cases, @Game. Perhaps there's a compromise to be had here somewhere.

Comment: The voting process already signals good content/bad content.  Let it work.  The ability of OP to delete a non-downvoted question that has an answer is short-circuiting the voting process.  And there is the side issue that someone invested time in the answer.

Comment: The problem of course is that the system doesn't know when there's a valuable answer unless it has upvotes or something, @RobertCrovella (in which case deletion is already prohibited). Folks post crappy answers all the time; in fact, finding your question has attracted an answer that isn't helpful is probably a strong motivator to delete it in the first place. There are already strong disincentives here; once upon a time, this was much more common (and folks cried out) - but as we've tightened the restrictions, moderators have been asked to handle much more of the load.

Comment: To Shog9 : i couldn't be more clear when saying ' i don't claim to have the answer'. Wrongdoers will find their way within any rule set anyway.  Most agree with 'i'll delete my question since i get crappy answers.'. Puzzling.
@RobertCrovella : for the crappy question/valuable answer thing : most friendly i say to you that there's a whole philosophical debate behind this (pearls...), and there are people, like me, who just think there's not even the slightest meaning of a good answer to a wrong question. Like 'hey i need a screwdriver to nail' : 'ok, take that ladder'... :-)

Comment: OK. To be clear I don't really care about folks deleting their own content. The noise I'm making is just due to the fact that this process allows them to delete somebody else's content without going through the "usual" process. But I acknowledge its a complex world. And this might be a nit. (Except when it happens to you. Then it's annoying.)

Comment: Not addressed by this Answer in the "Inverted Conditions" Section, about "*has no accepted answer*", but even if there is an 'Accepted Answer', the Asker has Control over the 'Accepted Answer', => if they *unaccept* the Answer, then they can/could still delete the whole Question (and the Answer with it), right...?

Answer (score 9):

We all agree that, as [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313730/how-did-op-delete-his-question-which-has-an-answer#comment-289257) by Robert Crovella,

> From answerer's perspective, it's kind of annoying when this happens

***What can we do then?***

---

**If you still have access to the content of the posts** *(lucky unclosed tab or >10K)*, and you do think that your answer is valuable for others than OP,

- grab the content,
- make a new **improved** question from it,
- self-answer this question with your valuable answer.

You may not receive the 15 *UnicornPoints* the deleter owes you, but you will probably grab more views than on an obscure "give me teh codez"* question.

Your answer will also win from it, by getting a more controllable starting point, it may focus on what made it valuable in your eyes.

<sup>* I don't have metrics, but I feel that most questions which show this behavior are of this kind</sup>

---

**If you don't have this content anymore**, *well it was deleted, right?*

- This is now a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) ([Grant access to deleted singleton-answer & question also to <10K rep answerers when question is deleted by owner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313870/grant-access-to-deleted-singleton-answer-question-to-10k-rep-answerers-when)) in order to be able to gain access to question deleted by the owner if we've posted a singleton non-negative answer on it, even for <10K rep users.
- As for today, you could ask a >10K rep user on chat to give it to you from question's link.

<sub>Disclaimer: *This is not properly an answer to the question, but it comes from the discussions in comments.*</sub>

Comment: Really great idea.

Comment: I though also about this : ' you answer was deleted : make a wiki out of it !'. But as you say here the core issue (for a <10k rep user) is to be able to access to a post -meaning some efforts- we've made even if the O.P. deleted it. If the user can also notify the moderators for a 'lack' of citizenship (...) it seems like a neat solution.

Comment: @GameAlchemist, I've actually made it a [feature-request] : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313870/grant-access-to-deleted-singleton-answer-question-to-10k-rep-answerers-when