# Statistics on answered questions deleted by their author

Tags: support, deleted-questions, statistics

**What percentage of open, zero or greater scored, answered questions are deleted by their author within 24 hours of posting?**

> ### When can’t I delete my own post?
>
> You can’t delete your own question when it:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has an accepted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
>
> [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/288751)

The requirement is that the author deleted their own question, so I'm defining "answered" here as: Has one answer, not upvoted or accepted, that was not deleted at the time the question was deleted.

I'm trying to filter out questions that would be deleted for a reason other than the author got the answer they were looking for, which is why I imposed the restriction of the question being open, and zero or greater scored.

---

I <s>attempted</s> bugged [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) to attempt to use SEDE to figure this out, but unfortunately the owner is not in the postswithdeleted table:

```sql
select top 100 *
from postswithdeleted
where deletiondate is not null
-- SEDE
```

Rene kept trying and figured out that we can find some information about questions deleted shortly after receiving an answer:

```sql
select 'site://q/' + cast(q.id as nvarchar) +'| question' as [link]
     , q.creationdate as [q create]
     , q.deletiondate as [q del]
     , a.creationdate as [a create]
     , a.deletiondate as [a del]
     , datediff(n, a.creationdate, q.deletiondate) as [q del after a]
from postswithdeleted a 
inner join postswithdeleted q on a.parentid = q.id
where a.deletiondate is not null
and q.deletiondate is not null 
and datediff(n, a.creationdate, q.deletiondate) < 60
order by datediff(n, a.creationdate, q.deletiondate) desc
-- SEDE
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to get *accurate* results from public data for this, I'm afraid. I'll post the queries I'm using to demonstrate why:

```sql
select count(*)
from Posts q
where PostTypeId=1
and CreationDate > getdate()-365
and Score >= 0
and ClosedDate is null
-- answer that was either not deleted, not deleted at the time of question deletion,
-- or undeleted and then re-deleted *after* the question was deleted (rare)
and exists (select 1 from Posts a where a.ParentId=q.Id 
  and isnull(a.DeletionDate, getdate()) >= isnull(q.DeletionDate, q.CreationDate))
```

**1,679,690** questions scoring >= 0 asked in the past 365 days having at least one answer that is either not deleted or was deleted along with the question.

```sql
select count(*)
from Posts q
where PostTypeId=1
and CreationDate > getdate()-365
and Score >= 0
and ClosedDate is null
-- answer that was either not deleted, not deleted at the time of question deletion,
-- or undeleted and then re-deleted *after* the question was deleted (rare)
and exists (select 1 from Posts a where a.ParentId=q.Id 
  and isnull(a.DeletionDate, getdate()) >= isnull(q.DeletionDate, q.CreationDate)) 
and DeletionDate < CreationDate+1
and exists 
  (
    select 1 from PostHistory 
    where PostHistoryTypeId=12 and PostId=q.Id 
    and CreationDate = q.DeletionDate
    -- handle case where author deleted question and was then also deleted.
    -- does NOT handle the case where the author deleted the question by deleting
    -- their account, since that doesn't touch posts scoring >= 0
    and (UserId=q.OwnerUserId or (q.OwnerUserId is null and q.OwnerDisplayName=UserDisplayName))
  )
```

**10,144** questions scoring >= 0 asked in the past 365 days having at least one answer that was not deleted at the time of question deletion were deleted in < 1 day by their authors.

Thus, the answer over the past 365 days is: **0.6%**

#### See also: [What posts get deleted, and why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why/296609#296609)

Comment: wonder how many of these 0.6% eventually hit the question block / rate limit / warning. "The only way to get question-banned by deleting questions is if you get in the habit of deleting them *after someone has taken the time to answer them*..." ([Do you get question bans by deleting your own posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311813/839601))

Comment: To date, 14% of them, @gnat. Only 11% of users did this more than once (made a "habit" of it); the rest got themselves banned for other reasons.

Comment: interesting, thanks. Does that include deleted accounts? It may be fairly common for this kind of users, _dump a homework -> get an answer -> delete question -> hit the ban -> delete account_

Comment: It may be common relative to... Something. But these are already rare, and deleted accounts attached to them are rarer still - I included them in the total for completeness, but the actual number of these questions associated with deleted accounts is about 200 for the year. Even counting downvoted questions, it's under 400. There is a surprisingly tiny population of users who are both sufficiently clever to get around restrictions and sufficiently not-clever to *need* to get around restrictions. A very annoying tiny population though it may be.

Comment: very interesting. 200 of 10,000 is really negligible, I didn't expect that. Possibly many really malicious homework dumps get buried in Triage and miss the chance to get an answer at all, this would explain why they don't enter the stats we discuss

Comment: Triage continues to affect roughly 20% of questions asked, which likely covers a lot of the worst offenders (behavior that'll get you q-banned will put you in purgatory a lot sooner).