# Why is a question that I answered allowed to be deleted?

Tags: discussion

**The situation**

This question ([Making a recursive method with triple fibonacci in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782763/making-a-recursive-method-with-triple-fibonacci-in-java/39782838)) was posted and had a few up-votes, so I decided to copy the code and run it to look for issues. I posted an answer that explained the confusion after working through it.

However, to my surprise, soon afterward the question was deleted.

**The question**

When I try to delete a question that I asked and that has an answer, it doesn't let me. So why did it let the poster of the question linked above delete his question? What is the difference?

Also, from a design perspective, why is this allowed? I feel a bit cheated that I put in the time to help out and I cant get any recognition for my work, even though the answer was already posted.

Comment: The deletion prevention requires either more than one answer or a positive score on the single answer, unfortunately.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Does systematic self deleting need to be prevented?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74466)

Comment: Also relevant: [Statistics on answered questions deleted by their author](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313854/4639281)

Comment: Everybody who is upvoting this should visit the question and vote to undelete.

Comment: In other news, the autoban script takes wasting other people's time into account when determining if a user should be blocked.

Comment: @Will The question isn't going to be useful to future visitors.  The OP did the site a favor by deleting it.

Comment: If that's true then this is also relevant: [Should one answer terribly poor questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293931/should-one-answer-terribly-poor-questions)

Comment: IMHO it should stay deleted.  It is a "typo" and should be closed and deleted as such.  That fact the OP did it just saves us all a bunch of time and effort.  I get that getting rep is nice but there are better questions to get it from.