# OP deleted question after getting a satisfactory answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680355/how-to-join-linq-dictionary-collection-and-object-collection/) earlier which I thought was fairly straightforward. I gave my answer and soon OP commented on it saying its good but requires a certain modification. After editing my answer to fit the new spec, OP promptly decided to delete the question.

Safe to say I am not very happy about this. What is the correct course of action here?

Comment: Yeah.  They do that.  Post homework, get an answer, ask for more, get complete answer, copy out answer, delete to avoid their prof's anti-cheat scripts.  That's how it works:(

Comment: @MartinJames Yea but what if the prof is a 10k SO user?

Comment: @stybl Then they'd be able to see the question if someone linked it to them, but since Google's web crawler isn't 10k, they're still not going to find it in any searches.

Comment: @MartinJames Looking through the question list (and it's a *long* list) it doesn't fit the MO of a student.  Just a bad programmer asking a question on SO instead of using Google, and getting answers from other people without having to look through the search results to get their answer.

Comment: You see a user who hasn't put much effort into their work and you avoid them like the plague.  The more you see, the better you can smell them out.

Comment: Relevant: [Statistics on answered questions deleted by their author](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313854). The moral of the story there is that this doesn't happen very often, and users that make a habit out of it usually work themselves into a question ban.

Comment: I experienced the same thing myself, and got a little frustrated to be honest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not actually a good question, and there's no way that the question is going to be useful to anyone else if it was undeleted.  That the OP cleaned up the question themselves instead of requiring a bunch of community members to all have to do it for them is a *good* thing.

Comment: Indeed. The bad thing is asking it in the first place. If this is a pattern of behavior, then it needs to be addressed, because it is an abuse of our resources.

Comment: @CodyGray Given that the user has 335 *undeleted* questions, and looking through a handful of random questions in their semi-recent history, all looking extremely low quality, I'd personally call that a bit of a pattern.

Comment: this doesn't seem to address OP question about what is the correct course of action here. I'd say the correct course of action is to abstain of answering homework dumps but maybe your take is different

Comment: @gnat The correct course of action for this *specific* question is to do nothing.  The question was deleted, which is a good thing, and I don't really see anything else that needs to happen here.  I agree with you that a good takeaway for the OP to take going forward is to abstain from answering extremely low quality questions like these in the future.