# Why was my answer in meta deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

This [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333480/395857) on this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333477/395857) on Roomba was deleted. Why?

I don't see any rule from the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) that I have infringed.

---

Here was the answer, if you cannot see it from the link:

> Roomba should be disabled, or at the very least, only focus on
>   downvoted questions:
>
> - if a question is not good, it gets downvoted. If off-topic, it gets closed.
> - 1 year is short, I have had dozens of (good) questions at risk, simply because few people noticed the question or were interested
>     (specialized questions)
> - it conflicts with the Necromancer badge -> make up your mind, do we want to encourage answering old questions or not?
> - downvoters use it to delete questions [on purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269392/178179)
> - users are [not notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694/178179) when a
>     question is deleted
> - it's a basic ethic, at least for me, to respect user content from users unless it is obvious garbage.
> - it happened to me quite a few times that a question removed by Roomba got upvoted after I reposted it.
> - questions older that 60 days that get deleted cannot even be retrieved by the user (sometimes saved by Wayback Machine, but still,
>     really not cool).
> - Some solutions are developed after the question is asked.
> - etc.
>
> One issue when discussing this kind policies is that active people
>   tend to mostly write answers. If you've asked a significant number of
>   questions I guess you'll be more understanding.

[image]

Comment: From the looks of it, it was deleted because a link showed up that said "delete" as a result of the assumption that negatively voted answers are low quality; a false assumption on meta. Removing unpopular opinions isn't improving the quality of meta, it is censoring it.

Comment: From the looks of it, it was undeleted because a link showed up that said "undelete" as a result of the assumption that people delete negatively voted answers because they're negatively voted; a false assumption everywhere.  Removing off topic content isn't censoring opinions, it's merely asking that they be posted in an appropriate location.

Comment: Censorship? Seriously? Considering he's asking a question about why it was deleted, I would say there is no "censorship" going on. Let's keep the hyperbole to a minimum. Also, obligatory XKCD link: https://xkcd.com/1357/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I find it ironic to include an XKCD link while attempting to say anything of substance. This isn't 4chan.

Comment: @TravisJ It's not ironic, in that it says exactly what he means it to say, rather than the opposite of its point.  And to say it's not substantive is to indicate you didn't read it.  It makes a substantive point, albeit in a comedic manor.

Comment: @TravisJ If you'd like a proper example of irony, take a look at your first comment here.  Your comment makes a wildly inaccurate assumption that others made a wildly inaccurate assumption.  *That* is ironic.

Comment: "Censorship" is perhaps a little strong, but this could be seen as artificially suppressing an opinion. The point of Meta is to encourage discussion in the community about the operation of Stack Overflow. As such, people often express opinions or feature requests in answers that aren't direct responses to questions, but are related. Moderators are very careful about removing any of these, as well as unpopular comments, because to do so could be seen as trying to suppress one side of an argument. It makes moderating Meta a little different than for the main site.

Comment: @Servy - You seem a little defensive about this topic. Also note that I am talking about the metric to show the "delete" button, and not the discerning of users who action it. Making deletion so easy on meta has caused problems in the past and that is why the threshold was altered, but that was merely a short term solution.

Comment: @BradLarson Sure, as well they should, because diamond moderators (and employees) are in essence, "the law". As such, the censorship charge would make more sense (as only governments can censor free speech). The answer in question here was not, AFAIK, deleted by moderators, but rather users with sufficient reputation to do so. As such, it is entirely within their purview to remove those responses, asking that the OP instead create a new question, which would seem to be the opposite of suppressing opinion.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Nobody asked the OP to create a new question, or even said they thought the answer was off-topic.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot ... Isn't that what Servy is saying in his answer?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Sorry, I wasn't clear. Nobody said anything *before deleting the answer.* Is the OP supposed to read minds? Or are people expected to post "Why was my Meta answer deleted?" every time there's a deletion?

Answer (score -12):

Your answer is completely off topic.  It's in no way addressing the point of the question, it's just you making a proposal that's entirely unrelated to the topic at hand.  If you want to propose a change, then ask a question to propose that change, rather than posting an answer to a question proposing a completely different change.

Comment: I do appreciate that you explained your reasoning here. I can see where you are coming from. However, the answer doesn't seem that off topic, as the discussion was based on roomba. One person proposes a change to a small aspect of roomba, and another user said "let's just remove the whole feature". While wildly unpopular, that still strikes me as being on topic to the discussion.

Comment: @TravisJ It's a wildly unrelated change to the feature.  One person asking one specific question about one feature doesn't mean any discussion of any change to that feature makes sense in that question.  In the same way that it wouldn't be appropriate for me to post an answer to this question explaining why some spam post was deleted, because the question is asking about why posts are deleted.

Comment: To be fair, I think a closer example would be an answer to this discussion suggesting that the deletion feature be removed. It would definitely received a lot of downvotes, and probably be deleted at some point, under the same arguments you make here. It would probably also be undeleted if the poster requested it though, because it is still along the same overall topic. Being highly downvoted sends enough of a message. Also, strongly related to this discussion is the one where the raised the downvote threshold for meta deletion: Strongly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267969/1026459

Comment: @TravisJ Sure, that would also be an example of an entirely offtopic answer that should be deleted, as it's not about the question at hand, and should be its own question.  As far as the link, stating that there are other posts deleted because of their opinion, rather than because of their on-topicness, is *entirely* off point here.  *This* question was deleted because it's off topic.  That others may (or may not) have been deleted because of the opinion they reflect is another matter entirely.

Comment: I disagree the answer was off-topic. It seemed earnest but absurd to the point of not really being applicable.

Comment: @ssube Saying it's not applicable is to say it's off topic...

Comment: You can be exceedingly wrong without being off-topic, IMO.

Comment: @ssube *You* said that you feel the answer isn't applicable.  That's a *synonym* with it being off topic.  An off topic answer is *defined* as being an answer that's not applicable to the quesiton.

Comment: I think I misspoke when using "applicable." The answer was on-topic in that it does address the problem, but it was not applicable in the sense of being a useful solution. As far as I understand, that is the line between down votes and delete votes (bad vs off-topic).

Comment: All that is needed to make the answer relevant is to make a small edit noting how the proposed change would make comments irrelevant. I've done so.

Comment: And yet, it has since accumulated 2 delete votes and is teetering on the verge of removal again, @Shog9.

Comment: @Cody Gray: News flash: trusted users use their delete votes differently from moderators.

Comment: Both of those delete votes were there already when I edited it, @Cody. That it's now gone > 24 hours without a third one is a pretty decent result, IMHO. That said, there's certainly nothing stopping folks from deleting it - they just need a different justification for it now.

Comment: I don't know who brought moderators into this, @Bolt. And I wasn't aware that the delete votes were there already before the edit was made. For the record, I agree with Shog's edit and very much disagree with the notion of deleting the answer. I was merely expressing my concern that the answer seemed about to be deleted again, in spite of the edit. I'm glad to see that my assumption was wrong.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I did - I'm just saying, no moderator would delete such an answer, and all of the moderators do happen to agree with keeping it undeleted. Trusted users use their delete votes very differently.