# Are 50K unanswered, no up-vote, questions between 2008 & April 2014 too many?

Tags: discussion, questions, automatic-deletion

I accidentally ran a data stack exchange query on this site and was surprised there are EXACTLY 50,000 questions that have zero or negative score and have gone unanswered since 2008 up to April 2014.

Here is the query if you would like to confirm:

```
SELECT p.Title, p.Id, p.Score, p.ViewCount, p.CreationDate, p.ClosedDate, p.AnswerCount, u.DisplayName
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
AND (p.Score < 1 OR p.Score IS NULL)
AND p.AnswerCount = 0
and p.ClosedDate is null
AND p.CreationDate < '2014-04-17'
order by p.CreationDate ASC
```

The same query ran on ***Ask Ubuntu*** returns 28 results which is humanly possible to vote close.

The 50,000 in ***Stack Overflow*** though could only be deleted with a bot.

Is there an initiative to auto-delete questions like these 50K?

Comment: Why should they be deleted? Zero-score questions aren't necessarily bad. Negatively scored questions with no answers will already be [automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) removed.

Comment: Primarily because they are are unreproducible and/or abandoned questions and/or poorly written and/or went away on their own and/or dealing with an old version of software and the problem no longer exists. It could also give the false impression no one looks at questions when it was really one of the preceding. That said there is also a view count which the query reports (p.ViewCount) and on the first page at least this count was low. The final point Iis it could help cull the site of "fluff" or "noise".

Comment: Perhaps that's true for a large amount of them. But do we really want to unleash a bot removing questions which the community hasn't left any indication as to it being a bad question? And at a quick glance (excluding merged questions), many of the questions seem perfectly valid.

Comment: @Rob My query never took merged questions into account as that never showed up on AU site. Looking at Stack Overflow results the first four or five results all show merged which should of course stay in place as a "Sign Post". I'll need to rerun it without merged questions.

Comment: This should do it: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/704692

Comment: Wow we went from exactly 50,000 rows to exactly 50 rows with your query. Yes things look well under control. Thank you for the SEDE database structure lesson and sorry I didn't filter out merged questions in the first place :(

Comment: Do note that I placed a 'TOP 50' clause, as it there were far too many questions to load. There are currently 199,337 matching questions.

Comment: It doesn't harm things to let it run though the entire database though does it?

Comment: No, it crashed, presumably because of the Post Link magic with 200,000 results

Comment: Post Link kept crashing on me yesterday so I simply eliminated it from my query today.

Comment: @Rob replacing "TOP 50" and post link with `p.title` instead returned 50,000 rows again which must be a max in SEDE. The first result was from 2009: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152540/close-window-in-tkinter-message-box and one could argue it should be deleted. But I'm not an expert on this site procedures and can't say for sure.

Comment: The last question on the list is dated 2012 so that probably means there are about 100,000 rows in the query. The last question was suggested to be migrated to a different SE site but never was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179793/is-my-data-access-leaking-connections

Comment: Are there high view counts and/or comment threads preventing these from being automatically deleted? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006

Comment: Related: [Time for roomba to ignore comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333477/time-for-roomba-to-ignore-comments)