# Too much importance given to questions with accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, accepted-answer, automatic-deletion

It seems to me that when an answer is accepted, it promotes the question & answer(s) a little too much.

For instance, one of the reasons a question (and its answers) is deleted by [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244519) is

- has no accepted answer

So basically if:

- user A (newbie with <15 rep) asks a bad question which gets 5 downvotes
- user B (newbie with <15 rep) provides a bad answer (and possibly gets downvotes)
- user A accepts the answer (but cannot upvote)

Of course, that doesn't apply if A upvotes answer or B upvotes question, but that's life & since votes are anonymous, you cannot be sure. And very low rep users cannot upvote, because they aren't trusted enough yet. The point is to at least avoid 0 or negative score & accepted to be well-considered.

The Q&A can have:

- a question with a zero or negative score
- a sole accepted answer with a zero or negative score

and in that case, if I'm not mistaken, Roomba won't delete it and it'll stay forever unless it's closed & deleted.

Maybe even worse: it will also be possible to link this question as an "original" question for duplicates (instead of a good "original" question), since googling a question can bring dupe searchers to this question (not sure at all that the relevance depends on votes when using google)

So the fact that it's not deleted and a possible candidate for a link to duplicates depends only on user A will to accept the answer whereas the Q&A is very bad.

Wouldn't it be time *not* to consider accepted answers as a criterion for valid Q&A for avoiding Roomba & linking to them when closing as dupes?

(I'm aware that a Roomba deleting *my* 0 score accepted answers on 0 score questions would make me lose [a few thousand rep](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:6451573%20is:answer%20score:0%20isaccepted:yes) - not all those 220+ answers answer a <=0 question, though, I couldn't filter accurately enough - , but that would be for the best)

As discussed in the comments, maybe 0 isn't the right threshold because it wouldn't be fair to low traffic tags. Negative could be the threshold, disregarding the fact that there's an accepted answer, *that* wouldn't change.

Comment: The main concern would be the tags/topics that just don't get much traffic at all, and where an accept from the OP is the only feedback the post has.  It'd probably be a better sell to allow deletion and make ineligible as a dup target if the answer has a negative score, even if accepted, rather than zero scored.  At that point you're basically treating the accept mark as if it's an upvote with respect to the roomba and dup target eligibility, no more, no less, which sounds about right.

Comment: @Servy yes, 0 can be the threshold, but < 0 can also be the threshold. I wasn't thinking about low traffic tag.

Comment: Do you have actual proof that this will be a beneficial change?  Can you point to evidence that suggests that this isn't going to remove value?

Comment: You need links to 0/0 Q&A which bring no value to the site ? what about -7/-1 accepted ? does it bring value to the site? ok: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884118/cant-print-number-from-11165200-to-11165300-in-python (I didn't want to quote that one int the question to avoid meta effect)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  At a minimum...I see a poorly phrased question which got beat up quite severely (from the comments, it seemed like it was easier to pick on the question than it was to give it any benefit of the doubt), and [your own remarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884118/cant-print-number-from-11165200-to-11165300-in-python#comment82734466_47884165) suggest that you're taking your belief that the question is off-topic (somehow) out on the answerer, which is a common yet regrettable practice.  Is it useful?  Probably not.  Does it still serve a valuable lesson:  sure.

Comment: ...that lesson being:  **don't blatantly copy-paste code from the Internet.**  I take the acceptance mark as a signal that the OP at least got 90% there.  There's the painfully obvious bug in the answer, but it at least *helped* the OP.  It'll help those that are paying attention, as well.

Comment: You are a wise fellow. Leaving bad q&a as long that there are negative votes doesnt hurt that much I agree.

Comment: Note that I downvoted the answer because it is technically wrong, not because the question is bad

Comment: For some hard numbers, there are currently over 5000 questions where the question score is negative, there is only one answer, the answer's score is negative, and the answer is accepted: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/773326/negative-questions-with-a-single-negative-but-accepted-answer. I may update this later to see exactly how many questions could be Roomba'd right now if an answer wasn't accepted.

Comment: that's what I was looking for. Would you mind editing the question to link to your query?

Comment: Maybe we can start with roomba of questions that were closed. I don't believe roomba touches closed questions, even with negative score, as long as there is an accepted answer with zero or positive score?

Comment: @Lundin no I don't think roomba deletes those. That would be a good start (and even if it stopped there, that would be good)

Comment: You've never seen what importance we do to the second class citizens https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333477/792066

Comment: Sort @TheGuywithTheHat query for lowest-scored answer, and at least the first hit (not linking here for obv. reasons) is clear evidence that accepted answer does not mean "valuable for posterity".  "don't use a tablet for data analysis, use a computer"... SMH

Comment: A sole accepted answer with zero score should be fine, and so is a question. I aaggrree that negatively scored questions and answers shouldn't be considered "good".

Comment: I saw some low-rep users self-answering + self-accepting, still with 0 votes. Quality of the Q+A were variables (sometimes terrible, sometimes OK).

Comment: 0 votes sometimes mean: no attention. So yes, it can be OK. Negative scoring should prevail on acceptance, though.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Closed Qs with bad As are all over the place and are not cleaned up by the Roomba...