# How long should you try to make an answer work, if you already have an other answer?

Tags: discussion

[Is there a function to find the difference between datetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865298/is-there-a-function-to-find-the-difference-between-datetimes/53870028#53870028)

I made this post recently, and the accepted answer works fine, but there is also another answer that I can't get to work properly.

Obviously I would like to use the fastest answer and I don't want to be rude by not testing the other answers since these people take their time to help me.

In my example there are 2 answers, but what if there are like 10 different answers and the first 1 you try works perfectly? Do you go back to try them all and if they give errors do you need to fix it to make it work accordingly? ( i am not a very good programmer yet, so fixing those errors would take me some time )

Comment: I would leave a comment if it doesn't work after you made sure your question can't be the source of the misunderstanding. I would leave the effort of providing a working answer to the user that wrote the answer.

Comment: Imo none. Because ,if you had a question on projectA change project and not able to test answer anymore. You are not required to accept/valid answer. I guess it's the best effort. thats for the "general" idea.

Answer (score 8):

The common expectation<sup>*</sup> is the question's author will abandon the question after asking and never provide feedback on answers or even come back. So, thank you for being an above average author and actually checking the answers.

More seriously, if you get an answer that answers the question *for you* (in whatever way you define that) - mark it as the accepted answer. Note that the checkmark only means the answer helped you the most. It does not mean the answer is completely correct or even a good answer. You can stop and go on with your life at this point (also other answers may actually be better).

Separately, you are welcome to evaluate all answers. There is no expectation that you spend a lot of (or even any) time on other answers after getting the answer you need. If you indeed tried other answer(s) and could not get them to work - add a comment under the answer, possibly downvote, if you know that the answer does not answer your question *as asked*. (Note that question you *asked* is not necessary one that you were actually interested in - be very aware of this difference when evaluating answers). Consider up-voting good and clear answers.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Official expectations can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - "do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well"</sub>

Comment: I think this is serious. Probably means "askers get their solutions and never come back". That's a bit of an excessive generalization, though

Comment: @usr2564301 about 75% serious. Edit by Makyen is exactly what I tried to say - in most cases there is zero feedback from question's author and I believe that's a baseline expectation of many people providing answers. I definitely don't *expect* question author to reply to answer in any way, but I do welcome it.

Comment: @usr2564301 The point of the paragraph is to say that the site is built to function properly even when the author of the question doesn't provide feedback on answers.  When the question author does take time to evaluate the quality of answers, that's nice, but's neither necessary nor is it their responsibility to do so.  The site is designed so that *the entire community* participates in evaluating the quality of the answer, unlike many other sites where it's just the question author, and perhaps a few moderators.

Answer (score 3):

Accept/read whatever answers you like, but evaluating all answers is often interesting for you when you ask a question.

And acceptance is your only decision, so answerers *know* that it can be complete random depending on who is asking. I'm not a great fan of acceptance myself ([Too much importance given to questions with accepted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360892/too-much-importance-given-to-questions-with-accepted-answers)). Well, it just states "it worked for me". It's a small indication of usefulness at least.

I've seen a lot of times the *worst* answer accepted, and the best (and highly upvoted) answers left unaccepted, just because the answer fixed a small typo in your code, when other answers pointed out issues with the complexity or security of your code, and explained how to fix it, but more effort was required to understand what was said.

For instance, if a high-reputation user answers, it's worth looking at the answer, because those people usually (not always) try to provide quality answers and know the rules about answering.

Also, I've seen a lot of askers systematically upvoting *all* answers: don't do that, unless they're good, and let the others vote. A lot of copycat answers are there just for the answerer to get reputation points, not to help you.

> How long should you try to make an answer work ?

Well if it doesn't work right away, maybe it's not as good as it looks. You can comment if you still find that it is a potentially good solution, and see if you get replies.