# Why was this seemingly off-topic question about how to get an app rejected from the Apple App Store reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A while back, I encountered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930829/how-to-guarantee-mac-app-store-rejection) where the user wanted to know how to make sure that their app would be rejected from an app store (because someone had apparently submitted it illegally and Apple was slow responding to the takedown notice). It was closed at one point, but it got re-opened. I voted to close it again, but my vote simply aged away.

My understanding from [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) is that developer-centric questions about app stores are off-topic. That being said, why was this reopened?

**Edit:** Even though this was closed again, it already received another re-open vote. I'm confused about why, since it seems to be clearly off-topic to me - am I missing something?

Comment: It's now closed again. The reason why it has been reopened can probably only be answered by the voters.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Because people do weird stuff - what do you expect? That has nothing to  do with whether we allow it or not, and the discussion of why is a pointless one when our policies actively disallow it. Reclose and move on

Comment: Given that the question again has a reopen vote on it, I suggest to leave this question open for now, maybe someone of the reopen voter drops by and states their reasoning.

Comment: I would assume all of the new reopen votes are because it's on meta more so due to any real reason.

Comment: This is an interesting example, because in some sense it can be answered in a way that most policy-related questions can't.  It's asking how to program an app in a certain manner, making it much more of a practical programming question than most others.  And in a certain sense, it can be answered by simply looking at the rules as written and breaking as many as possible.  However, it still invites speculation about how Apple reviews apps, which is a point against it.  All in all...I probably wouldn't vote to reopen it, but I might not vote to close, either.

Comment: Anyway, all of that is why I'm voting to reopen _this_ meta question, because the duplicate covers it poorly.  Also because it now has 2 reopen votes and a request to participate in this meta discussion before casting a third, which is easier if answers can be posted.

Comment: I wonder why non of the three reopen voters is willing to give their opinion on why the question is on-topic. I'm absolutely fine with leaving it open if there is a reasons for it, but I find it highly offensive to completely ignore a discussion.

Comment: @BDL Lack of consistency is the main issue. Why are we cleaning some off-topic questions when others can stand freely.

Comment: @RyanM How to break rules would require first listing all rules... I think list questions are also off-topic. And yes, speculation is the greatest pain point, as the rules may constantly change and just because one app was rejected because it violates some rules that does not mean that others will.

Comment: @BDL are you equally offended by the re-closing without a discussion? There is no requirement for people to justify their votes to meta

Comment: @MartinSmith: You mean the reopening of this meta question? I gave a comment above why I think it should stay open. Others agreed. Where is the lack of discussion here?

Comment: I typed reopening but meant reclosing (of the main question) - none of the three people that voted to reclose have participated in this discussion either, and nor do they have to. Participation in meta is completely optional. Not something to find "highly offensive" if people choose not to

Comment: I'd just like to quickly point out that this question was selected by the audit system early on in its history, and the "correct" action was to vote to leave open.  Some poor guy actually failed an audit by doing the right thing and voting to close.  I do understand the need for audits, but this is an example of where the audit system could use some adjustment.

Comment: Question is closed again, interestingly it has 16 upvotes and is only at -3 because it also has 19 downvotes.

Comment: Now the question is deleted, closing the question is a legitimate action, however the deletion is kinda harsh, IMO.

Comment: @BDL My last honest attempt at opening a discussion about what I perceived to be too harsh moderation just gave me flames and critique for even bringing it up. I won't do that again.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I disagree, the question seems to be doing harm to the site.

Comment: @Cristik why is deletion harsh but closure isn't? From the system POV, closure is just one step towards deletion.

Comment: @Braiam harsh at least for the responders that come with creative solutions. For their effort, I would've keep the question closed, but not deleted.

Comment: @Cristik well, they should know better than to answer off topic questions, right? They are victims of their own decisions.

Comment: @Braiam well... we could be pragmatic, or we could allow border-line questions like this just live. I don't think this question is harmful, we have bigger fishes to fry when it comes to deleting off-topic content.

Comment: @Cristik I don't buy the "fish to fry" argument. There are things that are already automatically deleted, these on the other hand would never be deleted by roomba. So, unless you want roomba to delete them, 10k users are free to use their delete votes however they want. [I've done my part trying to get more cruft deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333477/792066), they are doing so too.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica  Disagree with what?  All I stated were facts, 1) that it was closed again. 2) The number of upvotes and downvotes it had

Comment: And now the question is undeleted and reopened again. Perhaps time for a moderator to lock it one way or the other?

Comment: @Nick locks aren't needed. If a moderator deletes it, it can't be undeleted by anyone but a moderator.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, that works for deletion, but if a moderator decided the question *was* suitable for the site, preventing it being deleted again would require a lock.

Comment: @Nick I really like moderators not to do that. If anything they should delete more, not preserve. There's a big pile of crap on the site, if you randomly delete stuff it's more likely to delete crap than actual quality content. Locks are, in the SO model, the worst tool in the toolset.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not commenting on the quality of the question, just the methodology. Some questions should be preserved, and those need to be locked.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have re-closed and re-deleted [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930829/how-to-guarantee-mac-app-store-rejection). That question is asking for people to interpret the acceptance and/or rejection criteria which Apple uses for the Mac App Store. Yes, the question asks for what can be done programmatically, but underlying that was the request that answerers *interpret* the current requirements for acceptance/rejection by Apple for the Mac App Store. As such, it falls firmly under the type of questions which were explained as being off-topic/customer service questions in [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic)

If, on the other hand, the question author wants rejection and had already determined for themselves that doing programming task X would result in rejection, then they could ask how to do programming task X (as long as doing X was otherwise a reasonably scoped/on-topic/etc. question). Why they want to do programming task X wouldn't enter into if the question was on- or off-topic.

Answer (score -20):

> Why was this seemingly off-topic question about ... reopened?

For kicks I'll take your question literally and remove the referenced topic, because really, for the **"why"**, the actual question is irrelevant imho. (I never looked at the actual Q; I did not click your link or the meta link.)

The question was reopened because part of the community that is at least somewhat active in the review queue thought it was a question worth reopening. (Well, or the asker knew enough people to rig the reopening.)

When I engage with the review queue (seldom enough) and I see an interesting question, I will vote to reopen, regardless of someone's else interpretation of what is on- or off- topic on this site. I will vote purely on whether **I** find the reopening of the question worthwhile *within the scope of this site*, or maybe what I'd prefer to be within the scope of this site, no matter what anyone else thinks may or may not be consensus on Meta.

Comment: By the same logic, you could argue murder is perfectly fine because of what you consider a worthwhile pastime, no matter what anyone else thinks may or may not be ethical... SO has rules. You were granted the _privilege_ to access the review queues. Don't abuse it. TL;RD: _"I do whatever I want"_ is abuse.

Comment: @Cerbrus - :-D Wow. That was quite the comparison.

Comment: I think it illustrates the absurdity of _"no matter what anyone else thinks"_ pretty well.

Comment: @Cerbrus - ".. worthwhile ... to be within the scope of this site, no matter what anyone else thinks may or may not be consensus ..."  now that felt quite taken out of context. Anyway: We clearly have quite different ideas on how this all should work. Let's leave it at that?

Comment: If you disagree with how SO/SE _should_ work, you suggest a change on Meta. You don't just ignore the consensus / rules to do your own thing.