# Is downvoting questions more popular than upvoting?

Tags: discussion, voting

I have noticed that when looking at new and old questions on Stack Overflow, the majority of questions have been downvoted rather than upvoted.

For example, I watched the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675424/using-php-desktop-notifications-like-in-gmail receive lots of downvoted within a few minutes of being asked.

On the other hand, questions like [Multiple elements with same class - only insert after last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676035/multiple-elements-with-same-class-only-insert-after-last-one) and [Why do `(console.error = console.trace)();` make `heap out of memory` in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676001/why-console-error-console-trace-gives-heap-out-of-memory-in-node-js) are clearly explained yet have not received an upvote.

Is there a specific reason for this? Do people prefer downvoting than upvoting? Is there a limit on upvoting posts or something like that?

Comment: There’s another possibility you haven’t listed - more content in need of downvotes comes in (although I’m very sure upvotes outrank downvotes in the totality of votes.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I wonder if there is a way to find out (_upvotes outrand downvotes in the totality of votes_)

Comment: I’m sure there is through the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, but a quick search doesn’t turn up the query

Comment: @Pekka웃 here you go: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/543927

Comment: Well I feel like my point has been proven - this post has been downvoted x2

Comment: Why so surprised to see [Using php desktop notifications like in gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39675424/2564301) downvoted that fast? Did you really consider it worthy of an upvote?

Comment: @RadLexus That was the whole point of my post - questions which are bad quality are downvoted immediately where as questions which are worth an upvote aren't upvoted.

Comment: Downvoting is definitely more popular on Meta. =) No worries though - it won’t cost points and is a legitimate tool of discourse here

Comment: `questions which are bad quality are downvoted immediately where as questions which are worth an upvote aren't upvoted` yeah, that happens sometimes and is sad. It’s perhaps because we have a very clear (if complex) set of rules on what is a *bad* question; they’re so clear that it sometimes takes only a few seconds to process a question and make the decision. Deciding whether something is *great* takes more energy and focus.

Comment: Some people prefer downvoting, other upvoting and the preference could have changed with time. Using the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) you probably could find out more.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Do people prefer downvoting than upvoting? Is there a limit on upvoting posts or something like that?

More likely, people prefer posting questions worth downvoting (or at least not worth upvoting) to questions worth upvoting. Mostly because posting questions worth upvoting is hard work, and not many people want to invest that sort of effort. You could go so far as to say that there *is* a limit, just one that's imposed by the people asking the questions to begin with, not by the system or ourselves. We're limited by not getting enough questions to upvote to begin with.

I'd *love* to upvote questions, but I'm just horrendously starved of anything that I can upvote in good conscience. And it doesn't even take a long-winded question with dozens of lines of sophisticated code and more than a handful of links to call research — I just upvoted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675269/when-should-i-use-border-over-grid) about 20 minutes ago: it's supported by research and critical analysis of said research while still managing to be simple and straightforward (i.e. not broad — it's a single-use-case comparison of two very primitive XAML controls with very specific purposes) and only barely over a paragraph long. But it's the first question I've upvoted all week, after downvoting, closing and deleting dozens more that are incoherent or poorly written, haven't the faintest sliver of research or attempt to even make sense of the problem, etc. It's really disheartening.

Comment: I suppose you're right. Many users seem to want to get an answer as quick as possible that they do not bother putting the necessary details into the post to make it up-voting worthy.

Comment: @PaulCrovella So much that. I think I end up actually posting about half of the questions I type into the "ask" form. The other half I'll see a related question pop up while I'm typing or I'll realise the answer while explaining the problem.

Comment: It's harsh, but there are more implied down votes than even exist as actual downvotes.  If someone reads a question, and leaves without voting it up or down, it may be that the user saw that it has no added value above the existing questions, or no intrinsic value period, but didn't want to/didn't have the votes remaining to vote it down.   (I'm still working out how all knowledge gets in questions with intrinsic value I see the goal now at least.), That they didn't vote could be seen as an implicit vote of no confidence in the question, no?

Comment: Take this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287187/force-command-to-make-newline?noredirect=1#comment67833165_40287187  I can see that this is not a good question for the next person who was having troubles reading from a stream in shell.  But it's only at -1.  all the other users who viewed the question just walked away.

Answer (score 19):

Your analysis is lacking in facts, so let's try working with some:

There have been [78 million upvotes and only 9 million downvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/544088/upvote-and-downvote-count) on Stack Overflow so far. That's nearly 9 times the number of upvotes as downvotes.

That makes sense when you think that downvoting requires much more rep than upvoting so fewer people can downvote.

Ahh you counter, it was so much better in the old days, that's skewing all the results. OK, let's restrict ourselves to votes cast from the beginning of this year then...

That would be [12 million upvotes against 1.7 million downvotes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/544088), so still around an 8:1 ratio in favour of upvotes.

Maybe it's different for questions as Hans Passant suggests in a comment, [but actually it's not](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/544163). 25 million question upvotes and 2.6 million downvotes, still 9:1 or so.

So there we have it, downvoting is not more popular than upvoting, and no there's no limit on upvoting posts except the number of people who have at least 15 rep.

Comment: +1 Nice to see some numbers. This analysis however relies on SEDE which doesn't include deleted posts. The possibility of a post being deleted could be correlated to the sign of its score.

Comment: I would be interested to know the breakout of upvotes vs downvotes in the last 12 months.

Comment: Questions, not posts.

Comment: @HansPassant I've updated the answer to cover that. It's much the same ratio whether you consider questions or answers.

Comment: @JimHewitt didn't I pretty much do that already by considering 2016 on its own, it's September now so 9 months vs 12 months won't be significantly different.

Comment: @user000001 I don't think including downvotes for spam and egregiously off topic stuff is something we **should** consider when looking at whether posts are upvoted or downvoted, spam for instance is generally downvoted by the system as a side effect of flagging.

Comment: I agree with the first comment. The deleted questions probably attract the majority of downvotes. I guess going through the user profiles and counting number of up and downvotes could give a different ratio (although still with upvotes outnumbering downvotes).

Comment: "That makes sense when you think that downvoting requires much more rep than upvoting so fewer people can downvote." We could restrict the query to all with downvoting privileges to exclude this effect or even more general see if the up/downvote ratio correlates with rep?

Comment: @user000001 there's a http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609/792066 question that can let you infer some stats, basically the number of Auto-deletion: DeadQuestions which are post that get autodeleted by downvotes is 174,400, Auto-deletion: AbandonedClosed is just mere 143,287, compared with the million that other categories have, I doubt they would amount to much, maybe a .1 variation.

Answer (score -2):

This answer is more about what is worth upvoting than it is raw up vs down votes. Questions that should receive downvotes:

- Spam
- Badly asked questions without enough detail
- Questions that are not specific enough
- questions that are easy to answer with a google (the prove research bullet)
- more?

Questions that should receive upvotes should tick most of these boxes:

- Must be well asked with a good clarity and detail.
- Should be something that good research on the net can't answer.
- Is clarified when questions come in.

Factors that might sway voters:

- Is it interesting/something that people need to know?
- Should you just know it?
- It's just the wrong approach, bad programmer?

Perhaps questions with a twist are most likely to garner upvotes?  Upvotes vs quality would be interesting to look at, though impossible to summarize.

Comment: useful vs not useful

Comment: But useful is quite variable...   If you're an expert, a far fewer set of questions are useful.  Is the criteria supposed to be it's "Useful to someone with the problem described in the question who has exhausted their other options?"

Comment: Usefulness is subjective. Don't overthink it.

Comment: Yes, subjective, but in  a meta sense, doesn't that make it "unuseful" to users on the site?  Answer usefulness rating is a good thing.   Question usefulness score seems ambiguous...  0 score could mean a question is so vanilla to not be interesting, or it could mean that there were equal numbers saying useful vs unuseful.   The raw number of voters seems relevant with a subjective criteria...

Comment: And also, doesn't that mean that downvoting is under utilized, rather that over.  There are a lot of things that are useful only to the OP that come across the SO stream that are ignored and not downvoted.

Comment: It isn't meant to. Voting is for rating the quality and usefulness of the post *to you*. The last statistics I came across related to upvotes vs downvotes put upvotes way ahead.

Comment: You've been here for a while, you're saying that's the way it actually works?  You downvote every question that comes across the stream that deals with a technology you are uninterested in?  It seems like usefulness is not the whole story.

Comment: uninterested != not useful. again, you're overthinking it.

Comment: heck, mouseover the upvote and downvote buttons.

Comment: I think I see now, but I guess I can't guarantee I can codify it yet.  @KevinB, isn't an upvote a proxy for "This question has value for the ages, as the (only-ish) way the next person with this problem will  find a good answer?"