# Why aren't *all* users notified when a post is deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Just a few days ago, I was trying to figure out why I had lost 40 reputation points within *two hours*. It was two to three hours later, before I stumble upon [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history) post. It suggested that I should check a certain box below my reputation history on my profile to check for deleted post.

Sure enough, two post I had gained about 40 reputation from had been deleted in the same day. This easily could have been resolved had there been a notification when the questions were deleted. Possible one such as when you are pinged.

I'm really not to concerned about the reputation(other than the fact that I need it for certain privileges), but I would like to know why a user is not notified when a post they have rep tied to is deleted. This seems like it would be a very useful feature, and would save users the time of having to track down their rep loss. What is the design decision behind this?

Comment: I just logged into an account I hadn't used in years, to find a dozen notifications about things that had long since become irrelevant clogging the inbox. And that account had only *one answer* associated with it... I can only imagine how miserable this must get for occasional users with more than a trivial amount of participation. If you're here every day, it's easy enough to catch this stuff from your rep history.

Comment: @Shog9 sure I guess. But, as you can see via my profile, I visited the site every day, and I had know idea why I just keep randomly loosing rep until I discovered the post i mentioned in my question. If pinging the user is a bad idea, then maybe we should make this info more noticeable?

Comment: Here's a tip: you can also [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks. I'll take a look into the link you gave.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer here is that most folks can't *see* deleted posts; we'd have to limit notifications to question authors and folks with >= 10,000 reputation.

The long answer is that reminding folks when something is *gone* is a good way to get them upset about something they wouldn't have been overly concerned about otherwise. There is [a tremendous amount of stuff being deleted here all the time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why), and most of it needs to be deleted; rubbing that in the faces of the individual authors would just make that more difficult.

Comment: Funny how people have so different view points. If I was notified with a polite message saying that a post I had rep tied to was deleted, I might be a little annoyed, but I would be glad to know. I wouldn't consider it "rubbing it in"... That is, unless the message said - _"Ha, ha sucker! You lost some rep"_.

Comment: Some folks are considerably less mellow than yourself, I'm afraid.

Comment: Wow, that is a shame. When I found out how I lost my rep, I was at first frustrated with the OP.  But I then realized that I only had myself to blame. I should have known better than to answer a question that was likely to be deleted. I really try to take every rep lose as leading experience.

Comment: And you knew where to look to learn how to determine where your rep had gone too, @leaf. It's a good attitude. I wish we had more of it.