# I got a comment to a 5 year old question, the question is no longer relevant

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I had a 0 vote question about a framework that has evolved over the last 5 years. The author of the framework commented that the question is no longer applicable, since that version of the framework is very unlikely to be used any more:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608114/orchard-commands-transactions?noredirect=1#comment70699082_7608114

Also, it didn't have any answer or comment (other than the one I received today)

Should I close the question, or should I leave it as is?

Comment: If it were me I would delete it. There's no answer to save for posterity and if the problem has ceased to be a "live" one, I sure would not want to get the notifications from new answers and comments.

Comment: Just because there are newer versions of software available doesn't mean that there isn't some poor schmuck out there stuck with an old, outdated one…

Comment: @deceze And that poor schmuck is welcome to ask their question on SO when they run into a problem. Someone for whom the issue is "live" is more likely to be active in responding to answers and comments.

Comment: @Louis Between now and the day that poor schmuck needs a solution, someone who knows a solution may drop by and post it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth That can happen. Another thing that can happen is someone landing on the question *before* it gets an answer and placing a bounty on it. And the question gets downvotes  because "you're shooting yourself in the foot by using an obsolete version" or because the question is deficient in another manner. I've seen it happen. So the author of the question gets downvotes on a question that no longer asks something they need solved.

Comment: What is the issue with leaving the question out there if it isn't a bad question to begin with?

Comment: You could at least edit your post and state, that your question is addressing a specific older version and you want it to work with that.

Comment: @gnat I'm not sure this question is a duplicate of the the question ban one. I'm not asking about that, though the answers are similar.

Comment: @Jaap Don't worry about the dupe vote. Claiming completely unrelated questions are duplicates is sort of gnat's entire reason for coming to meta. You get used to it.

Comment: In this particular case, I'd leave the question. It's a little unfortunate that the answer (as bad as it was, consisting of just a link) was deleted, removing what little useful information there was. I'll reproduce the link in a comment if that's ok. If I had infinite time, I would reproduce the useful information from the linked thread in a new answer, but that seems like a waste of time given the obsolete nature of the question.

Comment: You are ultimately the one with the question. If you don't care about it, you have every right to claim no further involvement with it, and it is perfectly fine to express that disinterest by deleting your question.

Comment: @Louis I don't see why a *good* question would get downvote because "using an obsolete version". We are stuck to obsolete versions everywhere by many different reasons.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I would leave it alone.

- The fact that the original author has commented is useful for people
  coming to the question later.
- The question is valid as it stands, even if it has no answer yet. 
  An answer may come.

It is doing no harm, it is not giving incorrect information, and "*Obsolete*" is not a valid close reason.

Comment: _"The fact that the original author has commented is useful for people coming to the question later."_ Comments are ephemeral so the content should be ported into an edit, if it's useful.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit why not ported into an answer? if that's the only real outcome of the question, then why should it not be seen as the endpoint?

Comment: @JakeMillington: Because it is not an answer or an outcome. It is a potential constraint on the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Potential? If something is proven as obsolete (not to mention, by the author of the framework), then surely that is definitive.

Comment: @JakeMillington Because sometimes you're forced to work with old versions of products/libraries/other.  A question about "How to copy something to the clipboard on windows 3.1" would still be a valid question even though windows 3.1 is obsolete and we pity the poor guy who has to code for it.

Comment: @GabeSechan Right. So a different question would cover a different version. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @GabeSechan that's the most counterproductive and annoying way to solve stuff, imagine there's a new question for each version of software, [absolute madness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex4nM.png), compared to a single question with all possible answers.

Comment: @Braiam yes, because when I want to solve something for a specific version I want to see the answers for 9 newer versions which aren't supported. Yeah, that's not only pointless, but confusing and frustrating.

Comment: @GabeSechan why do you think that your problem is specific for that version? Why, if other versions are fixed, don't you upgrade, or ask for a backport of the fix?

Comment: @Braiam Really?  You think its always possible, much less desirable, to upgrade?  Try doing some real world programming sometime.

Comment: @Braiam: *most* questions and most answers apply across multiple software versions, so it would be ridiculous to split all questions as default, as you say.  But it’s perfectly reasonable for *some* questions (or answers) to be version-specific — how else would the poor schmuck who has to code for Windows 3.1 ever get their answer?

Comment: @GabeSechan oh, yeah. I program in the way I have less problems on the long run, which usually is the latest stable version, like 99.9999999% of all programmers.

Comment: @PLL but not for that you should craft a question that its only valid answers are for 1 version.

Comment: @Braiam Now here's reality-  you can't always do that.  Migrating OSes could take months and you don't have resources.  New versions of libraries won't have all the features you need.  Or maybe you altered the library to your purposes and convderting those changes takes months.  Its rarely the case that you can stay on the newest version of everything.  Its not even necessarily desirable-  new things are frequently buggy, its considered a good practice not to move to them for X months to wait for the bugs to shake out.  Have you never done maintenance work ever?

Comment: @GabeSechan do you have any data to back your claims? Apart of your own observations? Otherwise I will keep what is reality: developers offer in a big shinny blinking button the latest stable version they support.

Comment: @Braiam 16 years of experience, much of which is in corporate programming.   You need to get out of your own little bubble.  Heck the last embedded gig I had used a compiler written in 2000, because they didn't want to risk binary incompatibility with partners.  We used 4 versions of that compiler, each for a different partner.  And yes, we had compiler specific code in places.

Comment: @GabeSechan except that is "your" 16 years of experience. Guess what, SO exist for all the users, not just for the ones that have 16 years of experience.

Comment: @Braiam You're right, it does.  It also exists for people with it.  Which means sometimes the right thing is to ask questions for specific versions.

Comment: @GabeSechan no. The long run trump over the short run. If your question isn't useful in the long run it will be end closed as "this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers". So, future readers > today readers.

Comment: @Braiam You do realize that was removed as a close reason, and for a good reason, right?  No, version specific questions do exist, always will exist, and will always have a place here.

Comment: @Braiam 16 years of experience isn't relevant? That experience isn't personal work where any dependencies are only dependent on what you want to use, but "corporate" where many different parties are involved. In that case, it's not just one person's observations if a whole team is working on it. If someone wants to ask a question for an outdated yet more reliable system than those currently supported that they NEED to include, then so be it. People can still answer and give a relevant and reliable response. Odds are others will read it if it was core functionality that was broken.

Comment: @JakeMillington do you believe that DIlbert with 27 years of experience working under the same manager is a representative sample of the population? No, right. The same is with any single individual. Even if you find 100 people with an aggregated of 300 years of experience they are irrelevant from a statistic point of view.

Comment: @Braiam Yeah, sure it isnt. But I don't agree with that at all. The fact that there is more than one person opting for this type of development tells me that it has a place. Since asking my initial question I've related this to my current project (god only knows why I didn't do that in the first place) and there are multiple products used that if they were to be omitted or upgraded to versions that have reworked or omitted features, proprietary code would need to be created. More work. If you can streamline a process with an outdated piece of code, why not? No one has said it's 'deprecated'.

Answer (score 7):

Chenmunka is correct that there is no good reason to outright *delete* this content (and you need a good reason to delete content) out of some notion of "obsolescence" (someone may come along with an answer in the interim, and you can't tell whether that may happen in five years' time the next time an attempt is made at asking the question).

However, the real problem with this question is that it is hopelessly vague. In its current form, it is not a question acceptable on Stack Overflow. No wonder it did not get answered in over five years!

Let's pore over the relevant points:

> I'm trying to create a command that will run for some time. It harvests an external webservice and needs to insert or update ContentItems. It's using a service which is injected into the command.
>
> I also want a progress record in the database that I can show in the admin using a custom controller.

Pretty vague, but we can probably accept this if the actual problem statement is clear.

> I've run into several problems with the transaction each command lives in.

What problems?

> In this command I want to handle my own transactions instead of using the default paradigm: "each command runs in it's own transaction".

What transactions?

> I was unable to fix several issues I had.

What issues? Why were you unable to fix them?

> Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Bordering on a poll question here. And what is "this"? Your goals were too vague to provide a useful solution off the bat.

---

The question needn't be deleted, but it *should* be closed pending improvement — and this may lead to a roomba-deletion in its present condition.

Comment: Note: if it wasn't for the answer that was recently deleted, this question would have been deleted by the system automatically years ago, as it didn't reach the 1.5 views *years

Comment: @Braiam: Then let the system do so again if it deems doing so to be appropriate. We do not need to jump in here to destroy content. I do not understand why so many people lately get so giddy over going out of their way to destroy content.

Comment: "Destroy " what content? The question has little to no value, as it has no content.

Comment: @Braiam: Says you! And, as above, says me also, but for very different reasons, meriting a very different way of handling the question :)

Comment: No, says the metrics we have: in 5 years of existence, it hadn't gathered 200 views, one upvote (on either question or answer), [not even by anonymous users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers?PostId=7608114). It is very far fetched to say it has any value, since nobody has demonstrated interest on it. BTW, anyone can ask that question, if they have it.

Answer (score 5):

> the question is no longer relevant

If it's no longer relevant, you can just delete it. Someone else that have the same issue, will ask the question that is relevant to them, which would in turn make easier for the people that can answer it, since any inquire they can have can be solved.

BTW, I've deleted irrelevant questions, because the issue no longer affect me.

Comment: I'm surprised this is an unpopular opinion.

Comment: @BoltClock Why? It's so much easier and faster reading a valid answer that applies to you than writing your own question and waiting for answers.

Comment: @Nirri: [There isn't an existing answer yet, though.](https://xkcd.com/979)

Comment: Even the answer that the question is no longer applicable is of help.

Comment: In my opinion researching a problem and finding outdated posts with no answers is very irritating.

Comment: @Jinx88909 tell that to the the guy that propose to "leave it alone".

Comment: @Jinx88909 It's irritating, but not sure if it's worse than not finding any post about the problem. At least you know you are not alone.

Comment: @Oriol I share your sentiments, but I prefer them to ask the question a new... at least there would be someone interested in an answer.

Comment: The solution to the no answers / not enough answers problem is to post a bonus.  That won't help if the question is unanswerable because nobody knows the answer.  Nothing will help that!

Comment: On relevance: how do we tell if a Question is no longer relevant?  In general?  In this case, we can't ... because despite the maintainer stating that the library is obsolete ... there make be a "poor schmuck" who has to use it.

Comment: @StephenC then, they should ask their own questions... why they shouldn't?

Comment: I suppose from the look of things there are pros and cons to both sides and comes down to personal preference.

Comment: There's no such thing as "my question" and "your question".  The questions here all belong to Stack Overflow.  You MUST NOT delete a question just because it's stopped being relevant to you.  Whether you're the original poster or not, you don't speak for the whole Stack Overflow community.  Why should someone else have to re-post a question just because you deleted it?

Comment: @DavidWallace There's a thing called "interest", and people with no interest, tend to not care about stuff they have no interest about. You have no interest on seeing the question answered, nor do OP. Why are you spending so much energy for something you don't care about?

Comment: Are you an authority on what things I'm interested in?

Comment: @DavidWallace as a matter of fact, yes, since I don't see a bounty placed on the question looking for answers, do you? Put your mouth where your words are.

Comment: What concerns me is the existence of a rogue user who goes round deleting things from Stack Overflow when they cease to be relevant to him/her, without concern for the other 6 million or so members of the community.  Let me repeat myself.  You MUST NOT delete a question just because it's stopped being relevant to you.  There are other people here.

Comment: @DavidWallace [you know which users delete most on SO? The authors. You know who is the next one? Community. You know who follows? Moderators.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609/792066) So, if you want to accuse anyone of being a rouge user, point fingers anywhere else. Relevance is of extreme importance on a post-information society..

Comment: But the author of a question is not the best judge of its relevance to others.  The fact that YOU YOURSELF posted a question does not give you the right to delete it.  Check the licence.

Comment: @DavidWallace but it's the best one to judge relevance to himself. He's not going to invest resources on stuff he isn't interested into. Nor should anyone being expected to do so. On SO, we expect askers to be able to provide clarifications or more information on call. If OP has no interested on providing such information, we should allow others to take up to this task instead.

Comment: One thing I want to mention on this, there's questions I personally avoided asking about more mature technologies (.NET / Win32) because I thought they were "too weird / too localized / too unlikely to help future visitors", [plus I figured it out myself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/4975230) - result is, I didn't post about it. If I saw an unanswered question that happened to be something I avoided posting about, I'd answer it. A question without an answer is an invitation for an answer, the lack of a question I read as "nobody had this problem except you, so don't bother posting".

Comment: @BoltClock going by the votes breakup, is no longer unpopular, just controversial, which is actually surprising.

Comment: @David Wallace: The terms of use do not forbid an asker from soft-deleting (aka hiding) their question for any reason they choose, provided it meets certain criteria (no upvoted answers, etc). So your repeated uses of "MUST NOT" don't exactly apply here; you probably meant "SHOULD NOT" (based on the definitions from RFC 2119). They do, however, permit the community to reinstate an abandoned question that's been deemed valuable. The system, and moderators, have safeguards against the rogue users that you allude to, so you don't have to worry too much about that.

Comment: @jrh that's your prerogative. I bet that if you haven't found your answer, you would have asked it anyways, if it was important to you.

Comment: @Braiam That hasn't been how it's worked so far for me personally. In order of things I'd try: 1. Look at .NET ref source, 2. Look at Mono source, 3. Look at OS software that does something similar, 4. Buy a book, 5. Try a third party alternative, 6. Look at disassembly, 7. Read low level hardware manuals, 8. Think about it for a while, 9. Ask on SO. -- I only got to step 9 once and probably only because very few books really cover IL (a relatively new-ish Microsoft technology) well. Also I didn't really do a ton of C# at the time, and the answers tend to be on C# blogs...

Comment: @jrh man, you are one in a million, you know. At least you aren't [that shameless like most askers are](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/792066) ;)

Comment: @Braiam yep, I linked that in my comment. I take that post seriously -- unfortunately it seems like there's not a lot for me to do here other than correct people's typos. That's been discussed to death already though. Oh well, chat and CR is fun at least.