# I'm very uncertain why my questions on SO were deemed low quality and my account was banned

Tags: support, post-ban

I've read the help page which comes up, I've reviewed the information on the [meta page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) about this issue, and I've reviewed my questions from the past.

I understand many of them received no up-votes, and there was one question with one down-vote (which the person who gave it didn't care explaining why), but I would certainly hesitate from calling them any of the following:

1. Extremely poor quality
2. Irrelevant to the site
3. Too specific (except for one case I can see) or demonstrating no proper research on my part

In general, I've asked questions on this SE site mostly when I've had trouble picking up new concepts, especially when I was new to programming.

However, I've still tried to keep them as general as possible so future participants of the site can benefit from them.

Now, to be fair, I have noticed I haven't accepted answers for a number of the questions I asked.

However, most of my questions here had been asked when I was new to SE and didn't fully realize the importance of marking answers. I would be glad to accept them now, but I don't see how not doing so makes my questions of low quality.

I would be grateful if someone could help me understand what I'm missing. Maybe I *am* at fault here and simply don't realize it. I just want to say that low quality questions are something I myself would not accept submitting to an SE site.

---

### === EDIT ===

I would like to thank everyone who's looked into this for me and helped with my prior questions and answers. I'm very grateful.

Some have asked about any possibly deleted questions or other information. Reviewing the criteria publicly disclosed on how exactly this ban is determined, I thought again about my past questions and felt it might be useful to mention the following incident.

Recently, I had asked about good learning sources I could make use of online for the technologies that go into hybrid mobile development frameworks such as ionic.

I had listed some restrictions, one of which among them was that I don't want to spend an inordinate amount of time learning before I could get a relatively simple app up and going. While this question wasn't as well received as I had originally hoped (and in hindsight I can see why), this was an unusual case.

I received an unexpected number of down-votes (maybe 3 or 4) and then immediately after I received a notice explaining something about a malicious account being involved and that account being under review.

The account, apparently, was ultimately deleted (or suspended), my post was deleted (if I remember correctly) and all the negative reputation change I had incurred was reversed. Which is what made this unusual.

To the best of my knowledge, **this was the only time** one of my questions had been deleted from SO.

If this has contributed in a significant way to the (now lifted) ban, it is unexpected for one bad question (and moreover in the given context) to affect an account.

If a moderator can verify this for me, I would be grateful.

Thank you all again. It's really nice to see the community come together to help someone.

Comment: This does seem ridiculously harsh, given that only one of your 12 questions has *not* received an answer, and 9 of them have received 2 or more answers. I did a quick skim, and the overall quality seems well above what could be fairly considered as "low quality".

Comment: Without going through your visible questions or trying to be offending, a few key words in *this* question have alarms ringing in my head. Keep in mind, this site is meant to be a Q & A site for "experienced" developers about fixing "specific" coding issues. Phrases like "... when I've had trouble picking up new concepts..." and "...tried to keep then as general as possible..." sound to me like they go against the general idea of MVCE. That said, it does seem harsh by what you've said here.

Comment: 12 questions with only one of them having downvotes is not enough to trigger a question ban. Some of the worst ones must have been deleted.

Comment: @dfd From the ["tour" page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (**emphasis** mine): "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and **enthusiast** programmers."  Nowhere does it state a requirement for "experienced" (and how do you even quantify that, it's subjective).  I'd argue that OP posting here only reinforces that they are definitely an enthusiast.  Long story short, I think your assessment is way off base.

Comment: I misspoke. I consider "professional" to mean "experienced. I'll stick to my intent though - questions that conform to MVCE, which "as general as possible" isn't, are more accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were banned when you were. I don't see anything obvious in your account that would have been likely to trigger a ban. Please note, however: you are no longer banned from asking questions on the main site as of right now.

Comment: one can't expect a newbie to programming to ask questions with vote >0

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava my very first question got +1 the first day. I had read a python/xchat plugin tutorial just hours before asking it. "Newbie to programming" can ask upvote worthy questions. What most people lack is the ability to write good questions, being a newbie or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to review my query. I'm grateful :)

Comment: @Braiam I'd have to disagree, but ok

Comment: And now we have to wonder how someone disagree with a fact.

Comment: @braiam IMO the truth is yet again in the middle. Novices with a good mentality, like you clearly had, have all the chance to succeed in asking a good question. Newbies with the newbie mentality to go along with it ("I'm a newbie, rather than making effort I demand that you do everything for me") have zero chance of success.

Comment: @Gimby and why should we go to the level to accommodate such mentality, someone might ask? We have no reason to do so, and we shouldn't do so.

Comment: If you have old questions with acceptable answers, but no accepted one, then you ought to be able to go back even now and accept answers for them.  This would be the right thing to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did follow up with my previous questions. I accepted answers for almost all of them, leaving out one with no answer, one with an answer which I don't remember if I can accept now (although it seems unlikely), and  finally [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746191/accessing-arrays-in-c) with many good  answers from which I would feel guilty picking one answer. I've had this trouble before, and they're all close enough chronologically for there to not be a clear choice. Sigh, if only I could mark them all as answers...

Comment: I have to agree with @GiorgiMoniava. Sadly the algorithm doesn't understand false positives in the form of downvotes.

See [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162897/lxml-requests-on-repl-it) and justify the dv if you can. This, repeated over 4-5 questions gave me a permaban, before even being aware that this was a possbile outcome of being a newb.

Comment: @dfd Only debugging questions require an MCVE (not MVCE). Other questions may be too broad, unclear, or otherwise off-topic without code, but non-debugging style questions don't explicitly require code. Let alone the fact that the phrase _"tried to keep then as general as possible"_ to me implies that the author intended to make the question apply to as general of an audience as possible, which implies any code would be an MCVE, and is definitely in line with the intent of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This site is about solving programming problems, and that includes a lot more than just simple debugging of issues with some code the OP wrote (which is generally useless for future viewers).

Comment: Thank you for your integrity ... people like you make this a better place. People like dfd have the opposite effect. Everything about his comment is wrongheaded, and twice misspelling MCVE, on top of not even understanding how and when it applies, should get him (and the 9 thugs who upvoted his comment) banned if one were to subscribe to his outlook.

Comment: @Braiam No idea how what you're saying is a fact. I mean a "newbie in programming" might not understand what the community needs to actually answer the **programming** question, which results in a "bad question" because not enough information has been provided. These are rare cases though. No way that your statement is a fact.

Comment: @Loko fact: "Newbie to programming" can ask upvote worthy questions. Braiam == newbie to programming. Fact: First question while being newbie was upvoted. Untrue: one can't expect a newbie to programming to ask questions with vote >0. Proved by previous facts.

Comment: @Braiam "one can't expect" refers to the expectation, NOT to the possibility. So you cannot say that it is true or untrue, it's relative. You also said "What most people lack is the ability to write good questions, being a newbie or not is irrelevant.". This clearly being not a fact, have you considered that what people were not agreeing with was this non-fact statement? No one contested that you got +1 on your first day, you can chill.

Comment: @timeFly one can expect "newbies to programming" to ask questions worthy of an upvote. What one can't expect actually is people to ask questions worthy of an upvote. Read my first comment please. I feel that I'm failing into a circular argument here.

Comment: @EdCottrell It seems I'm back to square one as when I got back today I saw I had lost 60 rep points because of "voting corrected."

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId Take a look at [your reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1184361/thisisnotanid?tab=reputation). You got many votes clustered together on March 19. That is, they were very close together in time. We investigated and saw that somebody was upvoting nearly all of your posts. It may have been somebody trying to "help out" with your question ban. But, regardless of why they did it, that kind of targeted voting skews the numbers on the site and makes the site less useful for everyone. So, the votes were invalidated.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId Please read this, if you haven't already: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Answer (score 11):

Of your [12 visible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184361/thisisnotanid?tab=questions&sort=votes), four (or a third) have a score above 0, and the average score *overall* is 0.3.  While this is purely anecdotal - the actual algorithm is not shared - I would ***imagine*** that your question quality was just enough on the edge.

In reality, we have an incomplete picture; **it could be the case that you've deleted negatively scored answers which still contribute to the question ban** (the negative score, not the deletion (as was in this case)).  However, I wouldn't focus on that; focus on improving the quality of your questions.  Questions which ask [which approach is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488608/type-comparisons-in-python) lend themselves to more downvotes and close votes in general.

> ... [M]ost of my questions here had been asked when I was new to SE and didn't fully realize the importance of marking answers. I would be glad to accept them now, but I don't see how not doing so makes my questions of low quality.

Accepting answers really doesn't factor into anything.  All it means is that this answer worked for you.  It doesn't, to my knowledge, symbolize or represent anything else.

Comment: As far as I can remember, I haven't asked for any answer deletions on SO (though I have on one or maybe two other SE sites). Casting good and productive questions is a goal I agree with. Asking about alternative approaches being discouraged is certainly something I hadn't come across before (it was also not mentioned by anyone when I asked that question). It would help me see where I need to improve my questions if anyone at that time had told me that my questions weren't up to mark or even just down-voted them. I'm still unsure why a ban is appropriate in my case.

Comment: Agreed.  I think some of the moderators on this site are sometimes a little bit too haughty.   https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.jbpgjxeik

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with that article. My perception may be biased, though, since I mostly frequent niche tags.

Comment: To everyone commenting on the zero-score questions:  I did mention that this was **anecdotal**.  Well-received questions are usually questions that are scored higher than zero, but the nuances of the algorithm are not explained to anyone that doesn't work for Stack Overflow.  What I'm merely suggesting is that OP's questions aren't all that well received, and should be edited to improve their clarity.  I've even provided one question which *sorely* needs to be edited.

Comment: @T-Heron You know that question bans are almost always done by an algorithm with no human intervention, right? Maybe slow down in the rush to judgement there.

Comment: @T-Heron This was an automatic ban; no moderators were involved. That said, I'm not sure what exactly triggered it.

Comment: @jrh if your questions are so "meh", you are wasting the readers time. Questions shouldn't be consistently "meh", it's boring.

Comment: @T-Heron: I think I've seen that article before. I'd already dismissed it as silly because of its repeated insistence of all the "hate" on this site, but then it started to make comparisons with Hitler. Off-the-scale daft, I am afraid.

Comment: (FWIW I'm all in favour of some other organisation attempting to improve upon Stack Exchange's model of democratic oversight and quality, and AFAIK nothing touches it. I use Reddit, but it does not come close - it is generally a mess for coding questions, and there are no mechanisms to preserve the best material for posterity).

Comment: @halfer You don't have to dismiss it as overly dramatic (it is, but there are better reasons). You try to search for all the "examples" (which btw, seems to be cherry picked from random points of time) and none were in the same state the post describes... in some cases years before the post.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not really into keeping "meh" questions around, but if SO encourages extreme research effort doesn't that mean that if people are using the site properly that there might only be one or two users who will really even think of searching for the question? [Also I'm kind of having deja vu here Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341949/i-got-a-comment-to-a-5-year-old-question-the-question-is-no-longer-relevant/341960#comment436380_341960).

Comment: *Accepting answers really doesn't factor into anything* I wouldn't be so sure about that. A big(ish?) part of the ban algorithm is how much of other people's time have you wasted.  Not accepting an answer on your question could be considered wasting other people's time.  I don't know if they actually do use this in the calculation, but it wouldn't surprise me at all.

Comment: @T-Heron and others. While the quality of posts has declined over the years, I think a lot of it has to do with just who should be considered qualified enough to post. Maybe the SE devs need strike a delicate balance for SO, but it's worth noting that bad questions are not *nearly* as much a problem on SE sites which demand you demonstrate your worthiness simply by virtue of the fact that you're posting there. Examples Include Physics, Mathematics, Electrical Engineering, Signal Processing, Software Engineering, Theoretical CS, Security to name a few.

Comment: And as these sites show us, maybe the moderators won't need to be so strict if simply the users posting would already be qualified through some direct or indirect means. I mean, I'm all for inclusiveness, but programming, at least it seems to me, is a field where it's too easy to start out and just be in the position to be able to come to a site like SO and basically say do this for me or I have no clue what I'm asking about. Of course, I'm not actually making a statement here about how the mods mod SO. That's not my place to say.

Comment: Just as another example, I want to include a question I asked on Physics.SE years ago and it was rightfully closed, even though it was an "interesting questions" as one of the mods put it. This is an example of a question being closed for all the right reasons (which the OP should've been careful about), and an example from my own past that I can be proud of: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/49853/what-is-a-good-way-to-reason-in-physics

Comment: I think all of us who care enough to post on META like this thread should keep these viewpoints in mind when reading new questions.  On StackOverflow, I down-vote, but only when the question clearly has not been researched AT ALL.  I mean, if you don't even Google, that shows and it's really obvious.  That gets my down-vote.  But as far as your questions, I went back and read over some of them, glanced at nearly all of them, and I liked them.  I gave you at least 4 up-votes.  The quality of your questions I thought, met Stack standards.  I do however, have a lot to learn myself.

Comment: Agreed. And thanks for the up-votes! They helped get my account back online!

Comment: Looks like someone else did the same, you showed you cared, and I really did like the questions I up-voted.  By talking this out with the community, you've learned a lot more, and so did I.

Comment: And the votes will be invalidated the next time the script run... REMEMBER VOTE FOR THE POST, NOT FOR THE ONE THAT POST IT!

Comment: @EdCottrell: I do see it; there are 4 deleted questions, 3 with a negative score.

Comment: @Braiam - I stated, and I quote:  "I really did like the questions I up-voted".  I voted for the post, *not* the person.  Please read comments carefully before responding.

Comment: @T-Heron: no, you didn't. You never would have found those posts organically. You started *from the person*, and voted for all but 1 of their questions (plus an answer).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I started from *this* post, *not* the person.  And voted according to this criteria - “This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear” which is SO criteria, not mine.   You are using the fact that I voted for all but one of his questions (plus an answer) against me.  Where in the rules does it say this sequence of events is wrong?  Feel free to challenge me because I have thoughts of becoming a moderator myself some day.  We probably need to dissect the merits of each of his questions to fully understand why and why not each question is *not worthy* of an up-vote

Comment: @T-Heron: I'll give you this post by Shog9, which covers this case exactly: [How can we bring multiple low-quality posts from a single user up for review without prejudice?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335442), with an added bonus of the post linked from there: [Can there be legitimate serial downvoting?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260843)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - acknowledged.  Thank you.  Let me review.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The information about the deleted questions dramatically changes the situation, can you add that as an answer that officially states that the cause of the problem was **negatively scored deleted posts** and NOT zero vote posts?

Comment: @jrh: there is no official answer, even moderators don't know how the quality post ban algorithm works.