# Were these duplicates deleted correctly, or would keeping them around add value?

Tags: support

> **Edit:** it looks like these deletions were justified, and more intensely peer-reviewed than it seemed - see the comments.

In an [unrelated Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343309/my-rating-is-significally-jumping-down-during-last-days-whom-i-should-ask-for-t) two questions came to light that had recently been deleted by several users:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054478/calling-string-intern-before-first-literal-occurence
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052932/sort-list-of-objects-based-on-objects-variable-frequency-in-descending-order

Those may be duplicates, but they are *very* decently worded. They certainly add value for future Googlers. The reason for keeping duplicate questions around is that the more different ways you have to describe the same problem, the better - as long as they point to a  good original question.

Has this changed recently, is this some new policy I've missed?

Comment: `Since when are we deleting useful-looking duplicates?` What makes you think those duplicates are useful?

Comment: @Servy the fact that they are *very* well worded, and hence increase the likelihood that someone will come across them one day and be pointed to the correct original question? I'm not familiar with the tag, so I can't really judge anything else.

Comment: Them being poorly worded would make them surely not useful, them being well worded doesn't mean they *are* useful.  In the case of a duplicate like this, are these posts going to be attracting people searching for this question that wouldn't otherwise be able to find the answer, either because they're linked from other sources, use radically different terminology, have better google-foo, etc.  I don't see anything here to indicate that these questions are going to get lots of traffic from people who couldn't find the canonicals.

Comment: @Servy the reason for keeping duplicate questions around is that the more different ways you have to describe the same problem, the better. Surely those two pass that test.

Comment: I can see that these questions have been deleted by three users, none of which has a gold badge in Java... EDIT: actually, at least one of them does, but it seems that he didn't delete the question single-handedly anyway.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't see anything in these questions to indicate that they're more accessible, or that they use notably different terminology, than other versions of these questions, or anything else to indicate that they're likely to attract lots of views that wouldn't otherwise find their way to the canonical.  What makes you think they do?  It's not that "all duplicates are better" rather, "duplicates that actually successfully direct people to the canonical are useful."

Comment: @ForceBru Several of them have gold badges in the tag.

Comment: @Servy so is that the rule - that three users get to make the decision, and perform a deletion that (as far as I know) is not peer-reviewed in any way? Not sure I'm comfortable with that, although I agree we have a huge problem with clogging search results with dupes like this... hmm.

Comment: I believe the idea with these questions is that there are already hundreds of duplicates, and the ones being deleted aren't any more easily googleable than the others.

Comment: @Servy, yeah, I've noticed this now, but still, if one of them deleted the question single-handedly, there would've been an icon of his gold Java badge, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure those went through SOCVR, we are digging up the requests.

Comment: @Pekka웃 How is it not peer reviewed?  You're a peer, and you're reviewing it right now.  It's also not just any 3 users, but users with considerable experience in the site that the site has determined can be trusted with such decisions.  It's actually rather hard to get questions deleted manually because there are so many bad questions and so few people, comparatively, with the privilege to delete them.

Comment: @ForceBru neither were deleted singlehandedly

Comment: That misunderstanding may have been my fault - I claimed the questions were deleted by "a user" where I should have said "a user among others". Fixed.

Comment: @ForceBru None of them could have deleted the questions single-handledly. That's not a power that gold badge holders have.

Comment: @ForceBru Having a gold badge is not considered by question deletion.  You need to be a mod (or the post author) to unilaterally delete a question.

Comment: @Servy `You're a peer, and you're reviewing it.` oh come on now. My coming across those URLs was complete coincidence. (Unless there's a "recently deleted" queue I'm not aware of.)

Comment: @Pekka there is a recently deleted queue in the 10k tools

Comment: @TinyGiant ah, cool. Wasn't aware of that. Well, maybe all is well then after all.

Comment: Also, we're fairly certain at this point (confirmation will come once our search bot is out of a meeting) that the posts were deleted after the deletion was requested in the SOCVR where the requests would have been reviewed by multiple users.

Comment: Fair enough. ---

Comment: Okay, that none of these users was able to delete them single-handedly shows that there were enough people to close the question first and then three more people have come to finally delete it. So, some six or five different people thought it would be right to remove the questions, and this is not a so fast process, which means they were probably deleted for good reason.

Comment: I'm upvoting this not because I believe that the duplicates were deleted incorrectly, but because this is a good question.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Peer review doesn't work like that. Everyone with experience in a field doesn't review something novel in that field; a few people are picked by a publication (or, say, a site, in this case) based on domain knowledge and those three people have the say in whether it gets published. In the same way, 3 users (or 4, when you consider both questions) who've been on the site for a long time and have been quite successful with it (all of them are multiple gold badge holders, and all of them have 30k+ rep), including two with a java gold badge, saw the question & decided it was worth deleting

Comment: @Pekka웃 If you are wanting a tag-filterable delete vote queue, where anyone with knowledge in a tag over a certain rep threshold can review delete votes on questions, that's a different discussion.

Comment: @TylerH no, that's not what I was talking about. I wasn't aware of the existence of the "recently deleted" queue - with that in place, all is well. (I remain dubious about *any* type of user being allowed to delete stuff, though - I've seen it abused too often. But that's a different discussion, too.)

Comment: "I've seen it abused too often", really? That's one of the most underused moderation power on the entire site! Only [~1.5% of all deletions are via votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609/792066), and is way behind self deletion and roomba by factor of 6-15. And it was lower the previous year (0.39%).

Comment: @Braiam: You're messing around with the statistics. It contains answers, but you didn't add up the 3rd-party deletions of answers. It contains reasons like auto-deletions, self-deletions and migrations, which are not relevant for "abuse". Your number is highly misleading and I recommend everyone to read it themselves, if is interested.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer Braiam did? "Question, 3rd-party vote, 1.47 %". It doesn't make sense to add up "Answer, Parent question deleted (3rd-party vote)", it is already contained in that -- it would be adding questions and answers which are unrelated. Even if you do and count things in double (or triple since you can have multiple answers being deleted because the question got deleted), you still have ~95% of the deleting _not_ done by 3 users voting to delete...

Comment: @Tunaki: Yes, that wouldn't make sense, I was talking about "Answer,    3rd-party vote". Besides that I mentioned other reasons that the number is misleading. It's difficult to agree on what should be counted in and what shouldn't, therefore I recommend to follow the link. I'm not providing my interpretation of the numbers as that would cause another discussion.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer Pekka complains that that users "being allowed to delete stuff" abuse of such ability too often, I took it in the context of being question deletion, which is why I used just that number. Deletion of answers ain't counted because it requires higher privileges (20k) and it requires a very specific circumstance (score <= -1). This limits the ability greatly and there is a very legitimate reason to use that privilege (NAA) by 20kers (which the queue also shares some load). My number isn't misleading, it was selected for very specific reasons.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We have an effort going on in the SOCVR chat room to clean up the site. Most of us there concentrate on close voting and others flagging. I've mostly concentrated on [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), voting to close off-topic and duplicate posts.

On top of that, some of us, who have the appropriate privilege, have taken it a step further. [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) has degenerated into a lot of garbage (maybe like other tags). Everything has been asked before. Everything is a duplicate. Most of my close votes each day are for duplicates.

Every day, I also submit a list of previously closed posts to these users in SOCVR and we review whether they deserve deletion. In this case and many others, we thought they did.

The first post is a combination of reference equality (in general and with String) and the behavior of `intern`, both of which have been asked thousands of times (the former maybe being the most asked question on SO, can we get some stats on number of dupes of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) ?)

The second post is a duplicate in the *sorting* category. The canonical shows you how to write a `Comparator` or `Comparable` and how to use it. Their question of *how to do it* comes with no evidence of effort. Adding a different post for each sorting technique seems counterproductive to me. *Maybe* I was wrong on that one, but it doesn't strike me as a useful post to keep on this site.

Vote as you think is appropriate. That's what I did.

I'll definitely hear you out for voting to undelete/reopen. We're always pingable in the chat room. I want to see quality in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and I don't think those are.

Comment: Just a note for the second post and my rationale. "How to sort a list of object with regard to a property" has been asked and answered [so many times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2784514?lq=1) (that's just the non-deleted and closed one), we really do not need another one.

Comment: Regarding these things I can tell only one statement: there are TONS of really similar questions on Stackoverflow. But they aren't deleted, they just closed as duplicate. I still have a feeling that deleting THESE particular questions is some kind of very strange prejudiced reason towards person, who received positive score on answering them. My apologies if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Andremoniy No, it's more that there are a lot of posts that should be deleted, and aren't. Why do you think there is a prejudice against a person?

Comment: Good work Sotirios, thanks for caring about quality on SO, carry on!

Comment: @Andremoniy if you see that many of the questions that you're answering are being closed as duplicates, maybe you should spend more time evaluating if questions are duplicates before answering them.

Comment: @JAL, as I wrote in other thread, I'm one of the activists who mercilessly downvoting and voting to close silly, duplicating or unclear question. I'm really trying to answer on only interesting questions or questions which have some kind of different angle of the problem than existent questions

Comment: @Andremoniy Keep it up!

Comment: Just to add on, I usually will avoid deleting questions with content that are _useful_ to future readers, and those that are excellent duplicate signposts. The two questions are quite specific to the users, especially the second which goes like this: "Now I would like this, what is the most efficient way to do it?". These are weak questions that largely serves the OP only, and are just part of heaps of similar questions that could be cleaned up. I highly appreciate Sotirios' initiative in hunting these down, and sometimes feel that his efforts are under-recognized.

Comment: "the former maybe being the most asked question on SO" No, the most asked question is [fixing NullPointerExceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). [Comparing strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) is still one of the most asked Qs though.

Answer (score 10):

I take umbrage with [this question's closure and deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054478/calling-string-intern-before-first-literal-occurence), specifically because:

- It's not asking the same question as was linked in the duplicate.  The duplicate asks for differences of the `intern()` method between Java versions, whereas this is asking for clarification about the use of `intern()` in general.
- The answer provided doesn't take or read similar to any of the solutions in the proposed duplicate.

Had a duplicate come along that answered the question of `intern()`'s general use, I wouldn't be so bothered.  But, since that duplicate doesn't, I genuinely feel like a mistake was made in its review.

Comment: Interesting that the answerer voted to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  I find that interesting too, but I also find it to be an incorrect dupe closure.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't have enough domain knowledge to comment on whether or not that duplicate closure was correct or not.

Comment: I think it's an established fact that questions with the same answer are duplicates. In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054478/calling-string-intern-before-first-literal-occurence), OP asks why `a` and `b` concatenated at runtime and interned is the same object as the one returned by the literal `ab`. The answer in the post I linked as dupe, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12278369/438154), explains exactly why that happens, but uses `te` and `st` instead of `a` and `b`. Assylias' answer does the same but goes through some hoops to do so.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Doesn't a question that has the same answer but is worded differently help others who are searching for the same thing but can't figure out the best wording for a question?

Comment: @Juan It would. But both topics required to answer this question have been asked so many times before that the answer space is completely diluted. SO doesn't gain anything from keeping this post around.

Answer (score 5):

Both of these questions were mentioned in a [review list](https://gist.github.com/sotodel/0a2d92faa6c08192efed94fd4044a9cc) maintained by [@SotiriosDelimanolis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis). This list is [shared regularly](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=0a2d92faa6c08192efed94fd4044a9cc&room=41570) in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), and is reviewed regularly by room members there.

- Question with id #42052932 was mentioned in [this revision](https://gist.github.com/sotodel/0a2d92faa6c08192efed94fd4044a9cc/18737a503d1f9c7cd088f2fdc38f4fc771635bb4)
- Question with id #42054478 was mentioned in [this revision](https://gist.github.com/sotodel/0a2d92faa6c08192efed94fd4044a9cc/6303b28f5564c040727076c2c7bd06225b944894)

Both questions were reviewed and deleted by members of the SOCVR. If this review process were to fail for any reason (we trust our members but recognize that people make mistakes), there is a [recently deleted posts review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days) in the 10k+ tools where users can review *all* recent deletions.

The SOCVR is always open to anyone, including those who may disagree with—or have questions about—any action taken by any member of the room. When actions are called out on meta, it is expected that the members involved will account for their actions on meta.

Comment: The recently deleted posts review queue in the 10k+ tools means users *can* review all recent deletions. but does this happen in practice? Who's got the time to do that?

Comment: @MartinSmith whoever cares?

Comment: @MartinSmith so it's my fault that you don't care?

Comment: Lol - No I don't care enough to spend my free time monitoring a delete queue to see if stuff is erroneously deleted. Maybe such people exist but relying on the existence of these people seems tenuous at best.

Comment: @Martin so if you don't care then what's the problem? I'm not relying on anyone to do anything. If you have an issue with something that someone is doing, it is up to you to do something about it. I—as well as many others in the room—review as much of this stuff as we can both before and after it is deleted. We also engage in undeleting and reopening questions as requests come up.