# Move good answers from deleted duplicate-questions to original topic

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Why not automatically move good answers of deleted duplicated-questions automatically to original question with keeping their score?

I still insist that if answer wasn't just copy-pasted from original thread, it can be worth for other people as it considers problem with slightly different point of view.

Comment: Can you provide some concrete answers of this *not* happening?  I mean, if the question was a dupe, then the chances are *very* high that any answers would be mostly repeating the same information in the dupe, too.

Comment: @Makoto look please at this questions where two examples mentioned. May be I'm stupid, but I don't see that for instance my answers on these questions where very similar to existent answers on "original" questions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343312/were-these-duplicates-deleted-correctly-or-would-keeping-them-around-add-value

Comment: The question regarding sorting by frequency does seem like it's well-covered by the duplicate; effectively, any custom sorting is done by implementing one's own comparator and the rest is simply business requirements.  The question regarding string interning is likely *not* a duplicate from what I can tell, though.  It's asking a *slightly* different question.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* done when the answers are considered to be of high enough value for it to be worth it.  If a question closed as a duplicate has high quality answers, answers that would be valuable to add to the canonical, then the questions can be merged.

If the answers on the duplicate are not considered valuable additions to the canonical question, and the duplicate as a whole is not considered a useful signpost, then the whole question, with its answers, is deleted.

Comment: What is criteria? Only subjective reasons or some numbers like: more than 10 score or more than 20 score?

Comment: @Andremoniy The criteria are as I've said in my answer.  The score is certainly something that those taking the relevant actions should be considering, of course, but not all posts with a particular set score are necessarily worth keeping, nor are answers below any set score okay to delete.

Answer (score -3):

> Why not automatically move good answers of deleted duplicated-questions automatically to original question with keeping their score?

Because score is a bad indicator of usefulness. Of course, you can use it as a proxy for it, but ultimately usefulness is identified by the people that can understand the answer and can assert that it is indeed useful. I've seen more times an answer having incredible score just because the problem is popular or common, and many more answers with score 1-3 that I consider very thoughtful. So, relying on only the score for such things isn't very attractive solution.

And even then, there's another condition of it being novel. There's no point of moving (the operation is called merging) an answer to another question that has the exact same thing or very similar. We regularly delete redundant answers from questions where there's a better version of the same answer, as this prevent wasting effort fixing the same thing in several places (DRY principle and similar).

Comment: Score *by itself* - and that part is important - is indeed a bad indicator.  However, without subject matter experts in a position to merge answers around, score is pretty much all that can be relied upon.

Comment: @Makoto which is why I said "you can use it as a proxy for it". But if you are 10ker and are voting to delete a question, I presume you are able to understand the answers and flag the question so it can be merged. My answer is mostly disagreeing with the use of score to merge answers in an automatic fashion.