# Reputable people keep answering duplicates - What's the solution?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers, se-quality-project

### It's apparent that reputable members (ranging between 10k - 600k reputation) are answering duplicates.

It's understandable if the question being answered isn't a blatant duplicate, but that's not the case for this discussion.

**I've included posts to justify this discussion. Do NOT single these users out, as they are only a few of MANY who answer blatant duplicates.** These references only exist to prove the point.

<sub>*I'm surprised that a discussion about this hasn't already been started. Maybe it's not an issue? If not, why discourage answering duplicates? Something isn't adding up.*</sub>

---

Here are a few posts to express my concern:

#### Answered by someone with 60k+ rep

- [Java 8: replace anonymous class with lambda expression [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320745/2398375) - Answered on Sept. 20, 2017
- [Declaration difference between ArrayList and collection [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46148373/2398375) - Answered on Sept. 11, 2017
- [Is it necessary to add a constructor all the time in child class [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46169075/2398375) - Answered on Sept. 12, 2017

#### Answered by someone with 600k+ rep

- [using Javascript how can I parse a gatecoin api json return [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46326961/2398375) - Answered on Sept. 20, 2017
- [My :checked styles are not applying when I click a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286266/1685157) - Answered on Sept. 18, 2017

<sup>The next 2 answers are for the same question, focus the same concept, yet the user doesn't edit their existing answer, rather post a completely new answer as a follow-up.</sup>

- Retry promise himself after fail in node js[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46117831/2398375)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46158184/2398375)

#### Answered by someone with 500k+ rep

- [A nesting If statement does not work [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389245/a-nesting-if-statement-does-not-work/46389282#46389282) - Answered by someone with 500k rep on Sept. 24, 2017
- [What is the difference between { get; set; } and { get; private set; }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389031/what-is-the-difference-between-get-set-and-get-private-set/46389056#46389056)
- [sizeof operator returning different output. why? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139967/sizeof-operator-returning-different-output-why/46140049#46140049)

---

If you'd like me to upload more examples, there's plenty - simply let me know.

The point is, reputable users are purposefully answering duplicate questions in hopes of gaining more reputation.

I can't imagine how many duplicates exist without actually being marked duplicate (unjustifiably by people with enough rep to know better).

---

### What's a solution?

These actions result in information being segregated across many posts. Some of the duplicates aren't actually marked duplicate, making it harder to obtain existing information on the subject, resulting in duplicate answers.

These users are highly knowledgeable, yet they seem prioritize reputation over site quality.

<sub>Recently, I saw a 300k+ rep user answer a question that was a blatant duplicate. After googling for a duplicate, the first result was actually answered by the guy who answered the "regurgitated" question - the answers were near identical. I'd link it, but due to my reputation, I cannot view deleted answers, as the regurgitated answer was deleted shortly after I commented (will edit it into this post once I reach the rep requirement to view it).</sub>

---

I don't have many suggestions for solutions myself. This seems to be a pretty deep issue, which would require some major changes.

All I can think of is:

- Lower the rep gained for duplicate questions (similar to how users lose rep when someone deletes their account)
- Give knowledgeable users a medium to express their understanding on a subject (which seems to be supported via the Documentation beta, but apparently doesn't seem to be helping)
- Give "this may be a duplicate" warning to those answering questions, in a similar way users are warned about posting duplicate questions

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions

Comment: also cross site related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions/

Comment: There is a bit more to it than just rep-hounding.  What all of these users have in common is that they can no longer cast a normal dup vote.  They are gold badgers, their vote is binding and the question is instantly closed.  Being the only user to close a question is *not* a great privilege.  You get to hear, loudly, about the OP's problems implementing the solution and it is all your fault.  I don't do it anymore either, life is entirely too short to have to put up with that kind of crap.  Faking the dup vote comment is a workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant off topic but did I remove my contact info like twitter and email from my profile for similar reasons..

Comment: I did consider letting SO users bully me.  But then I thought that I ought to be the jerk.

Comment: Call My a cynic but, I genuinely think SO (the company) doesn't care anymore. The days of wanting to build a resource that improves the internet are gone. What they want now, is people participating, clicking on ads and looking for jobs. People who ask stupid duplicate questions are just as valuable a user as those that close duplicates and generally clean up the site. This kind of problem has been an issue for years and years, I've seen loads of people suggest solutions. Not one has ever been implemented that I'm aware of. The status quo continues.

Comment: Closing as duplicates is one of the most difficult features on this site if you ask me. In most cases, it's about abstracting a question and closing it as a dup to a generic question versus tailoring an answer specific to that question. I honestly don't know what the best thing to do either in these cases, and that's probably why I'm filtering out duplicates from the close vote review queue. It also doesn't help that gold tag badge holders can't vote for duplicates that might be borderline, since their vote will actually close those questions immediately.

Comment: I don't really see why you can choose what type of duplicate vote you use, and gold badges could have the option to dupe hammer or just add standard close vote. I'd suggest this change is less work than creating a whole new documentation section and then binning the whole lot off after a couple of months

Comment: @HansPassant [insert Spiderman quote here] That said, has your experience been raised anywhere on Meta for discussion? That sounds like something that should probably at least be brought to everyone's attention.

Comment: I must say I've noticed recently an increase in multiple answers to dups, including from people who should know better. Haven't a clue how to fix it, and penalising it would be more hassle than it's worth, I think.

Comment: @Liam Don't forget to add "push political agendas" to the list.

Comment: I think we can all theorize about why this happens and what we can do about it, but I think it'd be really helpful if repeat offenders have their say here about why they do it. The C# and Regex tags have a couple of 100K+ rep people as well who don't dupe-vote but consistently answer instead.

Comment: The solution is to make duplicates more accessible, and provide better incentives for posting new answers to years-old questions with extremely outdated but highly upvoted and accepted answers. No one wants to point to an outdated answer just because the question was first asked in the late 00s. And the ones who *do* refer to old duplicates don't read past the pinned, accepted, outdated answer, and thereafter automatically assume their question hasn't been answered to their satisfaction. So linking to duplicates doesn't even *work* as it should.

Comment: Reputable people got that many points by answering many questions instead of closing them.

Comment: @HansPassant Just ignore the messages; haters gonna hate. The cost of simply ignoring a message is far outweighed than the site being flooded with duplicates and commenters and answerers wasting their time putting effort into a duplicate question. The privelege was given so that competent users can more effectively control the quality of the content.

Comment: @BoltClock How would that solve anything? The problem is rep-wh.. who just want to get their 25 points, they don't care about anything else. When they see a chance to get them they go for it even if they know it's a dup. Helping other people find dupes and making the originals better is good but won't help with the problem raised by OP.

Comment: @Oleg: It would certainly help *me*, I have so much rep to my name I couldn't care less about earning any more, but I can't count the number of times I've answered duplicate questions just because I can't find a suitable duplicate because search has been terrible for years in a row.

Comment: @DBed - Well, that's good advice, and used.  Perhaps it could be extended to "just ignore it when a user doesn't want to dup-vote a lazy question".  Tolerance works best when applied both ways.  Anybody that expects frequent contributors to be the sole guardians of the site are apt to be disappointed now and then.  Keeping it entertaining and useful is everybody's job and one that does start with whomever is first to create new content.  That they tend to suck at it, and are never held responsible, is the way this tends to go down-hill.

Comment: @HansPassant: You're well inside my top 5 of folk I respect most on this site: and I'm sure I'm not alone in this opinion. Yes, there are some odd folk out there.

Comment: @Liam wow, you're cynical. Almost as cynical as [the guy who wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351792/839601) that "Project {Re,De}duplication" turned out to be "The thing that Stack Exchange was most interested in was how to recognise when two posts are falsely labeled as duplicates"

Comment: I didn't make that up, @gnat; my answer links to the original source. I won't dispute the charge of being a cynic, though.

Comment: yes @JoshCaswell I checked your links and discovered that your answer is correct. How cynical of you was to expose this to me and break my dreams of SE management trying to improve handling of blatant duplicates flooding the site

Comment: I think I misunderstood the emphasis of your first comment, @gnat, sorry.

Comment: Maybe the Mjolnir managers should be given more options, and more power. If they just want to add a vote for closing in the 'normal' way, it should be an option.  If the question is NPE or i++ + ++i, they should have the power to just close the question with one click without putting in the effort of finding the duplicate - the OP can then put in the effort to go looking for it, (what they should have done in the first place), when they see their question closed as 'Mega-dupe'.  If a Thor misuses that power, it could be withdrawn.

Comment: ..and scanf() reading the \n left in the buffer, and linked-lists with all the node strings the same as the last entered..  'Mega-dupe - refer to [language]  MDQ list'.

Comment: What I've also noticed is that if it was a low reputation user in those places answering duplicate, they would have been berated and most likely down-voted to oblivion.

Comment: Down-voting doesn't work either, majority of the low rep users who answer duplicates and deterred by down-votes but for the higher rep users, they basically have nothing to lose as it doesn't really affect them.

Comment: @Script47 yes.  Once the duplicate answer is posted, the battle, (whatever exactly it is), is over.  The rep-cucumber does not care about the occasional downvote since, on average, they make more on upvotes and accepts.  The OP does not care s/he has copypasted out their unique homework answer as soon as it appeared, and will never use that 'member for today' account again, so any down/close/delete voting is irrelevant.  The only measures lkely to be effective are those that discourage the posting of the duplicate answers in the first place.

Comment: A possible solution is to have a grace period (5 minutes?) where if a duplicate is found within that period of time all voting is reversed so the duplicate answeres gain nothing, other than a bad press.

Comment: @Script47 tht would be better than deletion - leaves some signpost there for those who might be about to post the same question, but removes the votes.  Not sure if there's enough demand for SO to implement it, though:(  Maybe it's already been suggested in some past meta?

Comment: @MartinJames: "*Once the duplicate answer is posted, the battle, (whatever exactly it is), is over.*" The way I see it, once the duplicate *question* is posted, the battle is over. The most effective way to stop this is to stop duplicate questions before they're posted.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'll grant you that one, but that is a battle I don't think we can win as long as 'Open new account, clickclickclick copypasta question, Ask' exists.

Comment: Points taken. But I then have one thing for you to do differently in the future: when making the content of **other** people the subject of a discussion on META ... it would be very much appreciate to at least notify these people. Or do you like it when people start talking about you without telling you about. Putting up examples is fine with me. Not notifying about doing it ... that is **rude** in my eyes.

Comment: @GhostCat right you are. Things take a turn to the dark side when we start condemning good people for doing a basic site function such as answering questions. I get the sentiment behind all this, but we must not forget that the source problems are not that questions get answered - it is that duplicate questions get asked so easily and that dupe linking is a chore which does not really have a good sales pitch behind it that will convince everyone. It is quite understandable that people choose not to do it. And I don't see why we can't respect people's choices regarding that.

Comment: @Gimby Something tells me that there won't be much upvotes for that comment of yours. Beyond that: given the fact that this question *here* has been flagged as duplicate - should it be deleted? ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat There's nothing rude about this, and I tried posting it in a way to emphasize that: "*Do NOT single these users out, as they are only a few of MANY*" - "*These users are **highly knowledgeable***" It's a topic for discussion, and seeing how you deleted two of the examples already, you don't feel it was justified? I wasn't attempting to down anyone here. I wasnt expecting this post to gain this much attention so quickly. I was simply looking for potential causes and solutions for a problem I've seen growing on SO.

Comment: @VinceEmigh For the record: I deleted *zero* of these answers. They got deleted because you put them up here, people turned to the questions and *deleted* the questions. Which is fine. But when I came in this morning and basically noticed that I had like -200 rep. And *when* you had put up just a small hint about this META question I would have known what is going on. So I was like sitting there for quite some time wondering what kind of strange serial question-deleting was going on.

Comment: You see, when I come across something worth turning into a META question - then I *tell* the affected people about it. Because it is very likely that within a few hours, many down/close/delete/whatever votes will be following. That has nothing to do with "singleing" out users. But linked content will be viewed, and reactions will follow.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm sorry, this really isn't something I normally do, and I will definitely inform any users I include in a future post. Like I said, I didn't think this would gain that much attention, and probably would have thought of informing if given the time (went to bed shortly after). Won't happen again, I'm sorry.

Comment: Why is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326930/using-javascript-how-can-i-parse-a-gatecoin-api-json-return/46326961#46326961) (delivered by OP's post) not categorized as a comment? It's a comment or not?

Comment: @Script47 You should be careful with such statements such as "if a low rep person gives a DUP'ed answer they would be downvoted". At least on the Java tag, answer downvotes almost exclusively happen for **bad** content, especially in numbers. There are occasional 1, 2 downvotes when answering obvious DUPs - but I have seen more than once that low-rep folks answered a DUP with "OK content" ... and got 1,3,5 upvotes for that. So: do not generalize *your experiences* to a global level. When I put up *bad* content, I collect downvotes, my reputation doesn't matter a bit there.

Comment: @GhostCat I was merely mentioning my experiences of what I've seen. Hence I never generalised and I said *What I've noticed[...]* and not *What always happens is[...]*.

Comment: @Script47 One can read your statement such as "if in those places that were listed in the original question low-reps would have answered". That is a prediction. That is applied to a set of questions that exist on very different tags. And as said: at least for the Java tag I do not see that. Answer votes there mainly reflect "direct quality" of content.

Comment: @HansPassant keep closing the questions, and don't link your profile to your email. Ignore the frustrated bozos. I've closed a lot of questions (less than you of course) and I'm proud of that. Never got an insult about that. But I try to be nice when closing: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352439/should-we-add-more-explanation-when-closing-as-duplicate

Comment: "The point is, reputable users are purposefully answering duplicate questions in hopes of gaining more reputation" - bizzare unfounded conjecture, you don't know the motivation of anyone answering.

Comment: The search function is shockingly bad. Often I have a *better chance finding an SO dup via google* than I do via SO search function.

Comment: The obvious answer is to stop rewarding us for it. (And I'm sure my use of the word "us" will result in someone trawling through my answer history)

Comment: People answer because the system is broken, and they feel it is better to have correct answers in the right place, to combat the flurry of poor answers that will come from people who don't participate in these meta discussions.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265165/rewarding-overzealous-users-for-answering-duplicate-questions-is-undermining-the

Comment: Many of your links are 404.

Answer (score 49):

I made a suggestion that **kind of covers off your third point**:

> Give "this may be a duplicate" warning to those answering questions, in a similar way users are warned about posting duplicate questions

**The feature request:**

[Could: "Possible duplicate of.." be given prominence for answering users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352450/could-possible-duplicate-of-be-given-prominence-for-answering-users)

**Scenario:**

- User 1 asks question
- User 2 votes to close as duplicate
- User 3 clicks to answer and is presented with dupe preview
- User 3 has to choose to close or continue to answer

Dupe preview would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: But this won't work if no one has proposed the duplicate yet.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that's why I said: _"I made a suggestion that **kind of covers** off your third point:"_

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ given that this question is about answering **"blantant duplicates"** (bold font is as used by asker) I think cases when no one proposed the dupe don't qualify in this context (on a more general note I personally see no reason to worry much about not very obvious duplicates and about answers to these)

Comment: In fact, this is probably the most practical solution IMO. If there's no dup proposed yet, then all potential answerers can't be asked to *search* for duplicates. But if someone has already proposed a dup, then an answerer can't ignore it and simply say "I didn't know it's a dup". This makes them responsible for answering a potential dup.

Comment: I thought of that too. Some users ignore the comments when they're trying to answer the fastest possible. So a warning like this would make _me_ think, for sure.

Answer (score 34):

I have a suggestion, which I am always attempting to voice since it never gets done.

***[Include the chosen tags in the search criteria for “Questions that may already have your answer.”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280668/include-the-chosen-tags-in-the-search-criteria-for-questions-that-may-already-h)***

Seriously, this will improve a lot of duplicate question asking.

Many OP's have no clue they are asking duplicate questions, or that one existed. Most of them were just trying to look for terminology, or thought they had a unique situation since the question asking interface showed no issue. They are for the most part not familiar with the site. Even users who are willing to read the instructions, and click extra boxes, still fall into these pitfalls.

Without at least making a good first effort to show them the duplicate post *in the ask question interface*, it is nearly impossible to expect them to not post their question.

Also, I know there is some work being done on this interface, or at least that is what I usually hear in response to gripes about the ask question interface, but it is been 6-8 years since it was changed. It is far overdue.

Comment: This is a very good idea, but is only tangentially related to the OP, which is not _"why are there so many duplicate questions?_ but rather _"why do high rep users answer clearly duplicate questions, instead of closing as duplicate?"_.

Comment: Well, obviously no one's ever seen that suggestion, because you hid it over there on "that other Meta" :-)

Comment: Your suggestion is great, but I still think that lots of users would ignore it. True, it depends of how you are formulating the question. I had a case where I couldn't find a solution to my problem. Searched google/stackoverflow but got half and (in my view) bad answers. So I wrote a new question. Then I thought of a correct title. Guess what, one of the suggestions led to a solution that is **exactly** what I was looking for (different approach + very elegant solution). I certainly would see it added yes.

Comment: I disagree that users would ignore it, and your explanation that a suggested question solved your problem definitely highlights the need for this here.

Answer (score 26):

In my view, the reason why it happens is efficiency, pure and simple.  Desire for points isn't the issue.  It's simply a desire to get the question 'dealt with' (answered soundly) quickly, to save people wasting time on writing the answer.  It is often far quicker and easier to write a new answer from scratch than to spend the time wading through a few hundred thousand questions seeking the right duplicate.

If the Stack Overflow team are worried about it, they will put effort into making it easy to find duplicates.  They'll provide some interface that allows a user to build up a list of duplicate candidates and make selections from that list.  There might be entries created by the 'general population' but there should also (or instead) be the opportunity for personal lists of duplicates.

Maybe if a suitably privileged user (gold badge, 20k, …?) starts using the duplicate search interface for a question, a temporary lock is placed on the question (with explanation reported to other users, including those already typing an answer) preventing the addition of answers. There should be a timeout (10 minutes?) after which the lock is relinquished.

There needn't be any specific award for identifying the duplicate using the interface.  Less privileged users might get an award (a couple of points perhaps) if they identify the question as a duplicate in a comment and the question is closed as a duplicate of the question they suggest.  Only the first to enter the comment with URL, or to vote to close as duplicate, would get the bonus.  I've quite often been grateful to another person for identifying a good duplicate so that I can wield Mjölnir effectively.

I've previously mentioned something similar to this in an answer to [Would SO benefit from an AI mechanism that helped moderators identify duplicated or related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343580/15168)

Comment: Yea Varily and Amen.

Comment: _"It is often far quicker and easier to write a new answer from scratch than to spend the time wading through a few hundred thousand questions seeking the right duplicate."_ You may need to upgrade your google-fu. The obvious dupes are usually the first search result when searching for the post title.

Comment: @Cerbrus: glad to know that works for you.  It doesn't always work for me.

Comment: I'm guessing searchability also depends on the question's language. For JS, at least, finding dupes isn't really a problem, as long as one doesn't use SO's search.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you can also close with an approx. duplicate, find a better one, and edit the list, remove the old one, and put the new one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355666/what-should-i-do-as-a-gold-badge-holder-if-i-feel-the-duplicate-target-isnt-the

Comment: The only reasons I ever post a dupe *and I have* is #1 because after searching for 10-20 minutes I couldn't find a dupe meaning S.O. search for utterly failed (and maybe google's). So I post only later to be told it's a dupe by someone that has intimate knowledge of the available answers. The less common reason is because the answers I do find don't actually address my actual question but overzealous closers close the question without actually understanding it.

Comment: Even as an answerer, when someone asks a question I know is a dupe I often find it impossible to find the dupe and so after 10-20 minutes I trying I give up and re-answer the question.

Answer (score 21):

I received this comment earlier from someone - not answering a blatant dupe, but answering a blatantly off-topic question:

> @Makoto Because I wanted to share my insight and I don't agree with every SO rule out there.

This resonates with a point I've been making about this situation for a while, and it holds true to all types of questions, even duplicates:

## Not everyone agrees.

Even worse...

## Sometimes the mob gets it wrong.

Let's dissect the first point and see if we can find a solution.

---

The issue that I've noticed when answering and closing suspected duplicates is agreement.  Even *I* disagree with some dupes sometimes.  Nowadays I look closely at the question and try to see if it *really* is a dupe, or if the answerer will *really* get the guidance they're looking for from that other question.  I've noticed others closing dupes simply key off of a few critical words (null pointer, scanner, etc) and not be *as* critical of the dupe closure.

The way I've interpreted duplicate closure was rudimentary:

- Closing the question as a dupe meant that the answer was elsewhere.
- Closing the question as a dupe meant that the answers present in the other question can solve their problem, even if the questions were asked under *slightly* different pretenses.
- Closing the question as a dupe didn't necessarily imply any quality checks on the question being closed itself.
- Closing the question *never* implied any judgment on the OP themselves.

...however, I think that there's a lot being lost in translation here.

For starters, people get *offended* if their question is closed as a duplicate, as if it's a knock to them for not doing all of the research they could've.  In reality, it could be that they didn't know how to massage Google, or they didn't know what key phrases to use in order to get the answer they were looking for.  I get and realize that simply "search for it" is a common rallying cry when it comes to looking for dupes, but...

- Stack Overflow's search is woefully underequipped to handle this.  You fare better on Google.
- Not *everyone* that's trying to figure out why their code written with `Thread`s isn't responsive after a few times knows what "deadlock" (or "livelock") means, or the user who writes a loop that never completes may not know what "infinite loop" is.

We want users to find this information for themselves so we don't have to, or to make it easier and [worth our while](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280568/1079354) to do it for them.

**Even then**, it's not going to be simple.  There are enough questions on the site that curating and finding *the* best authoritative answers to a specific problem is likely possible but time-consuming, unrewarding, and can be wholly undermined by a handful of suddenly popular questions.  Worse, you're not going to get everyone to get along with the duplicate closure, and you're not going to get everyone to think that questions *should* be closed at ***all*** (as in the case above).

---

On to the second point:  we're all human and we make human mistakes when evaluating questions.  [Here are some queries to audit the use of the dupehammer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315155/how-can-we-downvote-the-use-of-the-mighty-mj%C3%B6lnir), and we can derive how often it is we actually take the time to reopen a question that's been previously closed as a dupe.

No, we're not all going to like our mistakes and we wish there was a simple algorithm we could follow to close all questions as dupes of a certain type.  But no such algorithm exists; the best we can do is a heuristic [which still has a chance of failing us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343334/1079354).

---

So...what can we do?  It's largely cultural with a *little* bit of tech mixed in.

- **Answering duplicates shouldn't be regarded as a massive sin.**  It happens; we find it simpler to answer than to search for a duplicate, or some of us are just plain apathetic to the ways of the system.  Instead of fighting them (hint:  you're not going to win because they outnumber you 100:1), realize that mistakes happen and people are people with their own opinions.
- **Fix search.  *Seriously.***  We should be able to identify a duplicate with a few key words from search, and the system should be able to inform (and actively prevent) askers from asking a question if the system can actually reliably find a duplicate for them.  This is the pipe dream; once we get to this point we'll finally realize our goal of less duplicate questions.  However, at a minimum we should have search be at least *on par* of that with Google's search.

I mean c'mon, it's bad when you see an obvious NPE question and the dupe suggestions *mention nothing about NPEs*...

Comment: Note that I didn't mention anything about users looking to close *everything* as a dupe.  Some of 'em wander around Meta doing that.  Irony hit me when *this* question was closed as a dupe.  They're a factor but we outnumber *them*.

Comment: RE _"Answering duplicates shouldn't be regarded as a massive sin"_: Apathy isn't a mistake. Apathy isn't excuse for yet another answer to yet another duplicate. You're saying we should just shrug off users who can't be bothered to close obvious dupes as such. Those users ___are___ the problem. Users need to be more selective in what they answer. More often than not, dumping the question title in google will get you a adequate dupe target.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  It's **not** apathy.  It's an acknowledgment and reminder that this isn't going to be some overnight policy change that everyone magically jumps behind and supports.  You *will* have people that disagree with this and will skirt your policies because, like I said earlier, they outnumber you 100:1.  It's easier to educate them and win them over than treating them like they're entirely evil and entirely wrong at what they do.

Comment: So, did I misunderstand _"or some of us are just plain apathetic to the ways of the system."_?

Comment: @Cerbrus:  I wanted to clarify my stance on it.  I'm not being apathetic here.  I largely agree with the sentiment that is being expressed.  It's simply that there are *others* which won't bend or budge, and will only bend or budge under the right kind of motivation.  Treating those users like they're horrible people isn't the right mentality to get into.  Sorry if I confused you there.

Comment: Okay, to clarify my stance: I don't have a problem with treating people that are "apathetic to the ways of the system", like they're horrible. This site has rules. If one doesn't follow those rules, one is a horrible person. (Note: grain of salt)

Comment: @Cerbrus:  Remember how I said that the mob can get it wrong sometimes?  *This* question was closed as a duplicate not all that long ago.  Does that make everyone who answered it *before* a horrible person? ...

Comment: One closure does not imply a community consensus that the question should be closed. But yes, obviously, they're horrible people.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  It took a while longer than I thought, but thank you for concisely demonstrating my point...

Comment: I don't think your point was in conflict with mine, though... _*shrug*_

Comment: This is a good answer, @Makoto. Sadly not upvoted nearly as far as it ought to be.

Answer (score 8):

**Allow answering any question with a link to another answer in some different question.** Grant more rep for this kind of answer than a regular answer if voted up (e.g. 15 points instead of 10). Render this kind of responses nearly identical to copy-pasting the original response to this question. It's important that the link points to an answer, not to the duplicate question!

This would give karmawhores an incentive to point to correct answer of duplicate question instead of writing/copy-pasting a new answer in place. In addition, it would give more automated metadata about duplicate *answers* and maybe avoid the need for closing the question (I see no harm about duplicate questions that have a single link-only answer and automatic info about related question. Future search queries have a better change to find either this duplicate question or the original version. In addition, such link-only answer would be automatically updated in case the original answer gets improved.)

I'm not sure if the author of such duplicate question should deserve a punishment in case the link-only answer gets upvoted. That author should definitely not be punished for up voting that answer himself to avoid any deterrant to vote correctly linked answer.

Maybe give an extra bonus (perhaps even 20 points per upvote) if such link-only answers have been provided by low rep users (e.g. <500). This might give new users an incentive to try to look for existing solutions while collecting rep. Hopefully this would allow them to get better at looking for duplicates before asking new questions.

(Looking for duplicates is sometimes hard. I personally was not able to find *this* question and tried to ask very similar question here in meta.)

Comment: This kind of style would also allow linking to *multiple* different related questions. I believe that the current style of marking as a duplicate of a single another question is too limiting. Sometimes the question is not an exact duplicate but multiple *answers* from different questions are still valid as-is. Allowing link-only answers for these cases would allow entering all those as answers for a single semi-new question.

Comment: Duplicate questions can link to up to five questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster Only a select few can edit the list of duplicates (moderators and gold badge holders, IIRC).

Answer (score -2):

Luckily I've escaped a specific mention in your citations!

My personal threshold for "exact duplicate" is quite high - for me the *question* has to be pretty much identical to another question. I've only recently started to close the i++ + ++i type questions as duplicates; but perhaps that's more to do with my becoming jaded by the sheer number of those types of questions being asked on the C and C++ tags.

I also believe there is an element of "showing off" in being able to deliver an answer quickly. It's also easier to answer than spend the time searching for duplicates. Coupled with the fact that you can earn points with an answer, answering becomes too tempting.

Personally I think reputation ought to be awarded to someone who initially spots a duplicate that is concurred by other members of the community and eventually closed as such. But deciding upon the amount of reputation awarded, and other issues such as what should be the award to a gold hammer close (where concurrence is not required) do not make this straightforward. Would reputation also be recalculated retrospectively?

Comment: RE: _"showing off"_: This is why I'm so motivated to "beat them", by finding a proper dupe target faster than someone can say _"`=` is an assignment, you need to use `==`"_

Comment: @Cerbrus I can understand ' I've only recently started to close the i++ + ++i type questions as duplicates'.  It's much easier to type 'UB' as a comment and downvote than go searching for the canonical dupe, and who wants to apply more than the absolute minimum of effort on such questions, given thier 'coypasta from homework and don't bother checking first' nature.  Spending more time on handling a bad question than the OP did in posting it is just disheartening:(

Comment: @MartinJames: What if I told you you can save time spent for _multiple_ users, by closing the question? ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh, I get that, which is why I often close-vote such questions with the catch-all 'too broad'.  It's not the best fit, but it's the quickest.

Comment: @MartinJames: But if a question is a duplicate, close-voting it as too broad is a little counter-productive.

Comment: @Cerbrus: My current records are [closing a question in 13 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970404/html5-vs-c-net) and [answering in 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/why-do-browsers-think-this-div-tag-isnt-immediately-ended/5455770#5455770).

Comment: I agree with "It's also easier to answer" and "reputation ought to be awarded to someone who initially spots a duplicate".

Answer (score -6):

I'd suggest taking [@Tanner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/57475/tanner)'s [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357026/2912665) one step ahead:

Hand out a -2 rep penalty (this number is debatable) to the answerer if they answer even after seeing the warning and if the question ultimately gets closed for being a dupe for which the warning was given. The penalty will be fair since they would have been presented with the dupe before they wrote their answer, thus making them accountable for answering a dupe.

Answer (score -8):

Being the person who wasn't singled out by putting up the first three links to questions which I answered to - let's give a different perspective:

- First of all, mea culpa: I shouldn't have answered those. But back then I was really hunting "legendary" - and well, sometimes gamification wins over "qualifi-cation". I will try to do better from now on.
- Nonetheless: you probably noticed that in each of those cases, my answer achieved more than 5 upvotes. So it seems: the people *actually* looking into the java tag, and looking at the combined input ... found the answer *worth* upvoting.

So, seriously: when you want to *stop* reputation hunters from answering "DUPS" - then the only way that will work is to *reduce* the potential benefit from answering such questions.

And beyond that: the *really* only thing that would prevent DUP questions and DUP answers would be if the **technical infrastructure** would prevent users from asking for duplicated content. And as outlined by others: this fact is known for years, and it seems that the people **owning** the infrastructure don't care. Any new question means clicks, and clicks turn into money. Duplicated questions do not. So, in that sense, all of this is somehow fighting windmills.

Finally: what is the outcome of this? A few questions out of zillions of DUPs with answers got deleted. And, me personally, I was frustrated for a day or two - which *also* means that anything between 20 and 50 close/delete votes for postings on the java tag came in those two days. Because that is what I do between answering - looking at stuff and voting all the time. But of course, we shouldn't talk about the net outcome of such discussions. Because it doesn't matter what happens in the real world ...

Comment: _"found the answer worth upvoting."_ -> Because they _recognize_ an correct answer to a familiar duplicate. The only reason it's getting upvoted is because _so many_ people know the answer is correct, there's bound to be a few that don't care about the fact it's an answer to a obvious duplicate. The only way to remove the benefit is by cancelling rep gained from answers on dupes.

Comment: I doubt that it is that simple. 5 or more upvotes is not something you receive that easily - at least on the java tag.

Comment: [Here's a recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463314/arrow-function-and-this-in-my-code). 7 upvotes within a couple of minutes of it being posted.

Comment: @Cerbrus And for an JavaScript outsider, this simply looks like a well written answer nicely explaining stuff and giving even "ready to run" snippets. This still resembles *quality input*.

Comment: So, we should just forget the fact that's it's a duplicate that's asked on a daily basis? Just because it's a well written answer?

Comment: See the updates I made to my answer. We can discuss this topic all day long, it will not at all influence the number of duplicate questions that get put up here. We are talking about the best way to fight a symptom. Because in the end, we all know that the **root cause** can't be fixed by us.

Comment: I've made a somewhat related feature request to [remove the grace period for answering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357183/dupe-hammer-remove-grace-period-for-posting-an-answer), after a question is closed as duplicate.

Comment: And I disagree with that. I have seen more than once that an answer that I typed in on my mobile phone (giving me the grace period) was a **much** better fit than the duplicated answer. My efforts would have been lost for nothing without the grace period. There are some users that put up close votes very quickly - and sometimes they just get it wrong. Combine that with a gold badge for the associated tag ... not so good either. Besides: searching for duplicates using the mobile is even more terrible than doing that in front of a desktop. But: I do see the potential benefit from your idea.

Comment: Yea, mobile devices... I'm of the opinion that those can only really be used to view SO :P

Comment: I thought so, too. I was surprised myself to see how useful they can be occasionally. They even work for *some* of the review queues.

Comment: Fun fact: I wrote this, and 90% of my content, from mobile. "*Searching for duplicates is terrible*" - This plays a huge role, besides the reputation. Writing a title gives duplicate suggestions for any language. In most cases, the suggestions are irrelevant, forcing users to Google for dupes. I'm not sure why users aren't forced to specify tags before the title, as tags are a requirement anyways. This small change would do wonders for the system which suggests duplicates when creating a title.

Comment: "_So, seriously: when you want to stop reputation hunters from answering "DUPS" - then the only way that will work is to reduce the potential benefit from answering such questions._" there is another: incentivize (correct) duplicate closure: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387398/997587

Comment: @starball Always lofty ideas, but incentivizing will only work if there is a counterbalance; doing it wrong will need to have a downside, the opposite effect. Something that forces people to pause and think. Otherwise all questions are going to look like nails that need a dupe hammer. That counterbalance is never going to be implemented.

Answer (score -15):

They answer duplicates because they want those easy points, the solution is trivial and simple, I will expand on OP's first point and give you a chance to vote on it.

> Lower the rep gained for duplicate questions (similar to how users lose rep when someone deletes their account)

- 0 points for accepted answer to a dup
- 5 points for upvote
- 3 points for downvote

The numbers are not set in stone and can be tweaked but the goal should be to remove the incentive to answer dups.

Comment: This is basically(similar to) what [has already been said here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions)

Comment: @Liam True, also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37478 from 2010. This question is also basically a dup(I think it's ok for meta maybe things changed after 3 or 7 years) nothing was done then and nothing will be done now. I can take some arguments from there and improve my answer but I don't think it will help.