# Should dupe hammer users be given the option to NOT instantly close duplicates?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, dupehammer

Gold badge holders in tags have the [power to instantly close duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212).

I just read [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution#comment517109_357021) from a Gold Badge holder regarding other users with similar powers:

> What all of these users have in common is that **they can no longer cast a normal dup vote**. They are gold badgers, their vote is binding and the question is instantly closed. **Being the only user to close a question is not a great privilege**. You get to hear, loudly, about the OP's problems implementing the solution and it is all your fault. **I don't do it anymore** either, life is entirely too short to have to put up with that kind of crap. Faking the dup vote comment is a workaround.

**Emphasis** mine.

I don't know how many gold badge holders have a similar view for using their duplicate closing powers, but it seems that this privilege could be a bit of a double edged sword.

**Suggestion**

Would it be a good idea to give these users 2 options:

- instantly close a duplicate (**Default**)
- cast a regular or weighted dupe vote

**Benefits:**

- Gold badge holders wouldn't be singled out if they didn't want that kind of attention
- More dupe votes might be cast as a result
- Some questions may not be clear cut duplicates, so casting a single vote will encourage a group consensus rather than a single point of view

I'm tagging this with discussion for now, as I don't know how gold badge holders in general feel about using their dupe hammers.

I will add it as a feature request if it gain some support and positive feedback.

Comment: There's a duplicate of this somewhere. The rationale was that you should be definitely certain about the question being a duplicate.

Comment: It is a pretty brilliant scheme.  The true intention is to stop frequent contributors that are worn out from repetitive questions from using their voting power.  They generate a lot of complaints in the SO email inbox, sometimes even justified.  Ideally SO stops pretending they can actually provide customer support and passes off the job to meta.  It takes many hands and meta is pretty good about dealing with whining.  The last podcast quoted some emails they got btw, with the overarching conclusion that closing questions is the primary trigger.

Comment: Oh, the irony...a question about duplicates - marked as a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this was implemented, I've actually been more motivated to find that dupe I *know* exists. I even started maintaining a list of bookmarks to those extremely common duplicates.

In that sense, I don't recognize myself in the quoted description at all.
I think it's a great privilege, a powerful tool, and extremely convenient.

If users are complaining about the duplicate, more often than not, pointing them at a specific answer in the dupe does the trick. If that's not enough, **shrug**, we're not obligated to answer.

#### That all said,

I think it's a **good idea** to allow gold-badge dupe votes to weigh as a normal close vote. But then the same should be possible for re-open votes.
Just as we may be uncertain about it being a dupe, we may be unsure about it not being a dupe.

Comment: If you are unsure, **just leave a comment**. Even if you vote was not a veto, **don't vote unless you are sure**. Every vote counts, don't expect others to fact check for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: What if you're certain it _is_ a dupe, but you're pretty sure there's a better dupe target out there, than the one you found?

Comment: Then dupe now, search for the better dupe, and edit the dupe target? If you don't find it, the OP has an answer already, if you do, they'll have a better answer. :-)

Comment: Fair enough. But I think it's holding back quite a few users. I think a lot of gold badge owners aren't aware you can edit the dupe target list.