# Should we delete questions with positive score?

Tags: discussion

This a continuation of this [meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301357/how-is-it-possible-that-a-2-question-gets-deleted) of mine:

I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169003/is-it-necessary-to-add-a-constructor-all-the-time-in-child-class) question on SO. It got closed out as duplicate a bit later. A few days later, some other users came in and deleted that question. After putting up my meta SE question, the initial SO question was un-deleted rather quickly.

Leading to the thought/potential discussion: it seems that sometimes people are a bit *too* eager in their efforts to uphold the quality of this community.

What is the best way to look at this?

Comment: Your name [came up yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution).  SO users are pretty passionate about it, hard to blame them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that link.

Comment: Not a Java expert, but is not the behaviour of ctors in a purely OO language well, just something that we shoud not need to be teaching?  Surely, that subject is covered in every Java primer.  I'm not sure why such questions are asked in the first place, never mind multiple duplicates of it?  It's not a programming question, it's 'teach me Java basics'.

Comment: I don't really see your point, because a question you answered was deleted then un-deleted we should ban deleting questions? Why? this seems like an isolated case without a valid argument (or any argument for that matter) to change functionality.

Comment: The question appears to have been deleted again.  Out of curiosity, did a firehose of downvotes affect the same outcome?

Comment: @bitnine In case you are asking me - there were three more downvotes on my answer. Funny fact: when I know click on "delete" here on my question, or on my ME question - the system won't let me do that. Because people put in *effort* to answer.

Comment: I was happy to deliver ...

Comment: @rene In case you are talking to me ... I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's be honest that this all starts with users that are too eager to answer duplicates instead of close voting them.

We certainly should delete all questions that have no lasting value for future visitors. What lasting value exactly means could and should be derived from score, views, and answers. This doesn't mean that positive scored posts are exempt from deleting. If that idea takes off it will very much stop all moderation effort.

Delete-voting on duplicates should be handled with care, but when a question and their answers are just a repeat of existing posts, there is not much need for yet another signpost. If future visitors who are looking for the same issue find a zillion posts that all address the issue slightly differently, that is doing them a disservice.

Having a single post with quality answers should still be the goal. It is harder to achieve due to the *let's answer any thing we see* mentality instead of *let's find a duplicate first*, but if we give up now, we better sell out the sites to Yahoo! Answers.

Deleting duplicates that have little value as sign-post should be deleted, no matter what their score.

Comment: Well, then lets avoid that in the future.

Comment: It's not that I disagree with what you're saying.  You're just saying all of the things we know should happen without telling us what metric we're using to measure "lasting value".  Until you get that metric squared away, you're going to be faced with ever increasing frustration, since "lasting value" can only be measured (at a large scale) in specific ways.

Comment: @Makoto simple... it's a judgement call. you be the judge. vote accordingly.

Comment: Well @Makoto the truth is I really expected this to be the unpopular vote so the outcome of the current score is ... a surprise. I did choose  *lasting value* on purpose because I realize, and you confirm that, that value is a subjective matter, that isn't easily captured in single digit, despite how much we, developers, would like that to be. It is up for debate.

Comment: @KevinB:  Judgment calls are how we got into this mess in the first place.  Everyone judges things differently.

Comment: Hence why it requires multiple votes.

Comment: Duplicate with lasting value = duplicate with terms that the target and other duplicates lack and is semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes posts that are duplicate gets much more attention, views and user interactions than the original ones (as a result of different wording, different tags and keywords). In such cases, users who Google "How to X" might see the first link leading to the duplicate question and not the original one.

On the other hand, I can understand deletion of new posts that are exact duplicate of another "popular" post (e.g. "How to compare Strings in Java").

In conclusion, there is no rule of deleting/undeleting a post. Each post should have its own considerations when it comes to deletion.

Comment: I don't understand why such questions are even asked on SO, never mind duplicated.  Comparing strings, for example, is a very basic language fundamental, and entering 'Java compare strings' into a popular search engine gives: 'About 55,800,000 results'.  Are more needed?   The behaviour of ctors in an OO language is in the same category.

Comment: @MartinJames Unfortunately, some (many) users misunderstand the basics of Stack Overflow (and probably don't know how to properly search the web). Sometimes copying the title to popular search engine gives you the answer immediately.