# What is wrong with these two questions, and how can I go about fixing them?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

I received a notification that I am now banned from asking questions due to my negative or zero scored questions. [I've read that in order to ask more questions, I need to improve my existing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

I have tried improving my questions, but there are two that I don't know how to fix, because I don't understand what is wrong with them.

1. **[How to change the color of the letters in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042646/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-letters-in-the-header)**
   I feel that this was legitimate question which received three answers.

   I don't understand why it has a negative score and I don't know how to fix it.

   UPDATE: I did prior research on Stack Overflow about this subject, and found some related discussion. However, I was unable to use this to solve the problem. The question is not a duplicate, that's why it wasn't marked as a duplicate in the first place and why people attempted to answer it.
2. **[How to change locations of the small pictures regarding each others and the big picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008541/how-to-change-locations-of-the-small-pictures-regarding-each-others-and-the-big)**
   This question was related to another question which I linked in the question itself. The original question's answers did not work for me, so I asked a new question and provided more details in the hope that I would get an answer that did work for me. Two days later I figured out how to solve the problem myself so I posted an answer.

   Again, I don't understand why it has a negative score and I don't know how to fix it.

   UPDATE: I think Stack Overflow is a place to ask questions that someone cannot figure out the answer to themselves. They ask the question regarding a particular code implementation in order to get help. I don't think the suggestion to hire a developer for this purpose is appropriate or helpful. It doesn't encourage people to create something new; it just discourages them from using Stack Overflow out of frustration for being rejected, criticized, and derided.

**What is wrong with these two questions, and how can I go about fixing them?**

Comment: I've edited your question here to clarify, remove noise and ranting, and focus on your requests for help improving your questions instead of what appeared to be complaints about downvotes (the downvotes weren't the problem, the fact that no one told you why your questions don't meet our standards of quality was the problem). If my edit deviates too far from the original intent of the question, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @Tiny, I am agree with you that the main problem was that "he fact that no one told you.."  and I put a lot of effort as the people who answered the questions. If it was noticed that the question is not right, they would not be posted and as result I would not be down voted ;    I don't want to be punished by not be able to ask and answer the questions because nobody said that my question/answers are not correct. thanks

Comment: some addition. My reputation was about 36 and then it drastically went down. So, I think since nobody tell me that the question/answer are not right, then I would not be able to figure out it myself and therefor should not be punished by down voted  and not ability to participate in forum.

Comment: Not that I want to send you away, but it may be a good idea to step away from Stack Overflow for a while, at least until you've learned the truth about what the site is for and start to understand what is happening to the content you contributed and why. Nothing is being done to you, the only thing people are doing is judging the content. And that's a very normal function of this site, it happens to all questions and answers posted. Have you seen the [tour] and the [help] already? If not: worth a visit.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/352742

Comment: @Gimby
You've already kind of send me away by not allowing to ask the questions for ..... I don't know for what? For just asking the question to find the solution?  So, after people answered on the first question and I accept the solution, you consider that this is sort of duplicate even so it was not duplicate in the first place and more importantly I could not implement the solution provided earlier. Therefore it is not duplicate since I got the solution after asking the question and not before it.

What about my second question where I provide the solution hoping that it help somebody?

Comment: *I could not implement the solution provided earlier* - Then you should have done 2 things: 1- don't accept an answer before testing it; accepting is just for when [it solves your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 2- Edit your question explaining **why** it didn't work (just saying "it didn't work" is too vague and we can't guess what happened unless you tell us).

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring.... I was not find the solution on my problem  and that why I've asked the question. Basically, I've asked the question to find the solution. And I accept the answer that solved my problem. What is wrong with that? Do I accept the answer that it is not the best for your or somebody else point of view? But I've asked the question and II supposed to choose the answer that I think is the best.  You can argue that it is not the best, but I think it won for 2 important  criteria : short and clear. Once again: it is supposed to be my choice but not somebody else.

Answer (score 11):

1. [How to change the color of the letters in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042646/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-letters-in-the-header)

   This question is a duplicate. It can't be fixed. Next time, search Stack Overflow to see if your question has already been asked.
2. [How to change locations of the small pictures regarding each others and the big picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008541/how-to-change-locations-of-the-small-pictures-regarding-each-others-and-the-big)

   This question is too broad. What you are doing is giving us some code and telling us to implement your requirements. That's not what we do here. If you want someone who can edit your code according to your new requirements, hire a developer.

Comment: The addition was after "UPDATE"  that clear show that the first question was not duplicate and the second one  could be solved with help of community without hiring a developer.  Also hiring a developer and not relate on community as you suggested  defeat the purpose of Stack Overflow as community center that helping people  to understand the subject or develop something new without frustration to be rejected.

Comment: @User *why* is the first one not a duplicate? Can you *show* why the solutions in the other answers do not work? Simply claiming that it is not a duplicate won't work. I can claim that I am a purple unicorn. It doesn't make it so. Please read [this](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) article before you come back and say that they "didn't work".

Comment: @User The [accepted answer in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042709/7605325) is the same as the [in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268759/7605325). This is the very definition of a duplicate, [according to FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/352742): *"Questions may be duplicates if they have the **same (potential) answers**"* - In this case, the answers are pretty much the same. Having some users answering doesn't change the fact that it's a duplicate. After all, [sometimes people answer duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357021/7605325)

Comment: 'the purpose of Stack Overflow as community center that helping people to understand the subject or develop something new' no.  That is a very useful side-effect.

Comment: @MartinJames or, "the purpose of public parks is to play baseball". No, that's just a nice side effect.

Comment: @Hugo
The discussion about reputable users:
“…are only a few of MANY who answer blatant duplicates.”
I am not reputable user. As I said, my reputation was 36 and up and I could keep it this way  but I asked the questions to find the solutions - and now it is very much down... and I could not even ask the questions.
Once again even so it was similar answer, but it was not blatant duplicate since I could not use it for my implementation. Therefore, I’ve asked the question and got the answer to my satisfaction even so I lost a lot of reputations and banned for asking the questions.

Comment: @Hugo
Fighting for definition “duplicate?”, “blatant duplicate?”  , “Not duplicate?” would make you afraid to ask the questions because you would be labeled and down voted.
I  spoke with a professional developer about  not be able to find the solution in Stack Overflow. He said that if the problem serious, you could not find the solution there since there are the solutions only for the very simple tasks.
The punishment by down voting and prohibition to ask the questions because of possible duplication defeat the purpose of Stack Overflow as community that help people to find the solutions.

Comment: @User Then you should explain why the solutions in the other question didn't work for you. With only the information provided in your question, other users can't guess why it wouldn't work. If you just say "no, it's not a duplicate, it didn't work for me" and don't explain why, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: @User And the other discussion I linked wasn't exactly about your reputation. It was about people answering duplicates and how this is an issue, and to show that a question still is a duplicate even if someone answers.

Comment: @Hugo
I am a new to JavaScript and the solution provided in earlier post doesn't work for me since I could not comprehend  and used it for my purpose.  And another hand, the solution for my question solve my problem: it was pretty clear explanation for novice how to achieve the goal with valuable example as below:
.red {
  color: red;
}

You probably noticed that another people provided some solutions as well, but I could not use them even so I've tried and even for other people , those solutions are better to take.  Is it important that I made the choice that help  to solve the problem.

Comment: @Hugo, yes it is not about my my reputation.  it is about that there is  very slight difference between "blatant duplicate", "duplicate" and "no duplicate" that even moderators don't find it as duplicate question. And as I explain you in the previous post I don't t  consider that the answer was duplicate since I could not use the previous one but find the solution with  the answer to my question. I think that finding the solution(s) is the most important part even so the solution could be the simple as that.  ICan I ask the questions or  I am banned to ask and therefore to use this side?

Comment: @User Again: if you couldn't use the solution, you should have edited the question explaining in details why it didn't work (so people will have a better understanding about your problem and won't consider it a duplicate). Unless you do it, this loop of *"it is"* - *"no, it's not"* will never end. And you shouldn't have accepted the answer until you know it works. Regarding your question ban, well, [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/7605325) contains all the information you need, good luck!

Comment: @Hugo
You misunderstand me. 
First question.
The solution on my question that I  accepted is working.  The other solutions are not working because my knowledge is not enough to comprehend those solutions. The same could be said about not finding the solution in the previous post that is considered as possible duplicate. Again: it is not duplicate since there is no solution for me, more accurate: there is no solution  that I could use to implement. Everybody is different. 
Second question.
I ask and provide the answer on it after I figure out the solution. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: the  correction:
I ask the question and provide the answer on iit after I figure out the solution. 
What is wrong with this approach and what if anything need to be done differently?

Comment: the  questions that remain to be answered:
I could not find the solution to implement therefore I've asked the first question. 
Could  I ask on  StackOverflow he questions that I could  implement and don't be afraid of possibility duplication  that not I neither moderators could oversee.? Or I need to hire a professional developer for help and don't use StackOverflow?

Second question that I've asked : have no answer yet

I ask the question and provide the answer on iit after I figure out the solution. 

What is wrong with this approach and what if anything need to be done differently?

Comment: @User in this case, I think your question ban is a well-deserved wake-up call that you need to learn how to ask questions on this site. Lurk here for six months, maybe try to answer a few questions or suggest edits, and then ask a much better question. Even when question banned, you can ask a question every six months.

Comment: Why people hate stack overflow and don't want to be part of it:

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-hate-Stack-Overflow
agree with that :
"The problem with StackOverflow is that some fanatic moderators with strange, arbitrary notions on what qualifies as a good question ruin it for most of us, by locking many REALLY GOOD questions and not locking some REALLY STUPID questions.

Also, mods often respond in a very hostile tone when they believe someone broke some arbitrary rule, chasing away many new users who might have become valuable contributors otherwise."

Comment: There were no moderators involved in any of this, @User. The only thing a moderator participated in was this Meta question, [revising and ensuring that it got re-opened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/357124/revisions).

Comment: @User Again: *"First question. The solution on my question that I accepted is working"* - And the solution is **exactly** the same as in the [duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268759/7605325). Still, you insist that the question is not a duplicate, when the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/352742) clearly states that "Questions may be duplicates if they have the **same (potential) answers**". If you can't understand that (and just call us "fanatic" instead), then there's nothing more to discuss. It seems to me that you don't want to discuss, you just want to be right.

Comment: I am not going to insist if you have the authority  to decide  what is right and what is wrong.  And you could find if you want some duplication in every possible question and answer since computer World was created long time ago and there are always  some duplications. I think that you don't need to be "fanatic" about that but rather don't count it as "duplication if it helps to find the solution - but a previous answer failed to do so.
"Fanatic" is not originally my expression, also(see link above) there are diminished flow of  members asking questions.  Don't want to be rejected, do they?

Comment: There are a long discussion about duplication, blunt duplication, partial duplication an so on. I don't think that consensus  could be achieved since I  believe  (as a lot of others users who already gone) to a personal achievement  and not being rebuke or banned  for asking  not "virgin" questions; I mean the questions or answers that were somehow earlier. If there is no choice  I need to follow others to move since waiting 6 months to ask -  and then to be rejected or banned again for any reasons that could not be overseen have no sense.

Comment: What about my second question that nobody discuss?
 I've asked this question since I could not find the solution(see  initial post). There were no any kind of duplication in the question/answer and I provide the  working solution to help other  people with similar situation.
In the link that I provide earlier, people complain that there are a lot of down voting without  any reasons especially for new members. 
I feel the same way.
Once again what could be wrong with my approach?
The answer said something about that it is too broad.... 
It is not too broad since it helps me and others.

Comment: @User *if you have the authority to decide what is right and what is wrong* - It's not my authority, it's what's described in the site's FAQ. Can't you really see that both answers are **exactly** the same? I agree that there are cases where the duplicate is unclear and questionable, but it's not the case of your question. Look, I **really**, really don't mean to be rude, but if you're new to javascript (as you said), then you're not the most qualified person to tell if a JS question is duplicate. No offense, the same applies to all users (including me) and respective languages they don't know

Comment: @User when you say "a lot of down voting without any reasons", I think you actually *mean* "a lot of down voting without any reasons *that I agree with or accept*". *That's* why you will keep getting downvoted if you do not learn how to ask questions here. If you want to dictate quality standards, start your own site.

Comment: @Hugo Are we on the same page, I mean on the same answer?
I am talking about the answer that I choose that have nothing to do with the answer that you refer as duplicate. 
My answer don’t use JavaScript at all, the answer that pointed as duplicate heavily used JavaScript. Mine is much shorter.
You would not find any similarity even just looking on those two codes. 
That way, I strongly believe (as any other not prejudice person) that there is no duplication in the answers at all. Therefore, my answer (with green mark) and answer in another post (with green mark) have no duplications.

Comment: @RobertColumbia it looks like you are not interested that users use StackOverflow and suggest to use a professional developer or start your own ...side.  
There are the thought about some members of this community who don't value other members especially  the new ones
 "If you disagree or question them, then they’ll gang up on you like files, including starting a “meta question” where they’ll publicly flame you. Complaints to the anonymous site administrators (aka, the “team”) will just get ignored too."
And people ask what is the alternative of this rudeness and share the links.

Comment: @User [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46042709/7605325) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268759/7605325)

Comment: @User we did not create a "meta question" to publicly flame you. *You* created this meta question in which you have demonstrated that you do not understand how this site works.

Comment: @User Regarding the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/164131/7605325): if we copy it and paste as an answer to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46042646/7605325), it's also a valid answer (you used the javascript tag, so you should expect javascript answers). According to [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/352742), they're duplicates because they have the same potential answers. *"But I can't use it, I'm new to javascript"* - Sorry, unfortunately an user's lack of knowledge or inability to use a solution is **not** part of the criteria (site's rules, not mine).

Comment: Once again, please clarify what/if any  wrong with the second question?
It partially copy and past from the earlier post since there is no elaboration: There were no any kind of duplication in this question/answer and I provide the working solution to help other people with similar situation. .... Once again what could be wrong with my approach?  The answer said  that it is too broad and suggested to hire a developer... I could not find any sense with those two  contradicted suggestions. 
Too broad, mean a lot of opinions... but nobody answered... Why hire a developer if I figured it myself?

Comment: @RobertColumbia
It is not my expression about  "meta questions".  I used quotation marks around text. FYI " ", mean that it is not originally  my expression but I take it from side where others express their own opinions that could be related to yours:
https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-hate-Stack-Overflow
I don't have a degree in JavaScript but I could comprehend  it and created several sides using it.  And I clear understanding that my question and the chosen  answer is not intended to use Java Script but CSS instead. It was clear declared in the answer. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @Hugo, there is no discussion as such when you edit my post after the argument arise.  It should be  "as is" .You are not supposed to mark the question or argument as duplicate when question  was not marked as duplicate in the first place. Playing with posts, answers or questions are not admissible. 
It is not just that I am trying to create the rules or confront your authority: it is rather  the basic rules of fair conversation.
When you wrote  "potential" - it has no sense at all. It is like say: " You are potentially right, but you still wrong and I am right because  I have more  rights"

Comment: @User I didn't edit anything, check in the revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46042646/revisions

Comment: @User Now you deviate from the subject and accuse me of editing the post, which I didn't. Seriously, I give up. We told you the site's rules and you refused to accept them. You have the right to disagree, and I have the right to agree and follow them. I'll just move on, nothing productive will arise from here. Enjoy your question ban, or go post on quora, as you agree so much with them, bye!

Comment: @Hugo
You wrote "if we copy it and paste as an answer to your question, it's also a valid answer ..."
Once again you are not supposed to copy and past or consider to do so because it is improper for sake of fair discussion where post should be 'as is". I am not deviate from the subject  but  rather follow it and I am( also as other users) follow the rules when I post my questions that wasn't considered as duplicate  and users made efforts to answer. You wrote that the question was duplicate since it related Javascript. It is false: no related it  at all, therefore it is not duplicate.

Comment: @ Hugo you wrote "I'll just move on, nothing productive will arise from 
here."
It is correct since you can not or rather have no authority to admit that I don't violate of this side rules an should not be banned.

Comment: The conslusion(see post and discussion)
There were no duplication  of the first post.
No any justification about that something wrong with the second question except some contradict statements in the answer provided.

Comment: The conslusion(see post and discussion)
There were no duplication  of the first question/answer.

No any justification about that something wrong with the second question except some contradict statements in the answer provided.

Regarding that I don't violate the rules, could you restore my right to ask and answer the questions? 

I probably would not use this right but I also don't "enjoy it" and I don't think that Hugo should use this expression since it sound  pretty unprofessional.... I think that representation of this side and the actions regarding users should be at least fair.

Comment: @User you do not seem to understand what we have been telling you. You keep saying the same things over and over and are unwilling to consider them from any perspective but your own. We cannot have a discussion unless you are willing to consider what we have to say as possibly true.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, it is exactly.  We both should consider that what another side saying is possible true.  Yes,  I think this from my perspective, you are from yours - and usually but not always the truth is somewhere in between.  It is not the end of the world and I probably have nothing to ask but I still don't want to be banned for six months. Once again, could you lift a ban and allow me to ask the questions?  It could  be done for  6 months under your supervision.  I mean, I could post the question only if you approve it. I think, this is the constructive solution and  end of discussion.

Comment: I was notified by email  that I need to improve the questions/answers Please see my initial post with comments that clear indicated that I could not improve the existing question/answer. My first question and answer were marked  as duplicate even so it is notl since question and answer don't use Java Script. And "so called" duplicate answer using Java Script.
My second question was considered as too broad but I have no answers at all to my second question  and figured out how to answer myself.  So, my second question is not too broad and II  don't need to use a developer as was suggested.

Comment: @User I do not have the authority to retract a question ban. As for your second question, you need to narrow it down and be more clear.

Comment: Anybody else except you have an authority to whom I could contact. or if there is no such person,  then how to delete  my account?

Comment: @User use the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page to request account removal. Be aware that creating a new account to get out of a ban is against the rules. Don't know and don't care if that was the plan you had brewing, just be aware that this is a known trick.

Comment: Rules are not supposed to be violated especially by the people who create those rules.  I consider that banning people for not violation of the rules is violation of the rules. Once again,  my reputation was 36 and up and if I continue to ask some  positive  received question it would  be much more up.  But i don't want to do so and prefer to ask the questions  that hard to answer  and that I could  use  even so I've got down voting. But I am not alone.: a lot of people upset to  this approach to users: 
https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-hate-Stack-Overflow

Comment: I've sent the request to remove my profile about 24 ago  and got response as below..What is time frame,(ASAP ) when the profile would be removed?
"You recently sent a request to have your Stack Overflow profile removed. We're sorry to see you go! This email is just to let you know your request has been received, and we will respond with help ASAP."

Comment: @user8210158 it looks like your account has been deleted. Farewell!