# Tighten rules for deleting dupe-hammered questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, dupehammer, vote-to-delete, deletion

I think the rules for deleting dupe-hammered questions should be tightened to require at least five users to make a vote to close or delete.

Dupe-hammered questions can be deleted by votes of only three users, assuming that the user who does dupe-hammering also votes to delete the question:

- User A : hammer + delete
- User B : delete
- User C : delete

In contrast, questions closed for other reasons require at least five users to cast a vote, assuming that three of the users who closed the question also vote to delete it:

- User A : close
- User B : close
- User C : close
- User D : close
- User E : close + delete
- User A : delete
- User B : delete

Given that duplicates tend to cause less harm than "send me codez", spam, and grossly off-topic questions, I think it would be fair to require votes of at least as many users for deleting dupes as it takes to delete closed questions from other categories.

The user count should include closing votes cast prior to hammering. For example, the following sequence of votes should lead to deletion:

- User A : close
- User B : close
- User C : hammer + delete
- User D : delete
- User E : delete

However, if the dupe is hammered first, the sequence should be as follows:

- User A : hammer + delete
- User B : delete
- User C : delete
- User D : delete
- User E : delete

Comment: But closing doesn't take five 10k users to take effect, it only takes five 3k users. Requiring five 10k users to compensate makes it unjustly harder to delete a question, just because someone closed it as a duplicate. That aside, you don't really identify *why* this is a problem that needs to be fixed. What's the backstory here? Are 10k users deleting a lot of dupe-hammered questions that shouldn't be deleted?

Comment: @animuson Obviously, I am not an admin, so I do not monitor the stats. However, this happens roughly once a month to questions that I answer, which is often enough for me to notice a pattern. In a recent case a question has been closed and deleted in a situation when even the closing was half-though through, let alone deletion. In another case the duplicate had a much better description than the canonical answer, yet it was dupe-hammered and deleted. That is why I think the process needs a little adjustment in this area.

Comment: @animuson As far as "why is this a problem" goes, I think that *more harmful* questions should require an attention from *fewer* users in order to be deleted, while currently it is the other way around.

Comment: That i can certainly agree with... but i don't see how making delete votes on dupes worth less goes toward that goal. it's completely invisible to the delete voter (unless they sit there and watch the question) and therefore doesn't really encourage them to focus their attention on more problematic questions.

Comment: One of the problems i often see is it's very difficult to get questions that should be deleted to a state where they *can* be delete voted (aka closed/on hold.) With dupe closure the closure is instant, which makes the question eligible for deletion instantly. We can cast downvotes on the question, but... it's kinda difficult to go against the tide of users who upvote everything, doubly so when something they've taken interest in receives a downvote.

Comment: @KevinB "With dupe closure the closure is instant, which makes the question eligible for deletion instantly." I think this is the root cause of my concern: hammered duplicates become deletion-eligible the instance the gold badge user casts his vote, which brings the question to the verge of deletion when paired with a vote to delete. Of all types of holds, duplicates are the most harmless, and they can be useful at times. However, they get expedited deletion, while all other types of hold require more attention from the community.

Comment: @KevinB Closure doesn't make the question instantly eligible for deletion.  The post needs to have a score of -3 to have delete votes cast, and it requires 20k rep instead of 10k until the post has been closed for 3? days.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it sounds like you should edit questions in shape so they worth upvotes when you answer them to solve the problem instead of adding restrictions on deletes...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I do that when I can. However, at times three people is just not enough to spot an important difference between a closed question and its canonical version. I started this thread after yet another question with my answer has been deleted (in case you are curious, the Q&A is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43147725/335858)). The user who closed the question failed to see the difference between the question and three possible duplicates (Java compiler does a special thing with small numbers fitting in a `char`; none of the dups explains it), and two other users missed it too.

Answer (score 12):

In the past 90 days, 28579 questions were closed as duplicates by gold tag-badge holders. Of these, 1564 were deleted by privileged voters.

For comparison, the system itself deleted 2800 of those dup-hammer-closed questions. And the askers of these dup-hammer-closed questions deleted another 3543.

Note that the number of delete votes required scales with both the score of the post and the scores of answers, up to a maximum of 10 votes to delete. Further restrictions here don't seem particularly necessary.

#### See also:

- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)
- [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)
- [What posts get deleted, and why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why)
- [How can we stop premature deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171763/how-can-we-stop-premature-deletion)