# Why doesn't the revision history of this answer say it was deleted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, revision-history, deletion, timeline

I noticed something strange in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19804912/4284627) answer's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19804912/revisions). It says that the answer was undeleted, but it doesn't say that it was deleted:

[image]

I also checked the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19804912/timeline), and the timeline doesn't either say it was undeleted. The timeline does say it went through [low quality posts review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3292547) and that the consensus was Recommend Deletion, so I suppose that's how it was deleted, but neither the timeline nor the revision history mention the deletion itself.

I've deleted and undeleted this question, so you can check the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/365333/revisions) and [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/365333/timeline) of this question to see how it should look.

Why don't the revision history and the timeline say that the answer was deleted? Is this a bug?

Comment: I'm guessing there was a bug back then, in the review deletion process, that caused the 'post deleted' entry to be omitted.

Comment: @NickA I don't think that's the case. That answer was undeleted almost a year after the Low Quality Posts review was completed. Besides, I deleted this question and undeleted it 4 seconds later, and both appear in [this question's revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/365333/revisions).

Comment: @DonaldDuck That's proof enough for me :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The system has never recorded an actual deletion event anywhere in the history when a post is deleted from the Low Quality Posts Queue, from the get-go. [In 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable), at the same time we got the disputed auto-flag for undeleting it, [we also started inserting a "Post Deleted From Review" history event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220465/add-delete-event-when-post-is-deleted-via-the-low-quality-review-process) (which now also lists all of the users involved with the review).

That is *still* not an actual deletion event though - it's a completely separate event from the normal deletion event that gets recorded when you delete your own post or it gets deleted by others with the appropriate privilege.

So back when review of that post was completed, all that happened was the post got silently marked as deleted. Nothing more. There is legitimately no deletion event on that post, and there never was.

Comment: If you're saying this is by-design, that's not very satisfying. Firstly, either the post was deleted or it wasn't —  I can't quite make out from your answer whether this is the case or not, but you seem to be describing some phantom deletion state. Secondly, at the very least the "undeletion" should be handled the same way, because the revision history as shown in the question here is just baffling.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, that's exactly what it is. The post literally got marked as deleted by adding a DeletionDate, but the system never recorded a deletion event in the revision history. Nowadays, we include a different event in the history at the time of deletion to avoid that confusion, but we didn't bother to go back and fix all the previous histories.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I read animuson's answer to say that the post was deleted and there isn't a record of it here because the system doesn't keep records of these kinds of deletions (at least publicly; I'm sure there's a flag or entry in a db somewhere)

Comment: @animuson: Okay, so it's a historical bug / design limitation manifest due to the age of the post? That makes more sense. I propose adding this conclusion to your answer :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Right. It occurred for ~ two years (mid 2012 through mid 2014).

Comment: Worth noting here that there's another common scenario where posts are deleted without a corresponding history entry: answers to deleted questions are marked deleted at the time of the question's deletion, but do not get their own history entry and can be undeleted without deleting the question (at which point the system will re-delete them on a schedule, again without a corresponding history entry). This sort of thing makes [attributing reasons for deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why) a headache and a half...