# Vote to delete good questions with wrong reasons

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete

I recently came to this question:

- [What does the regular expression /_/g mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052616/what-does-the-regular-expression-g-mean)

and saw it is closed as a being a duplicate for this one:

- [How to match multiple occurrences of string within a string using reg ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041308/how-to-match-multiple-occurrences-of-string-within-a-string-using-reg-ex)

The first question has:

- 82 upvotes
- ~70K views
- 2 good answers

plus being ~3 months older than the second question and being close to removal (7 delete votes up to now) and **not** the same question as the first question.

I think I should tell the differences because it received a considerable number of delete votes in a month and it is not the first question that I'm seeing to be a similar victim. So please read on:

- First question,

  1. asks for replacing `_` with a space character
  2. asks for `g` modifier but is not the main problem
- Second question,

  1. asks for matching a pattern
  2. asks for `g` modifier which is the main problem

Knowing the differences the first question *could* be a duplicate for one of these instead:

- [JavaScript - Replace all commas in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610402/javascript-replace-all-commas-in-a-string)
- [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

(one is closed for the other, but has got no delete votes)

For now I can edit the duplicate question to one or both of these two questions, leave it alone or re-open it to neutralize the delete votes which I think are cast for an inaccurate reason but it leaves two questions unanswered:

1. What if I didn't hit that question in delete queue?
2. and how many questions are removed the same way and or are in the queue to be removed?

Comment: *"What if I didn't hit that question in delete queue?"* - Plenty of stuff gets undeleted on the regular. The weight of the world isn't on your shoulders here.

Comment: "What if I didn't hit that question in delete queue?" - irrelevant, you did catch it. People will make mistakes, there is no stopping that. So bonus points that there is such a thing as a queue which allows mistakes to be caught.

Comment: In a community driven network the first commentator says *the weight isn't on your shoulders* and the second person says *you did catch it* however I did catch it by chance and I'm here because of that chance. I could hit the queue in the next one or two weeks and never see it.

Comment: The question they are trying to delete is the first result you get when you search for "regular expression g" in google.

Comment: Frankly, these reviewers' time (7x delete-voters) would be better spent writing more comprehensive answers to canonicals (to *their* liking, so they don't feel the urge to delete them).

Comment: @jpp It's not very fair to blame individual deletion reviewers here. The delete-vote queue is *fundamentally flawed*, everyone would make mistake sometimes, but that queue only *accumulates* mistakes if a question is incorrectly placed into it. 1000 reviewers think it shouldn't be deleted, but if another 10 cast the vote, it gets deleted. To make it worse, a deleted question is effectively invisible even to 10k users, since no one has a link to it. So once it's deleted, it's almost deleted forever.

Comment: @liliscent is entirely correct, ideally there would be a "vote to NOT delete", that would cancel a pending delete vote before it gets deleted, but it's unlikely that will happen any time soon.

Comment: @liliscent, I didn't mean to place *blame*, though I understand how my comment can come across that way. But IMO it's still the case their time would be *better spent* improving canonicals. It's true the system is geared more towards reviewing than improving popular Q&As.

Comment: @jpp I respectfully disagree with your "improving canonical" part. A popular question gets popular for a reason. Take the regex question here as an example, the answer is only two sentences, but the vote and view show that it's very useful. It's *risky* to try to "improve" a popular Q&A like this one, because the editor's good-faith attempt (e.g. make it longer or more comprehensive) might make it *less* useful to all the viewers.

Comment: @liliscent, I've posted *many* answers to old Q&A where the accepted answer is highly upvoted. If I think I can add value, I post answers to 5yr old questions *as readily* as I do to a new question. The Necromancer badge is actually the one I value above all others. If you're competent, you shouldn't believe it's innately risky to contribute to canonicals, that's how errors propagate.

Comment: @jpp Adding new answer isn't the *risky* way I was referring to. There are some users that try to *edit* the top answer of a popular question and add a lot of tangentially related stuff try to make it more "comprehensive". That's very risky no matter how competent you are. Radically changing the representation of a highly voted post is not acceptable, that's what was trying to say in the last comment.

Comment: "and how many questions are removed the same way and or are in the queue to be removed?" Not enough. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609/792066 Self deletion is the leading cause of deletion.