# Where can I find statistics about deleted questions related to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, statistics, data-dump, research

I have found similar questions in this meta site so I hope it is the appropriate place to ask it.

For my research, I need statistics on deletions between July 1, 2013 and March 4 2019 related to Stack Overflow questions. Since the repositories do not contain deleted questions, and this data is not available except for the moderators, I would like to request it from you.

The purpose of these statistics is to estimate the valid distribution of the quality of questions posted to Stack Overflow.

However, querying SEDE the number of deletion can be obtained but it does not contain important details, such as the reason for deletion (especially in case of previously closed questions), which is needed to estimate the valid distribution of the quality of posted questions.

I found a post where the statistics related to 2014 was provided, but I need the data for the whole period mentioned.

My research is related to the quality of the posted questions and the further goal is to build an evaluation tool based on NLP and deep learning methods, which can be used by askers to pre-evaluate their questions against the SO policy.

Dumps contain closed questions but do not contain deleted-questions which is about 25% of the posted questions. Due to the deleted posts, the dataset (dumps) are extremely unbalanced,  the closed questions are only very tiny parts of the post available in the dumps. This is detrimental for the deep learning algorithms which need much more data to provide acceptable accuracy for practical usage.

Despite the lack of data we are struggling to build a good classifier, but we should demonstrate the reasons of the weaker results, evaluate the distribution of the quality and estimate a reasonable accuracy if the deleted data would be available for us.

I would be grateful if you can help us to get the statistics or maybe the deleted questions (their body, title, tags, and the reasons for the deletion). We do not need the users' data, we lean on only the textual information in our research.

A closely related question is here ([What posts get deleted, and why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why?noredirect=1&lq=1)) , where the asker got some useful details, that is also usefull for me. If somebody could provide also the reasons of closing, I would be very thankful.

Comment: You need to have at least 25,000 rep to view site analytics.

Comment: Or you need to be a moderator to view site analytics.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the rules, but I this is only a try of a researcher who simply can not wait to achieve the designated reputation level :)

Comment: Google "site:meta.stackoverflow.com a year in moderation" to find the Shog9 posts back.

Comment: Here's a spreadsheet based off Shog's posts https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1upnX9UX8ab8rde8DrGnOkZNnMqK0Qce0MgpLVTFUTUE/htmlview.

Comment: Thank you Hans and Samuel, unfortunately I can not upvote your comment due to the low privileges...