# Can a deleted question ever be undeleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, moderators

Are moderators allowed to undelete posts? Under what conditions are they allowed to do so?

I personally have never come across such a situation, but I was wondering if the possibility ever exists (of course, apart from vote to undelete by high rep users)

Comment: Yes, Mods can undelete, but only if they feel the post sh

Comment: @10Rep looks like you were cut-off mid-sentence/word ... please don't let us hanging like this ... the suspense of the remainder of that sentence is killing ;)

Comment: One moderator has done that roughly [109 times](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1292187) since his election.

Comment: Curious how many times I've done it, @rene. Can you make that field an input param? (I was elected on 22-11-16)

Comment: @BhargavRao forking will work but also done the parameters now: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1292187/can-the-asked-question-ever-get-undeleted-by-a-moderator?moduserid=100297&since=2016-01-01

Comment: @rene Oops. I meant to finish with "should not have been deleted in the first place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They can undelete, and do undelete.

Posts deleted by a moderator **can only be undeleted by a moderator**. Their delete votes are binding and votes to undelete by regular users can't be cast.

If a post was deleted by a moderator and one wants to appeal the deletion; the way to go about it is to raise a custom flag on the post, and explain why it should it should be undeleted.

Unless one simply believes the deletion was a mistake, more often than not editing the post before raising the flag will be warranted, to try to solve whatever problems made the moderator delete it in the first place.

If the flag is declined, one can try to bring the case to meta to look for further community input.

For these cases, one should come prepared with:

- a link to the post, a screen-shot and/or a complete copy of the post so users below 10k reputation can still read it;
- depending on the desired outcome, either:

  - if one is looking to undelete the post, and to contest the moderator call; a well prepared argumentation about why the post should be undeleted (being prepared for disagreement is very healthy as well)
  - if one is simply looking for better understanding of the deletion rationale, simply pose the question about why the specified post is not fit for the site and is better deleted.

Comment: "Unless I'm mistaken, posts deleted by a moderator can only be undeleted by a moderator." - correct. That also means mods are forced to undelete answers that were deleted by mods in cases like fixed NAAs. Same with questions deleted by mods that have since been improved. The thing here though is that while they _can_, it rarely happens because most askers and answerers just abandon ship after deletion

Comment: *Posts deleted by a moderator can only be undeleted by a moderator* What if it was deleted by the OP?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I don't understand the question. OP delete votes are not binding, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @yivi I think the question is, can moderators undelete self-deleted posts, to which I think the answer is yes?

Comment: Yes @Nick, as mentioned the post owner vote is not binding. Posts deleted this way can be deleted by moderators or other community members.

Comment: Basically the thing to remember is that mods can do anything they want because they are, well, mods.

Comment: @10Rep No they can't, they can't undeleted self-deleted comments (well, they can undeleted their own self-deleted comments, but not other users)

Comment: @Nick Oh, why is that? What if a user self deletes a comment that adds something very useful to the post? According to the CC license, once you post something useful here, you can't delete it, which is also why you can't delete your own accepted answer. What's different with comments?

Comment: That's not actually what the CC license states, @10Rep - folks delete their own posts [ALL THE TIME](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why) after all. Unlike posts, comments cannot be easily edited or disassociated (which the CC license DOES require), so it's best to let folks retire them if they wish to.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok, I've looked at the license, and it makes sense. Thanks.