# What happens to all the questions that never get answered?

Tags: support, questions, unanswered-questions

To clarify, I'm not talking about worthy questions as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions), nor am I asking about how to attract more attention to an unanswered question. My assumption is that no one is going to answer the question or attempt to revive it. I'm talking more about questions like "I can haz java programz to Google Maps please help!!!!". In other words, questions that don't even attract enough attention to be closed by a moderator.

I tried to search for them in unanswered questions but seems that all downvoted questions are hidden from view (I tried sorting by votes and going to the last page).

Furthermore, there are many good questions that have no activity and have been open for years. Will they just remain open forever (again, assuming that no one attempts to revive the question).

Does StackOverflow ever clean up this almighty in tray?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/169611

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262077/what-should-the-system-be-deleting-automatically-that-it-already-isnt

Comment: Great links - I'm tempted to leave this question up because the others are more asking about the process they already know exists. But perhaps this is just a duplicate. Now that you have all commented on it it won't get deleted automatically :p

Comment: @user1886323 Questions on per-site metas are never automatically deleted.

Comment: @TinyGiant Same rules for automatic deletion apply: [example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/254305/revisions).

Comment: @Normal well then Jeff Atwood's post needs to be updated: [Every site in the network ***(except metas)*** will automatically delete old questions that meet this criteria from this point forward.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/288751)