# Should we improve / edit abandoned questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, abandoned-questions

Many users on SO ask questions and then disappear. Gone. Never to be seen or acknowledge receipt of comments or answers to their question.

Sometimes they are good questions, but may need some careful editing to make them useful to a wider audience.

**Is it permitted to edit such a question to make it better, in order to generate useful responses and hence a good Q&A?**

I have one concrete example:

[Pandas - convert Series of ints to strings - Why is apply is much faster than astype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371629/pandas-convert-series-of-ints-to-strings-why-is-apply-is-much-faster-than-as)

My idea is to add some version information (which is likely to be important to any answer) and possibly offer a bounty to encourage a good response.

The counter-argument is that the additional information added *may not align with OP's requirements*.

However, in my view if this question has been abandoned for weeks, the community should be permitted to turn the question into a useful Q&A.

**Note**: I could not find a duplicate, but found these *related* Meta questions:

- [Recycle abandoned question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258223/recycle-abandoned-question)
- [Is it OK to edit someone else's question or answer when the choice of accepted answer otherwise contradicts the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283130/is-it-ok-to-edit-someone-elses-question-or-answer-when-the-choice-of-accepted-a)

**Update**: I have now offered a bounty after adding `[python-internals]` and `[python-3.x]` tags with a one-line edit saying the question refers to Python 3.x. If anyone believes this is inappropriate, **please flag the question** so a moderator can have a look. I believe handling edit wars is within their remit.

Comment: @jpp They're not obligated to provide feedback on other answers (not that you even know whether or not they're actually voting on answers).  Them also not providing non-anonymous feedback on answers also doesn't make it okay for you to change someone else's question into a different question.

Comment: I think Hans is referring to the edit war where you keep adding a version specific tag and jezrael keeps removing it and now you've added text to the question claiming it's specific to version 3.

Comment: So the "concrete example" here is possibly not the best possible one jpp could have provided. It doesn't take away this is a valid question on itself.

Comment: I'm not familiar with panda, is it clear from ops code that this is python 3 or would the code also work with previous versions?

Comment: @BDL, The answer will be very specific to Python and Pandas versions.

Comment: @jpp Then why did you post an answer if you need to know what the OP's version is in order to answer it?  According to you you don't have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @Servy, you're right - I made some assumptions which I shouldn't have. But the stuff I put down *may be useful to the next answerer*. I turned it into a community wiki as I don't want credit. **Would you rather I delete my answer?**

Comment: Well, tags in my opinion should not be used to fit the question to an answer. They should be used to describe what the question is about. Also, your answer doesn't really require that tag. Would it be so bad if someone else drops by and leaves an answer for python 2 or for future python versions in a few years?

Comment: @jpp If you have information that might be useful, but that doesn't actually answer the question asked, then you should *find a question that it actually answers* and post it as an answer to *that*.  If you need to write such a question yourself, then so be it.  So if you're able to have the OP clarify what information you need in order to post an answer (in this case, knowing what version(s) of their products they're using) then you can correct your answer to actually answer the question.  If you can't, and there are no other questions on the topic, you may need to ask your own question.

Comment: I don't think that it was necessary to ask op in which version he wants the answer to be (as some others suggested), providing an answer in the most up-to-date version should be always fine unless there is an explicit request in the question for a particular version.

Comment: @BDL It does depend on the specifics though.  In a lot of programming languages/frameworks the differences (when solving many types of problems) from one version to the next are either non-existant, or so small that it's easy enough to cover all of the recent versions.  But when there are either radical changes in a given product between versions, or when the changes between versions radically change the solution to the question being asked about, trying to cover "all versions" can sometimes make a question too broad.

Comment: This quesition seems to be closely related [to another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365538/user-adding-tags-that-arent-relevant).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're more than welcome to improve an existing question, yes.  It doesn't matter whether you think the author is "active" or not.

What's not okay is changing the question to ask something different (again, whether you think the author is active or not).  Just adding in your own specifics to the question isn't appropriate.  Edits are there to improve the question that someone else is asking, not to turn it into a different question.

If a question is missing information necessary for an answer then *it's not a good question*, it's a question that merits closure until the author is able to clarify it.  If you have your own question that is similar, but that provides lots of different information than another question asked (enough that it either changes whether or not it is answerable, or changes what the answer is) then *ask your own question*, don't edit your question into someone else's.

If the question is actually a good question (which means that it contains enough information to be answered, as is) then either the answers there answer your question, in which case, you don't need to add in the specifics of *your* problem into someone else's question, or the answers *don't* answer your question, in which case you should ask a new question in which you provide your own specifics and explain how the solution already presented doesn't work for you.

Comment: In principle, I agree. In practice, I've already offered a bounty on the edited question. If you think what I've done is wrong, please have a look at the question and flag it, so a moderator can decide on appropriate action. I believe handling edit wars is within their remit.

Comment: @jpp Since you agree that the edit was inappropriate you should just roll it back yourself, and save a moderator the trouble, rather than threatening to continue to engage in an edit war that you agree you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Since I've already offered the bounty and people can see it / might be working on it, I prefer to do nothing. If you think that's wrong, do please flag it yourself. **I am threatening nothing.**